# Что такое выборы в модераторы сообщества и как они работают?

Tags: поддержка, faq, выборы

[Бюллетень сообщества](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129483/new-community-bulletin-box-in-side-area) говорит, что в данный момент проходят выборы в модераторы сообщества.

Подскажите, как они работают? Каким образом можно принять в них участие? Существуют ли какие-либо ограничения? Где можно посмотреть результаты голосования?

[image: бюллетень сообщества]

Answer (score 15):

Что происходит? – Сообщество выбирает [«ромбовых» ♦ модераторов](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role), тех ответственных людей, которые смогут поддерживать баланс в сообществе.

Модераторы выбираются в три стадии.

### Первая стадия:  Выдвижение

#### Длительность: 7 дней

Любой участник может выдвинуть свою кандидатуру на пост модератора, с условием удовлетворения условий описанных ниже.

- Участник должен иметь минимум 300 баллов репутации. Минимум репутации необходим, чтобы убедиться, что кандидат понимает как работает Stack Overflow на русском.

Выдвижение не является обязательным, его можно отменить на любой стадии выборов. Список кандидатов отсортирован согласно времени их выдвижения, новые заявки будут располагаться в верхней части страницы.

Кандидатам необходимо создать небольшое вводное слово о себе, добавив информацию о том, почему, по их мнению, именно они будут отличными модераторами. Любой участник имеет возможность [комментировать](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) любую заявку. Комментарии к заявкам не могут ни получить голос за, ни быть отмечены сигналом тревоги (в случае обнаружения оскорблений, пожалуйста, используйте [чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--)).

[image: выдвижение]

По истечению 7 дней, 30 кандидатов с наивысшей репутацией переходят на *начальную* стадию. В случае, если будут выдвинуты 10 кандидатов и менее, начальная стадия пропускается и происходит переход напрямую к стадии *выборов*.

### Вторая стадия: Начальная

#### Длительность: 4 дня

На этой стадии начинается голосование. Любой участник, имеющий 150 баллов репутации может принять участие в голосовании, за исключением того, что [кандидаты не могут голосовать за себя](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170909/179419). У участника есть один голос для каждого кандидата, ровно так же, как в случае вопроса или ответа. Комментарии запрещены.

Голосование проходит с помощью стрелок вверх и вниз, расположенных напротив заявки кандидата. Голос за говорит, что вы хотели бы видеть данного кандидата на следующей стадии, голос против сигнализирует об обратном.

[image: начальная стадия]

Повторюсь, выдвижение не является обязательным, его можно отменить на любой стадии выборов. Заявки отсортированы произвольно.

Результаты голосования открыты.

По прошествию 4 дней 10 кандидатов, набравших большее количество голосов, переходят на стадию *выборов*.

### Третья стадия: Выборы

#### Длительность: 4 дня

В заключение, проводится стадия непосредственных выборов. Как и ранее, любой участник, достигший 150 баллов репутации, может проголосовать. В противоположность начальной стадии, [кандидаты могут голосовать за себя](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170909/179419). Как и ранее, комментарии запрещены, а заявки отображаются в произвольном порядке.

Каждый участник сообщества имеет три голоса для 1-го, 2-го и 3-го выбора. Голоса подсчитываются по методу [«Meek STV»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1999/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2).

[image: выборы]

В противоположность *начальной* стадии, результаты голосования закрыты.

### Результаты и другая информация:

[Yi Jiang](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/150097/yi-jiang) создал [сайт выборов](http://elections.stackexchange.com/), который содержит статистику всех настоящих и прошедших выборов для всех сайтов сети Stack Exchange.

Страницы о прошедших выборах сохраняются для потомков и доступны по адресу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election.

Если выборы находятся в разгаре, результаты предыдущих не отображаются. Их можно найти по адресу `https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/<№ выборов>`.

Полный список настоящих модераторов доступен на главном сайте [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators). Дополнительную информацию можно найти в [блоге](https://blog.stackexchange.com/category/moderators/).

Comment: Описание алгоритма Meek STV вы будете переводить?

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что баджи не требуются? Для enSO нужны Civic Duty, Strunk & White, Deputy, Convention и Yearling

Comment: На данный момент все баджи есть только у пяти пользователей https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/374860/users-eligible-for-2011-stack-overflow-moderator-elections

Comment: @Oceinic Ваш результат неверный. По-первых, вы пропустили Timofey Bondarev и Krom Stern (у них меньше 3000 репы). Во-вторых, вы пропустили Nofate и Barmaley (у них нет баджей, потому что они временные модераторы со времени создания сайта). В-третьих, вы пропустили Discord, потому что на момент создания текущего дампа он был забанен и имел репутацию 1. В четвёртых, Yearling не нужен (но он и закомментирован). В целом, у нас 10 человек со всеми нужными баджами. Конечно, остальные тоже могут участвовать, но я не думаю, что они смогут превзойти эту десятку активных юзеров.

Comment: Зашёл к португальцам. У них вопросов вдвое меньше, а модераторов на треть больше, чем мы выбирать будем. С чем это связано?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб С большой вероятностью, у нас будет не меньший состав модераторов от сообщества.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Я не смог подобрать достойного, на мой взгляд, перевода. Возможно, у вас получится лучше!

Comment: @ЮрийСПб: " чем мы выбирать будем" — о каком количестве речь, откуда данные?

Comment: @Oceinic На сколько я понимаю ситуацию, нет, они не нужны. Я уточнил этот вопрос у коллег, но еще не получил ответ. Если окажется, что я ошибся, я обновлю публикацию.

Comment: @Oceinic: я не буду серьезно воспринимать кандидата без этих четырех баджей (исключая Nofate).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: перевел описание Meek STV.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, э-э-э... Ну я так понял... На en-SO в последние выборы троих выбрали, в чате кто-то тоже, вроде, троих поминал, да и в механизме голосования, как я понял, только за троих один человек проголосовать может. Видать это неспроста) Вопрос в том, будут ли ещё одни выборы для увеличения (а не замены) кол-ва ромбиков)

Comment: Предлагаю у нас на руСО называть их не "ромбовыми", а "бубновыми" (так и просится "туз" добавить :) )

Comment: Так сколько же всего будет модераторов?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, просто для справки, выборы ежегодные?

Comment: @VenZell Выборы проводятся в случае, если есть «нужда». Если, например, за пол года сообщество разрастется и будет нуждаться в увеличении команды модераторов, уверен, выборы будут проведены.

Comment: @Cerbo Будем скромнее - "бриллиантовыми" (бубна = diamond)

Comment: @sercxjo Предполагается, что сообщество выберет трех модераторов на текущих выборах. Дополнительно им буду помогать я.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov Бубны более харизматично, к стати еще ассоциация с шаманами напрашивается. То есть можно их шаманами называть, потому что у них бубны :)

Comment: Да уж, шаманить им и шаманить...

Comment: @NickVolynkin _"я не буду серьезно воспринимать кандидата без этих четырех баджей"_ Речь о бейджах только на ru.SO? Если, к примеру, у кандидата есть все эти бейджи на большом SO, то они что, соответствуют совсем другим навыкам и опыту?

Comment: @DmitryD. как-то пропустил уведомление по вашему вопросу, а вот теперь наткнулся. Вообще, баджи на большом SO это хорошо. Но у нас другое сообщество и у него не совсем те же задачи и проблемы. Я бы хотел, чтобы модератор варился именно в нашем котле и был в курсе наших дел. В итоге оказалось, что баджи не были обязательным требованием и не у всех кандидатов они есть. Гораздо важнее - здравый смысл и реальный вклад в ruSO.

Comment: "Yi Jiang создал сайт выборов" - устаревшая ссылка на сайт

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, Ваш ответ уже крайне устарел и не соответствует новым страницам выбора модераторов. Пожалуйста, обновите свой ответ так, чтобы можно было понять как голосовать на этих выборах. Я, к сожалению, не могу понять ☹️ Вот сейчас на англоязычной странице я выбираю в чекбоксе имя одного из модераторов и ничего не происходит вообще. Также мне не понятно что за программисты такие глупые, что не могли написать объяснение как это делать.