# Как устроено голосование на выборах модераторов?

Tags: поддержка, модерация, выборы

В ответе на вопрос «[Что такое выборы в модераторы сообщества и как они работают?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1983/181472)» говорится:

> Каждый участник сообщества имеет три голоса для 1-го, 2-го и 3-го выбора. Голоса подсчитываются по методу «Meek STV».

Что это за метод и как он работает?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Пример: выборы 2015 года

Посмотрите, [как считались результаты](https://www.opavote.com/results/6206376263024640/0) голосования на [выборах модераторов в 2015 году](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2226/181472):

[image]

## Как подсчитываются голоса

STV означает "single transferable votes" — единичные передаваемые голоса.

Meek — это B.L. Meek, который разработал этот алгоритм в 1969 г.

Давайте разберем работу алгоритма на примере. Пусть у нас есть:

- 24 голосующих участника (voters)
- 6 кандидатов (candidates)
- 3 вакантных места (seats)

Требуемое количество голосов для избрания рассчитывается по формуле:

```
quota = voters / (seats + 1) # деление целочисленное
quota = 24 / (3 + 1) = 6
```

Каждый голосующий выбирает кандидатов, которые получат его голос в первую, вторую и третью очередь.

В начале голосования каждому кандидату начисляются голоса от тех, кто выбрал его в качестве первого номера. Дальше происходит логическое ветвление:

Набрал ли кто-то из кандидатов необходимую квоту?

1. Да, такой кандидат есть.

   Этот кандидат побеждает в голосовании. Если он набрал голосов больше квоты, то избыточные голоса в равных долях перераспределяются тем кандидатам, которых обладатели голосов указали в качестве второго номера.

Например, кандидат А набрал 10 голосов. Для победы в голосовани нужно 6. Поэтому от каждого голосовавшего используется по 6/10 голоса. При этом 4/10 остаются свободными. Эти 4/10 от каждого из десяти голосовавших отдаются их вторым номерам (либо третьим, если вторые уже победили или исключены).

Если несколько кандидатов набрали квоту, то голоса перераспределяются с каждого.

2. Нет, все набрали меньше квоты.

Тогда из соревнования исключается кандидат, который набрал меньше всего голосов. Освободившиеся голоса перераспределяются вышеуказанным образом.

После освобождения голосов производится пересчёт и новая проверка — до тех пор, пока не наберется необходимое количество победителей голосования.

---

<sub>Ответ написан на основе перевода [How are moderator election votes counted, in plain English?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77541/how-are-moderator-election-votes-counted-in-plain-english)</sub>

<sub>Спасибо [D-side](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/181100/d-side), который [сделал анимированную картинку](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40570328#40570328) из отдельных диаграмм с opavote.com.</sub>

Comment: Хм, а что будет если голоса распределятся поровну между `seats+1` кандидатами? Хотя это больше теоретический вопрос, в такой ситуации ни одна система не даст осмысленного результата.

Comment: @PavelMayorov наверное, тогда мы исключаем последнего в списке и распределяем его голоса. Или вы имеете в виду ситуацию, когда двое претендуют на последнее место и больше исключать некого?

Comment: Э, нет. Я говорю про ситуацию когда **все** голоса распределяются поровну между `seats+1`, т.е. некоторые кандидаты одновременно достигли квоты, а остальные по нулям.

Comment: @PavelMayorov тогда, видимо, как в анекдоте про тоннели под Ла-Маншем: будет N+1 кандидатов. :)

Comment: Ещё одна [картинка-анимация расчёта с выборов 2017](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6225/213987) есть в посте Николаса с итогами.