# Результаты выборов в модераторы 2015

Tags: обсуждение, выборы, вехи

[Первые выборы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/1)  в модераторы сообщества Stack Overflow на русском подошли к концу, все голоса отданы. По результатам голосования, модераторами сообщества стали:

[image: Nofate] [image: Nick Volynkin] [image: PashaPash]

Эти участники в самое ближайшее время будут назначены как [выбранные сообществом модераторы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators). Пожалуйста, поблагодарите их за желание помочь сообществу в развитии! В будущем, не стесняйтесь поддерживать их советами и отзывами о их деятельности.

Давайте вместе еще раз выразим нашу благодарность Nofate, который практически в одиночестве помогал сообществу развиваться в течении всего бета-периода, а также ReinRaus и Barmaley, которые вместе с Nofate активно принимали участие в управлении сообществом до перехода на платформу Stack Exchange.

Для получения более подробной информации о результатах выборов вы можете загрузить данные по [ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/1) или [посмотреть отчет онлайн](http://www.opavote.com/results/6206376263024640/0).

Comment: Странные результаты: на протяжении всех выборов **только на повышение** играли Discord и Nick Volynkin, в то время, как основные 2 кандидата, которые оформились в самом начале, в разных раундах периодически уходили и в минус. Создается впечатление, что кто-то сильно хотел подтянуть число явных лидеров "за уши".

Comment: @mega: это не раунды голосования, а раунды алгоритма Meek STV. Он так работает. [Как подсчитываются голоса на выборах модераторов?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1999)

Comment: Ура! Спасибо всем за поддержку!

Comment: Это многое объясняет, хотя суть от этого и не меняется: подтянули вторых и третьих к первым. Значит, первым выбирали в основном Nofate и PashaPash.

Comment: Всех поздравляю!!! Отличный выбор!!!

Answer (score 3):

Что же мы видим по прошествии более 5 лет с этого события:

- [PashaPash снял с себя ромбик](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9559/176217).
- Nofate [последнее публичное действие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1984/nofate?tab=activity) на сайте совершал 31 мая 2019 года (скоро уже как два года бездействия). [Пара комментов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1984/nofate?tab=activity) была на Мете в августе 2020, внезапно на сообщении об отставке другого (более свежего) модератора.
- Nick Volynkin тоже [практически пассивен](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/181472/nick-volynkin?tab=activity).

Не знаю как обстоят дела с обработкой флагов у тех, кто ещё не снял свой ромб - всё же эта информация не является публично доступной. Но судя по тому как обрабатываются тревоги на Мете (ну, ооооочень долго) и неожиданные решения по тревогам на основном сайте, скорее всего и в модераторской (требующей ромба) деятельности активности по сути нет.

Честнее всех в этом плане выступил PashaPash из этой троицы.
Sad but true.

Comment: И в чём же тут заключается честность?

Comment: К тому же, когда объявляли последние выборы, эти факторы учитывали.

Comment: @Qwertiy какие именно факторы учитывали? Что модераторы бездействуют?

Comment: Учитывали активность модераторов и то, что двое уходят. PashaPash вроде ушёл раньше.

Comment: @Qwertiy честность в том, чтобы не держаться за ромб, если понимаешь, что на ромбическую деятельность нет времени.