# Неправомерные действия модератора PashaPash, вопрос адресован Nicolas Chabanovsky

Tags: обсуждение, модераторский-произвол

Вопрос адресован только сотруднику компании [@Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky), потому что знаю его еще со времен ХешКода как справедливого и грамотного человека. Всех остальных участников сообщества, очень прошу не оставлять ответы или комментарии по данному вопросу, не изменять репутацию вопроса. Вопрос адресован только одному человеку, т.к. не имею прямой связи с ним.

Я считаю неправомерным, выходящим за пределы полномочий, поступок модератора PashaPash. Если возможно просмотреть историю комментариваев - прошу ее обнародовать или просто прочитать, у меня нет возможности выложить полную переписку, предоставлю только то что сохранилось у меня.

Сам вопрос, который привел к дискуссии тут: [Что делают указатели в приведенном методе?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/585802/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5?noredirect=1#585834)

Часть переписки между мной и модератором тут:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Вопрос:** прошу дать профессиональную оценку правомерности действий модератора PashaPash. Прошу рассмотреть две позиции: а) неправомерное удаление корректных, формально не нарушающих правил сообщества, но "неугодных" комментариев. б) блокировку аккаунта, выглядело это так, что модератору просто надоело спорить (или не хватило аргументов\чувства собственной правоты) и он неправомерно (из личной прихоти, граничащей с проявлением слабости) заблокировал аккаунт, воспользовавшись своей властью тут.

---

p.s. ну и довольно неприятная вещь, зачем делать из человека - ненормального? Зачем выбран такой текст в аккаунте: "Данная учётная запись временно заблокирована **чтобы позволить участнику успокоиться**. Срок действия блокировки истечет через 7 дней." 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

*p.p.s пришлось создать новый временный аккаунт, т.к. блокировка старого аккаунта не дает создавать сообщения на мете. Основной заблокированный [аккаунт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/211694/align).*

---

p.p.s. сообщество, почитайте, посмейтесь: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33266690#33266690

Возможно и Вас когда нибудь так обольют г... за глаза.

Comment: *Вопрос адресован только одному человеку, т.к. не имею прямой связи с ним.* -- вы его профиль вообще открывали? :)

Comment: Если вы хотели свзяаться напрямую с @NicolasChabanovsky - вам стоило просто ответить на его сообщение в личной почте.

Comment: @D-side, да, конечно. Но, можете мне не верить, всеми указанными средствами связи (за исключением почты) - я не пользуюсь. А почта - очень ненадежный метод, сообщения иногда попадают в "спам", и остаются без ответа. Для использования мобильного телефона вопрос не имеет достаточной срочности. Очень прошу больше не комментировать данный вопрос.

Comment: @PashaPash, я уже почти дописал вопрос, когда получил сообщение в личную почту. До этого 1 час ждал реакции на просьбу разблокировать аккаунт для постинга вопроса на мете.  Пусть будет тут. Хотелось бы так же чтобы ответ был гласным.

Comment: @Prisoner боюсь, что опубликовав этот вопрос на Мете вы априори обратились **ко всему сообществу**, и потому комментировать будут все, кто считает нужным. Если вы хотите гласности ответа, чтобы сообщество увидело неправомерность ситуации, сообщество же должно увидеть и доказательства неправомерности действий, т. е. для этого комментарии приведшие к конфликту должны быть опубликованы. В противном случае этому вопросу нечего делать на Мете: он не позволит разрешить аналогичные ситуации в будущем по той причине, что описание ситуации неполное. У меня всё.

Comment: @D-side, есть ли какая либо возможность дать доступ к вопросу только NicolasChabanovsky не удаляя вопроса?

Comment: @Prisoner естественно нет, у нас тут свобода слова

Comment: @Prisoner можно попросить NicolasChabanovsky поставить защиту на вопрос (от всех, хотя для модераторов она всё равно не действует), но на его месте я бы не стал её ставить. На StackOverflow сильнО влияние сообщества и такие случаи полагается решать публично, с участием влиятельных участников сообщества (и речь не только о модераторах). Лично я, к примеру, успел только к самому окончанию конфликта, когда тот уже скатился в неконструктивный флейм, и своими глазами видел доказательства только в пользу модератора. Мне интересно увидеть доказательства и с другой стороны.

Comment: @D-side, прочтите, пожалуйста, комментарии под ответом модератора. Там объясняется часть, к большому сожалению полной переписки не осталось. А под конец дискуссии я просто был возмущен пренебрежением правилами самим модератором, и, возможно, вел себя некорректно.

Comment: @Prisoner это, наверное, нужно адресовать не вам, но эти комментарии читаем не только мы двое. Я рассчитываю, что модераторы поймут в чём дело и предоставят соответствующие сведения. Потому что если этого не будет, то в вопросе нет никакого смысла для сообщества, а значит и для Меты.

Comment: @D-side, я полность с Вами согласен. И в самом вопросе я предложил сделать тоже самое, обнародовать удаленные комментарии. Я не оскорблял сообщество в целом или какого то конкретного обозримого участника в частности.

Comment: _остальных участников ... прошу не оставлять ответы или комментарии_ - Э, нет! У нас тут свобода слова! Кто хочет, тот и комментирует.

Comment: Правильно я понимаю, что весь сыр-бор начался из-за какого-то жалкого минуса (судя по экранным снимкам @NickVolynkin-а)? В таком случае **абсолютно все** участники должны начать кидаться друг в друга тухлыми помидорами. Ведь каждого хотя бы раз, но минусанули.

Comment: @Arhad, ага. Так многие и кидаются, только начинают ставить минусы всем подряд, на кого падет подозрение =) И с этим уже много раз предлагали на мете бороться разными методами, но дело так и не сдвинулось с места.

Comment: `начинают ставить минусы ... на кого падет подозрение` — так массовые минусы [вроде бы откатываются автоматом](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4006/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F/4007#4007).

Comment: @Arhad, а про массовость не кто и не говорит. Заподозрил какого то участника в том, что он влепил тебе минус, пробежался по его топовым ответам, влепил ему в топовый ответ минус.

Comment: Ну тогда пусть тому, кто минусует без объяснения причин, будет пусто и изжога ;-) . Всё равно он не сможет отнять существенной репутации (считанные минусы по -2 балла каждый, при дальнейшем усердии через сутки сработает откат всей серии).

Comment: @Arhad, тем не менее теряется репутация вопроса, теряется интерес к нему от профессионалов.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Соглашусь, вы не использовали нецензурную лексику в своих комментариях, и, возможно, в рамках социальных норм своего окружения действовали так, как требует ситуация. Но следует учесть следующие.

1. Чтобы оскорбить не обязательно использовать нецензурную лексику. Можно оскорбить «теплыми» словами. Позвольте пояснить. Возьмем, к примеру, слово «овощ». Если мы говорим о чем–то, что растет на грядке в контексте похода в магазин, вряд ли кто–либо сочтет это слово за оскорбление, но если вы начнете называть «овощем» вашего коллегу, не думаю, что он придет в восторг. Контекст имеет значение. Грубость, даже культурным языком, – недопустима в профессиональном сообществе.
2. Мы все живем в разном социальном окружении, в разных культурах. То, что допустимо для одного, может быть нонсенсом для другого. Зачастую мы ошибочно переносим шаблоны социального поведения из нашего повседневного общества, которое отличается от общества к обществу, в профессиональное сообщество, которое более или менее одинаково. Особенно часто это происходит в момент «возбуждения» (любой волнительный момент). Результатом практически всегда является конфликт, по сути, из–за неверного толкования контекста одной из сторон (мы понимаем чужие слова в контексте своего локального сообщества, а не высказывающегося человека). Единственным путем продуктивной работы является профессиональный язык в любой ситуации без использования общепринятых «шаблонов» локальных культур.
3. Чем раньше отреагирует модератор на признаки неконструктивного взаимодействия, тем меньше негативных последствий будет для сообщества. Удаление грубых комментариев – первый шаг к устранению эскалации конфликта.
4. На мой взгляд, модератор – это человек с крайне сильными положительными чувствами к коллегам. Будучи знатоком, он вкладывает огромный личный ресурс в развитее сообщества по средствам модерации. Уверяю вас, модераторами движет исключительно благородные мотивы. Комментарии, сделанные модераторами, на мой взгляд, следует рассматривать как попытку помочь, улучишь ситуации и предоставить взгляд со стороны. Им просто незачем обижать коллег, которые доверились им, назначив модераторами.

---

Мета – это место, где участники сообщества собираются, чтобы найти решение проблемы *вместе*. Публикуя вопрос на Мете, пожалуйста, ожидайте, что высказываться будет каждый, у кого есть отличающийся от уже высказанных взгляд на ситуацию.

Хоть я и модерирую сайт активно, пользуясь инструментами модератора, я на столько же модератор, насколько и любой участник с 20 000 и более баллами репутацией. Моя основная задача как сотрудника компании – поддерживать продуктивное взаимодействие сообщества с компанией и быть уверенным, что компания понимает и учитывает нужды сообщества, а также поддерживать здоровый рост проекта. Модераторы от сообщества, в свою очередь, легитимные представители общественного мнения. Они были выбраны другими участниками в результате [демократического голосования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/1).

Comment: 1) почитайте чат: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33266690#33266690

Comment: 2) почему Вы опустили грубые комментарии модератора PashaPash (или как выразился Nick Volynkin - императивную формулировку)? Кто дал ему такое право? Модератор всегда так должен действовать? Почему я не позволяю себе задать вопрос какому то конкретному участнику сообщества, и приказать ему дать мне ответ?

Comment: Мне особенно понравилась цитата из чата: "Вот придёт Николас и оттаскает нас за бороды." На самом деле я не имел ввиду подобное, мне не нужно чтобы Вы разбирались, таскали кого то за бороды. Мне нужно чтобы приняли какие то меры, боролись с грубостью и модераторов и пользователей. В справке говорится - будьте доброжелательны, где эта доброжелательность проявилась в действиях или цитатах модераторов?

Comment: Ладно, бог с вами. Суть я понял, спасибо за ответ. Оставьте пожалуйста вопрос и чат для будущих пользователей.

Comment: @Prisoner Чат – отдельный вопрос. Обсуждая чат мы можем уйти от основной темы. Задав вопрос на Мете, вы адресовали его сообществу, дав тем самым право всем участников, включая PashaPash и NickVolynkin публиковать ответы.

Comment: Ссылку на чат дал в своем ответе Nick Volynkin. Как то не видно там: "Уверяю вас, модераторами движет исключительно благородные мотивы. Комментарии, сделанные модераторами, на мой взгляд, следует рассматривать как попытку помочь, улучишь ситуации и предоставить взгляд со стороны". Там видно только стёб ;-)

Comment: И да, профессиональной культурой общения в чате не блещут, последний перл от утки: `@VladD согласен кстати. Не то что издевательски, просто слишком честно. Это все равно что сказать "участник забанен за то что д_____б. Даже если он действительно такой, ему оч не хочется это признавать.`

Comment: Если это профессиональный язык - увольте, не нужно такое сообщество. Смешно читать чат и видеть такое в вашем ответе: "Грубость, даже культурным языком, – недопустима в профессиональном сообществе." ;-)

Comment: @Prisoner вы так болезненно реагируете на реплики из чата, будто принимаете их на свой счёт, когда совсем недавно утверждали, что ваши оскорбления адресованы чисто абстрактному минусатору и никого лично оскорбить не должны. Выходит, всё-таки могут и от этого нужно воздерживаться?

Comment: @D-side, прочитайте чат внимательно, часть реплик из чата направлены конкретно в мой адрес. Так же действительно смешно читать о каком то "профессионильном языке" после прочтения чата.

Comment: @D-side и я не "болезненно реагирую". Мне просто любопытно наблюдать как люди врут себе в лицо, кидаясь громкими заявлениями о "профессиональном языке", о "оскорблении тебя модератором только в благих намерениях". Все это звучит как политиканские перлы...

Comment: @Prisoner нормы поведения в чате (являющегося [третьим местом](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/04/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/) рядом с сайтом и Метой) значительно мягче, поскольку у чата совершенно другая задача и значительно меньше посетителей, а посему позволительны выразительные средства вроде преувеличения, сарказма, иронии и юмора. Скорее всего, сделайте вы это в чате, вам бы весело ответили чем-то таким же и забыли об этом. Но на сайте нормы заметно строже.

Comment: @D-side, Вы не поняли мой комментарий. Что в чате, что на основных сайтах - модерируют, отвечают, "помогают в благих намерениях" одни и те же люди. И нормы общения у этих людей - далеки от идеала, описанного Николасом. Да и чат - это хоть менее посещаемое, но все же общественное место.

Comment: @Prisoner люди одинаковые, места разные, и нормы в этих местах разные. Шокирующая правда: модераторам катастрофически часто приходится лицемерить, дабы соблюдать нормы модерируемых мест и поддерживать статус-кво. Это не означает, что они вынуждены лицемерить всегда и везде.

Comment: @D-side, лицемерие - есть порок, в любом его проявлении. Вам понравится когда вам на уши лапшу наматывают, а Вы должны с восторгом стоить, терпеть, и улыбаться? ;-)

Comment: @Prisoner вот вы сейчас примерно и описали состояние модератора, отчаянно старающегося не сорваться и отвечать корректно даже на прямые оскорбления.

Comment: @Prisoner. Я не модератор, мне можно формулировки не вытачивать. Посмотри блин в зеркало, фарисей.

Comment: @D-side, так в том то и дело что модератор "сорвался". Это не позволительно, модератор - не "абы кто", модератор - "народно" выбранное лицо, гордость и пример для подражания сообщества.

Comment: @Утка, не Вам давать советы с вашей "культурой общения", вы больше  похожи на другое пернатое создание, рвущееся в бой =) Вот только смотрите чтобы у вас, со слов из чата, не "бомбануло".

Comment: @Prisoner если рассматривать "долго терпел систематические нарушения правил, но внезапно перестал" как "сорвался", то да, он сорвался, и в совершенно правильном направлении: выписал нарушителю блокировку и ликвидировал следы конфликта как излишний "шум", не имеющий отношения к вопросам и ответам.

Comment: @D-side, тем не менее он откровенно грубо выразил свои требования. Если бы небыло грубости с его стороны - небыло бы и конфликта. Частично сам модератор виноват в таком развитии событий.

Comment: @Prisoner сообщество, судя по голосам и развёрнутому мнению ключевых лиц, считает, что модератор был достаточно корректен и совершенно правомерен в своих действиях. Боюсь, вам нечего этому противопоставить.

Comment: @D-side, не мне вам объяснять что такое репутация в данном контексте. Сообщество - как озеро, куда дует ветер - там и волны.

Comment: @Prisoner, вы можете явно указать, какой именно комментарий PashaPash вы считаете грубым?

Comment: @Nofate, конкретно этот: http://storage8.static.itmages.ru/i/16/1102/h_1478109076_7578682_12722e7925.jpg Звучало это так: "Мне плевать на твое мнение, держи его при себе и молчи в тряпочку".

Answer (score 16):

> Если возможно просмотреть историю комментариваев - прошу ее обнародовать или просто прочитать

Пожалуйста. Вот комментарии, которые были удалены в первый заход. Делаю скриншоты "внахлёст", чтобы было видно, что ничего не пропущено.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробую объяснить, в чём тут проблема. Вы демонстрируете неуважительное отношение к другим участникам и пытаетесь их оскорбить сравнением с животными. У нас так не принято. Считаете, что кто-то неправ - аргументируйте. В целом в вашей позиции есть рациональное зерно: небольшая доля минусов действительно прилетает из-за непонимания вопроса. Но форма выражения этой позиции совершенно неуместная.

Дальше:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Вы в упор не хотите замечать грубости, приказного тона, в котором были составлены комментарии модератора PashaPash.

Грубости со стороны PashaPash не вижу. Императивные формулировки вижу. Как мне кажется, они вполне уместны в ситуации, когда кто-то призывает вас к соблюдению правил, которые приняты на этом сайте. Эти рекомендации и должны быть сформулированы императивно, потому что иначе могут быть восприняты как необязательные.

1. Если хотите обсудить комментарии и минусы - задайте вопрос на Мете.
2. Если хотите поменять правила или оспорить действия модератора - задайте вопрос на Мете.
3. Не используйте комментарии к вопросу для обсуждения чего-то кроме вопроса и ответов.

> Кто дал ему такое право?

[Сообщество с помощью голосования](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2226/181472) возложило на него обязанность доносить правила до участников. Право есть у всех, обязанность есть только у модераторов. Вот в рамках этой обязанности он и доносит лучшим способом, которым умеет.

Если вы знаете, как можно было бы иначе написать, чтобы лучше и быстрее объяснить вам суть проблемы - расскажите нам, мы возьмём на вооружение. Я вот уже час дополняю этот ответ, но до сих пор не уверен, смог ли до вас достучаться.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот комментарии под ответом, после блокировки вопроса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы пытаетесь оскорбить PashaPash сравнением с женщинами. Давайте приведу аналогию. Представьте, что кто-то кому-то пишет:

> Признайте уже, что вы не правы. А то ведёте себя прямо как Align.

Вам бы понравилось, что сравнением с вами кого-то вот так ругают? Вот и женщинам не понравится.

---

> Прошу рассмотреть две позиции: а) неправомерное удаление корректных, формально не нарушающих правил сообщества, но "неугодных" комментариев.

Первая порция комментариев была удалена из-за оскорбительного содержимого. Потом все комментарии вместе были удалены потому, что не относились к сути заданного вопроса. Таковы правила, комментарии - это инструмент для уточнения подробностей по вопросу, а не выяснения отношений.

> б) блокировку аккаунта, выглядело это так, что модератору просто надоело спорить (или не хватило аргументов\чувства собственной правоты) и он неправомерно (из личной прихоти, граничащей с проявлением слабости) заблокировал аккаунт, воспользовавшись своей властью тут

Модератор не может спорить и уговаривать вас неограниченно. Эта работа не оплачивается, время на модерацию - это личное время человека.

Аккаунт был заблокирован вполне в соответствии с правилами сайта. Вот если бы он видел, но никак не вмешивался, не удалял комментарии и не наводил порядок, это было бы некорректно. Тогда можно было бы спросить: "а почему модератор не выполняет своих обязанностей".

> прошу дать профессиональную оценку правомерности действий модератора PashaPash

Peer review: думаю, лучше было бы не отвечать в комментарии, а сразу написать личное сообщение с кратким описанием проблемы и парой ссылок. И всю остальную переписку вести там.

---

К слову:

> @PashaPash, зачем Вы изменили вопрос? И что конкретно поменяли?

Он поменял форматирование кода, конкретно - отступы.

---

> так же есть такое понятие как "панибратство", люди, которые долго работают вместе, стараются друг другу помогать и выручать в трудные моменты

Я, как и вы, однажды тоже писал разгромный пост о неподобающем поведении модератора. Поверьте, если есть за что покритиковать, я покритикую.

Comment: Вам не кажется что своими комментариями и иронией Вы подливаете масла в конфликт? Именно поэтому я жду ответа только от @Nicolas Chabanovsky, который является настоящим сотрудником компании, модератором с многолетним стажем. Он сможет справедливо и непредвзято оценить данный вопрос, не вставляя едкие и оскорбительные комментарии.

Comment: @Prisoner Как я уже заметил в комментариях под вопросом, написав на Мету, вы обратились к сообществу. Как Nick Volynkin, так и PashaPash являются **выборными модераторами от сообщества**. Поэтому они имеют даже большее право высказываться от лица сообщества, чем Николас. Вы можете игнорировать их ответы, если считаете их нерелевантными. Но как можете видеть из голосов, сообщество так не считает.

Comment: @D-side, потому что "народный модератор" Nick Volynkin надергал цитат из контекста, вставил едкие и оскорбительные комментарии. Сообщество довольно...

Comment: @D-side, так же есть такое понятие как "панибратство", люди, которые долго работают вместе, стараются друг другу помогать и выручать в трудные моменты.

Comment: @Prisoner вы считаете, что какие-то комментарии, которые могут оправдать вашу позицию, опущены на скриншотах? Можете их описать хотя бы примерно? Потому что я даже не представляю, что там такое может быть, что могло бы оправдать "надёрганные цитаты".

Comment: @D-side, полный, последовательны по времени лог комментариев.

Comment: @Prisoner ироничный комментарий был добавлен с целью разрядить обстановку, но раз не вышло, я удалил его из текста. Сожалею, если я вас им задел. В остальном моя цель - дать вам обратную связь, чтобы помочь вам понять, что произошло и как можно в следующий раз сделать лучше.

Comment: @D-side, ну и чисто по человечески - Вам бы было приятно если бы Вы были на моем месте, а сторонний "народный" модератор вставлял подобные едкие и оскорбительные комментарии?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, прошу вернуть Ваши едкие комментарии в исходном виде в ответ.

Comment: @Prisoner полный последовательный лог добавил. Комментарий не верну, но он навечно сохранён в истории ответа, а история доступна всем.

Comment: @Prisoner вы подтверждаете, что это **полный** лог и никакие существенные реплики в нём не опущены?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, перечитал ответ с учетом обновлений. Вы старательное обходите углы. Вы в упор не хотите замечать грубости, приказного тона, в котором были составлены комментарии модератора PashaPash. Кто дал ему такое право?

Comment: @D-side, да, но тем не менее Nick Volynkin обошел много острых углов в своем ответе.

Comment: @Prisoner это вторично. Важно, что теперь есть доказательная база: лог, подлинность которого вы подтверждаете. Теперь у участников есть возможность обоснованно принимать ту или иную сторону конфликта. Раз уж вы решили вынести конфликт на публику.

Comment: @D-side, а я все еще не теряю надежду увидеть ответ Николоса. Для меня его мнение решающее в данном вопросе.

Comment: @Prisoner добавил ответ про углы, грубость и приказной тон.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, иронию понял, особенно прочитав чат с комментариями. Так Вы определяете мнение сообщества насчет "императивного" тона? В чате, где и 1% всего RU сообщества не наберется? Где один Grundy чего стоит))

Comment: @Prisoner я обращался не за мнением всего сообщества, а просто за мнением и рациональными аргументами. Но можно вынести это на Мету.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я думаю стоит это вынести на мету. Вот только инициатором данного не хочу быть, и так много г... на меня в чате вылели.

Comment: Сообщество, почитайте, посмейтесь: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33266690#33266690

Comment: Возможно и вас так г.... обольют когда нибудь тут за глаза...

Comment: @Prisoner, Вам больше нравится когда в глаза? Я готов! Вы сами тут как из шланга поливаете, и еще другим запретить пытаетесь.

Answer (score 15):

Во первых, если вы хотели связаться напрямую с @NicolasChabanovsky - вам стоило просто ответить на его сообщение в личной почте.

Вы хотите подробного объяснения причин блокировки? ок, смотрите:

- Вы начали нелестно отзываться о других участниках в комментариях к вопросу.
- Вас сразу же попросили перестать оскорблять других участников - в первом же комментарии (он уже удален к моменту снятия скриншотов)
- Вы продолжили сравнивать других участников с животными
- В вопрос пришел модератор (я), почистил все, посчитал что гнев вы излили, и можно обойтись без суровых мер.
- Вы начали возмущаться. Я *дважды* попросил вас не флудить в комментариях, перестать оскорблять других участников и перейти на мету.
- После второго преупреждения я заблокировал комментарии к вопросу с вполне *однозначной предупредительной надписью*.
- Вы перешли в комментарии в первому же ответу и там продолжили, уже с переходом на личности.

Я посчитал это грубым нарушением принципа [be nice](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) и заблокировал вашу учетную запись.

Вы получили три предупреждение от модераторов, еще несколько - от проходящих мимо участников, проигнорировали их и получили обещанный бан.

Comment: Вас не смущает, в какой именно форме Вы выразили протест? По поводу трех предупреждений от модераторов - небыло никаких предупрждений, либо я не видел их т.к. банально не знал о них. Небыло никаких уведомлений. И да, я просил ответить сотрудника компании @Nicolas Chabanovsky, а не Вас.

Comment: И наверное самое важное - я сравнивал с животными только тех абстрактных участников, которые хорошему вопросу просто так ставят минусы, никак не обосновав его. Я не оскорблял сообщество в целости или какого то участника в частности. Можете выложить все комментарии на обозрение Николаса.

Comment: @Prisoner Николас может видеть удаленные комментарии. Мне все равно кого вы просили ответить - у нас тут свобода слова. Задав вопрос на мете вы автоматически соглашаетесь с тем, что ответить на него может кто угодно. Мне неважно, сравнивали ли вы с животными всех подряд, или конкретных участников (второе же хуже, нет? это же прямые оскорбления конкретных людей). Вас предупредили, попросили перестать, вы проигнорировали - я принял меры.

Comment: Вы путаете абстрактное с конкретным. Повторюсь, я не оскорблял сообщество в целости или какого то участника в частности. В какой форме меня "попросили" перестать - уже неважно? В данном контексте, с вашей стороны "предупредили" аналогично "указали/приказали". Никакой доброжелательности, к которой призывает справка - небыло и в помине. Все сугубо в приказном тоне.

Comment: @Prisoner я тоже повторюсь - оскорбляли. неназванных минусаторов, Pavel Mayorov и лично меня. Сравнения с животными, намеки на несоответствие поведения полу, и предложения заняться саморазвитием - это нарушение be nice. Не ждите от модераторов доброжелательности, если сами ее не проявляете. Никто не будет ходить и на *каждое ваше сообщение* отвечать "ну зачем вы так, минусаторы же тоже люди, повежливее". Вам сделали явное и прямое предупреждение, сразу же - вы его прямо проигнорировали. Сами виноваты.

Comment: Тогда Вам должно быть вдвоейне стыдно. Вы, опытный участник, поставили минус и не оставили комментария, который помог бы улучшить вопрос, как рекомендует интерфейс. По поводу доброжелательности - никто не давал Вам права что-то кому то приказывать. Вы не начальник, Вы не имеете подобного права. Статус модератора не делает Вас избранным\особенным. Можно хотябы сейчас узнать - за что Вы поставили минус вопросу? Только обоснованное, а не зависящее от настроения, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Prisoner причем я к улучшению вашего вопроса?

Comment: @Prisoner а, понял - нет, минусы там не от Pavel Mayorov - я имел ввиду три категории оскорбленных. т.е. там не от Pavel Mayorov минус. В любом случае - вы получили развернутый ответ о причинах блокировки. У вас остались еще какие-то вопросы по этому поводу?

Comment: Я жду конкретный ответ от сотрудника компании @NicolasChabanovsky.

Comment: @Prisoner: Заметьте, что пользователи **имеют право** ставить минус чему угодно без обоснований. Точно так же, как и плюсы, кстати. Вы можете _попросить_ минусовавшего объяснить свою позицию, но никак не потребовать.

Comment: @VladD, Вот Вы - VladD, заслуженный участник сообщества. А минус поставило абстрактное существо, которого я в глаза никогда не видел и не слышал о нем. Как может обидеться абстрактное существо - на просьбу\приказ или назовите как хотите - за что оно поставило минус? Считайте что аноним - это некий абстрактный пользователь в вашей базе данных, которого вы никогда не видели. Как он может на что то обидеться?

Comment: @Prisoner: Ну, поставивший минус — это конкретный человек, и он вполне может обидеться. То, что мы с вами его не знаем, ещё ведь не означает, что мы можем его обижать?

Comment: @VladD, а Вас не смущает что в 99% случаев Вы никогда не видите этого человека? Человек то может быть конкретный, но толку от него как от абстрактного... Если бы конкретный человек отозвался и аргументировал свой минус - я бы извинился и удалил комментарий, но только если бы действительно аргументировал. А не влепил от балды по воле настроения...

Comment: @Prisoner: Мы ведь с вами сейчас друг друга тоже не видим, и может быть и не увидим никогда. Но мы ведь можем нормально общаться? В любом случае, мне кажется, что вам не стоит обижаться на минусы. Мне ставили много минусов, иногда на мой взгляд незаслуженных. Ну так я ж могу и ошибаться. Так что я не обращаю внимания и стараюсь давать хорошие ответы, когда получается.

Comment: @Prisoner видите ли в чем проблема - минус вам поставило абстрактное существо - а прочитал ваше оскорбление я. И мне было неприятно его читать.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, не хотелось бы продолжать дискуссию, но сугубо из уважения к Вам как к профессионалу отвечу: у меня небыло умысла оскорблять Вас или других людей, которые читали мой вопрос. Если бы я захотел оскорбить Вас - я бы написал прямо. Но в комментарии небыло Вашего ника, как и ников других участников. Вы должны были это понять.

Comment: @Prisoner пожалуйста, с уточнениями - на основной сайт. Мета не для этого.

Comment: @Prisoner это ваша проблема, а не моя. И точно не проблема участника PashaPash, в комментариях к чьему сообщению.вы патаетесь начать обсуждение. Больше я вам ничего тут не отвечу.

Answer (score 4):

Кратко поведаю своё видение того, что сопутствует проблеме, поднятой в данном посте.

---

---

### О минусах в целом

Всё больше убеждаюсь в **их необходимости**, и благодаря им в том числе сайты сети Stack Exchange эффективнее конкурирующих.

- Вынуждают писать качественные вопросы и ответы, иначе заминусуют.
- Во многом и они тоже пресекают в сообщениях оффтоп, неконструктивную полемику, «флуд».

---

---

### О проблеме неаргументированных минусов

**Она присутствует**. Когда тебе, не комментируя, ставят минусы, непонятно за что, это неприятно, и может оттолкнуть от участия в сайтах Stack Exchange. Предложения на данный момент обсуждаются [**здесь**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4015/199934).

---

---

### Что делать, если поставили неаргументированные минусы

- **Не париться на этот счёт**. Не завидую жизненным приоритетам сильно переживающих из-за дизлайков.
- Вспомнить, что **в целом система работает. Если регулярно писать хорошие вопросы и ответы, плюсов будет гораздо больше.** Так, Ваш [**вопрос про указатели**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/585802/199934) собрал больше положительных оценок, хоть здешних участников трудно заподозрить в особой Любви к Вам. И участникам с пятизначным рейтингом прилетают минусы, но они неуклонно повышают свою репутацию.

---

---

### О Вашем поведении

Не считаю, что оно в высшей мере конструктивно. Возьмём пример, с чего всё начиналось:

> А скорее всего кто-то встал не с той ноги, чем то ему не понравился вопрос, он влепил за него минус. Я буду относиться к таким индивидам как к животным - как к животным, движимым животными инстинктами, большего они не заслуживают.

**Подобные «скорее всего» ну просто никогда не имеют общего с реальностью**. Вы не можете знать мотивов неизвестных, проминусовавших Вас, но вынесли в их отношении не самое приятное сравнение.

> ```
> Исследуйте результат, а не цели; что человек сделал, не предполагая, о чём он думал.
> ```

(Немного оффтопа. К счастью, времена, когда каждый этологический вопрос объяснялся «волшебным» словом «инстинкт» остались в прошлом зоопсихологии. Животные — развитые существа со сложной структурой мышления.)

---

---

### О поведении участников этого треда

Можно заметить обстоятельство, что «текучка» мета-активных участников достаточно невелика. Да, кто-то уходит, другие приходят, но в целом хорошо знакомые друг с другом костяк значительных изменений не претерпевает. Следствием чего служат единообразие во мнениях и круговая порука.

В Stack Overflow на русском уровень конструктивности общения выше, чем в большинстве сообществ, [**демагогии**](http://kristinita.ru/Giologica/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE) поменьше, но сказать, что она отсутствует, как класс, тоже нельзя.

Выражая точку зрения, отличную от мнений большинства, будьте готовы к претензиям по частностям, а не ключевой точке разногласий. Если будете отвечать на эти частности, да ещё и не идеальным тоном, комментировать будут уже ваши комментарии, всё дальше и дальше отдаляясь от сути разногласий.

И главное — невысока вероятность, что за Вас кто-то подпишется. Как бы ни был неправ Ваш оппонент, они ни словом его не осудят; **каждое сообщение будет направлено против Вас**.

Что делать:

Если занимаетесь социологией/психологией/логикой — это прекрасный материал для Ваших статей. Нет — совершенствование поведенческих навыков в конфликтных ситуациях никому ещё не навредило.

---

---

### О модераторском произволе

**Существующие условия ему потворствуют.**

1. **Отсутствует открытость** — необходимая составляющая демократического общества. Нельзя посмотреть список действий, находящихся в привилегии модераторов, чтобы выносить по ним оценочные суждения. Существует практика удалений — а удалённое-то не проверишь. Вместо ссылки на действие, приведшее к бану, можно увидеть только это «чтобы позволить участнику успокоиться». Чем меньше открытости, тем легче совершать то, что именуется «произволом».
2. **Нет правил, регламентирующих действия, находящиеся в привилегии модераторов**. Примерного формата: `неправомерное действие (спам, угроза, мат и т. д.) → рекомендуемый срок блокировки или же предпочтительное вежливое указание со ссылкой на правила → обоснование целесообразности срока бана`. Отсутствует выраженная в правилах шкала прогрессивных блокировок; фраз, что баны — не наказание, а применяются для предотвращения вреда. Как результат — завышенные сроки блокировок.

Действия, находящиеся в привилегии модераторов — «тёмная сторона» Stack Overflow на русском. В целом модераторы руководствуются своими неписаными правилами, которые они уже многократно применяли. Но будьте готовы, что эти неписаные правила окажутся для Вас неприятными.

---

---

### О свободе слова на Stack Overflow

Понятие «свободы слова» больше теоретическое и зависимое от взглядов/мнений влиятельных членов объединений и предписаний крутых дядь свыше. Допустимый уровень свободы везде свой и различен: узнать его можно, просматривая обсуждения, обращая в них внимание, как дозволено говорить участницам и участникам данного конкретного сообщества. Если в чате здесь допускаются вольности, то в сообщениях и комментариях по сложившейся практике они пресекаются. **В Stack Overflow на русском достаточно жёсткое отношение к неуважительным репликам**; возможно, жёстче, чем в любом из программистских сообществ, в которых Вы принимали участие.

Относятся к этому по-разному. Лично я отнюдь не поощряю хамство и оскорбления.