# non inclusive language в комментариях и вопросах

Tags: обсуждение, правила

Существует такой термин *non inclusive language*, перевода, который бы мне понравился, я не нашел. Но суть следующая - это язык который разделяет людей на группы и носит негативную эмоциональную окраску. Примеры выражений с использованием такого языка: **все нормальные люди**, **как все белые люди**, **разве вы этого не знали**, **это известно всем** и т.д. Я считаю, что подобные выражения использовать недопустимо - особенно в комментариях. Это мое персональное мнение, а не попытка навязать новые правила.

Текст комментария:

> Зачем такой гемор? может все же откатить транзакцию и попытаться снова, как все белые люди? Иначе какой смысл был вообще изобретать транзакции?

Считает ли вы подобные комментарии нуждающимися в коррекции? Если да, то как улучшить качество подобных комментариев?

**UPD:**

Почему я поднял этот вопрос?

Я достаточно часто слышал от людей, не связанных с IT сообществом, что члены IT сообщества грубые, злые и, не умеющие общаться, люди. Меня всегда это удивляло. Да, я встречал неприятных людей, но их было небольшое количество. Поэтому я стал больше интересоваться этим вопросом и таким образом вышел на множество статей связанных с общением. Также я встретил несколько статей с извинениями за слова, которые я бы не посчитал оскорбительными.

Например, вот [извинения](https://gist.github.com/unclebob/2508746) от Ucle Bob

Поговорив, а в основном, послушав других людей, я обнаружил печальную закономерность - я часто использую слова и фразы, которые для меня звучат нормально, а для других оскорбительно. Почему оскорбительно? Потому, что я никогда не задумывался, как звучат мои слова для других. Я привык говорить, так как я говорю. Но поскольку моя цель это общение, то я начал прислушиваться к обратной связи. И теперь стараюсь обращать внимание на то, что я пишу. Да, это требует усилий, но я считаю, что игра стоит свеч. Особенно для сайта вопросов-ответов. Я прихожу сюда учить и делиться знаниями. Если можно сделать ответ "приятным" и понятным для большой группы людей просто используя иные формулировки, то это моя прямая обязанность - найти эти слова и формулировки.

Я часто вижу (да и сам пишу) подобные фразы и поэтому я решил поднять этот вопрос.

Я не предлагаю запрещать людям что-то делать или говорить! Я предлагаю людям обращать внимание на то, как они дают ответы и какие комментарии оставляют. На мой взгляд использование *inclusive language* делает ответ/комментарий более понятным. И при этом не ущемляет право отвечающего/комментирующего на самовыражение в рамках вопроса.

**UPD2**:

Мой целью не является навязать мое мнение сообществу или ограничить кого-то в правах. Моя цель - выяснить отношение сообщества к этому вопросу. Я предлагаю всем желающим подумать над этим и прийти к какому-нибудь выводу.

Comment: Кажется, это называют "дискриминирующие высказывания". А можно парочку примеров реальных комментариев?

Comment: вы хотите ссылку на комментарий или просто текст комментария?

Comment: Не принципиально. Ссылка, конечно, была бы не лишней (как источник), но лучше сам пример текста прямо в вопросе.

Comment: @D-side к сожалению, я не знаю как сделать ссылку на комментарий. Добавил ссылку на вопрос.

Comment: Ссылка на комментарий находится на времени его оставления. Адрес можно скопировать с него.

Comment: @D-side спасибо. Буду знать.

Comment: `подобные выражения использовать недопустимо` - подобные это какие? В которых, вы почему-то посчитали, есть оскорбление или дискриминация?

Comment: Устал, не очень хорошо соображаю, чтобы написать толковый и неодносторонний ответ. Поэтому свой ответ пока что удалю, впоследствии доработаю и верну.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский выражения использующие non inclusive language. я поэтом и задал этот вопрос, что бы узнать мнение сообщества. я знаю, что некоторых сообществах обращают внимание на язык, а в некоторых нет.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman не знаю о каких сообществах говорите, но сообщества состоят из разных людей и поэтому тут дело только в конкретных людях. Вот у вас конкретно это в голове взрощено как ассоциация с чем-то неподобающим, хоть ничего и не имелось в виду такого, что вы напридумывали. И сделать с этим ничего уже нельзя. Если так считаете — можете нажимать флаг на комментариях, которые считаете неправильными. С остальным разберутся модераторы.

Comment: Ну так и сама политкорректность по большому счету это non inclusive language, т.к. разделяет людей. Может просто стоит быть более терпимым к чужим слабостям?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я говорю в основном о сообществах в США. Я согласен с вами, что сообщества состоят из разных людей и поэтому я считаю важным, что бы каждый член сообщества чувствовал, что ему рады, чувствовал себя включенным, чувствовал себя защищенным от возможной агрессии. Особенно это важно для новых членов сообщества и членов которые отличаются от основной массы сообщества. Вы правы и по поводу взращенния  у меня в голове нового взгляда. Раньше я не обращал внимание на слова и не думал, что обычные (для меня) фразы могут звучать унизительно для других.

Comment: @avp поясните, что вы имеете в виду под: _политкорректность по большому счету это non inclusive language_?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman в общем, кмк, т.к. сообщество свободное, то вы вольны поступить как считаете правильным...Как я уже писал, например флагнуть..... Но так как я увидел, что это кому-то неприятно и вызывает совсем не тот смысл, какой имелся, я, конечно, от греха подальше, удалил коммент)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский у меня нет задачи пожаловаться. Я хочу начать дискуссию и в ходе дискуссии научиться быть большее человечным, и возможно научить других быть более человечными. Я понимаю, что вам неприятно, что я считаю ваш комментарий некорректным и прошу меня простить, что "прославил" вас таким образом. Возможно это было моей ошибкой.

Comment: В данном случае *политкорректность* это то, чем Вы обеспокоились

Comment: @MikhailVaysman мне не неприятно) Мне было непонятно) вот если меня забанят за то, что я не имел в виду — вот это будет неприятно xD

Comment: @avp я имел ввиду пояснить - почему политкорректность это non inclusive language?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский если хотите, то я могу удалить все комментарии с вашим именем и тогда не будет ссылок на вас. я просто перенесу свои ответы в мой вопрос в обезличенном  виде.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman все, кто нужно, уже всё знают) Пусть всё остается как есть

Comment: @АлексейШиманский хорошо. Еще раз прошу прощенья за это.

Comment: `почему политкорректность это non inclusive language?` -- потому что она принуждает к определенному поведению и разное отношение людей к этому принуждению разделяет их. Согласные и не согласные для начала начинают избегать друг друга.

Comment: @avp тут все зависит от людей. От их мотивов. Идея которую я разделяю и которую хочу выразить: давайте искать, то что нас объединяет, давайте объединятся, а не разделятся. Если я ищу способ объединится и ищу способ включить людей в сообщество, то я должен стараться не использовать слова, которые будут разъединять. Если кто-то разделяет мои идеи, то для него это не будет принуждением. Моя ошибка была в том, что я спросил про - надо ли наказывать? А надо было спросить - как улучшить комментарий? Я уже исправил это.

Comment: Да, давайте объединять, это правильно.

Comment: @avp а если бы вы узнали, что некоторые ваши слова (которые вы считаете нормальным) выглядят разделяющими для некоторых членов сообщества, что когда они слышат эти слова и фразы они чувствуют, что им не рады, что им не место в этом сообществе - что бы вы сделали?

Comment: Скорее всего, *ничего* (пусть сами справляются со своими обидами)

Comment: @avp вы не думаете, что это противоречит желанию объединится? Как я полагаю вы белый цисгендернный гетеросексуальный мужчина. В IT это основной тип людей. Это так называемые привилегированные члены сообщества. И то, что приемлемо для вас в общении с такими же белыми цисгендернными гетеросексуальнными мужчини легко может обидеть белую цисгендернную гетеросексуальнную женщину. Готовы ли вы учитывать этот факт? Или ей надо самой справляться с этим своими обидами? Заметьте я заменил всего лишь одну переменную.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, что-то надоело мне обсуждать эту тему и переливать из пустого в порожнее

Comment: @avp Хорошо. Спасибо за разъяснение вашей позиции.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman давайте все-таки не впадать в крайности. И давайте не путать устойчивые языковые конструкции с чем-то реально обидным, например, оскорблениями.
 
Не употребляйте, пожалуйста, цис- и транс- применительно к женщинам - это хорошо звучит, когда относится к хиральности молекул, но плохо, когда к чему-то еще. Да и кто сказал, что у женщин должна быть хиральность?

Comment: @merletta я не впадаю в крайности. Я говорю не об обиде, а о разделении. Неважно какой эпитет употребить - белый, черный, умный - это разделяет. Есть мы (белые, черные, умные) и они (остальные). Возможно я не правильно перевел английскую фразу. Если у вас есть возможность, то переведите её для меня - white straight cisgender man (woman), так что бы она не была для вас обидной.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman вам не кажется, что применение этой фразы к женщине само по себе *разделяет* в ваших терминах?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman давайте все-таки лучше будем писать код, а не прокрастинировать? Любая подобная фраза не является принципиально важной частью ответа на вопрос по программированию. Люди приходят сюда получать ответы на свои вопросы именно про него, а не уточнять, как правильно называть половую принадлежность друг друга.

Comment: @Nofate разделяет. Точно так же как и любая характеристика. Но в данном случае мне надо было разделить.

Comment: @merletta как верно замечено ниже мы не безэмоциональные машины и если есть выбор сделать ответ более приятным для вопрошающего, то почему бы не приложить для этого усилий? Ведь когда кто-то пишет ответ на вопрос - его цель передать информацию, научить вопрошающего. Иначе зачем отвечать?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman а зачем делать ответ более приятным? Если я - днище и хочу перестать им быть, то, наверное, это не зависит от пола) Тем более увольняют как раз за некомпетентность, а не по половому признаку - конечно, если говорить о *нормальных* местах работы.

Comment: Предлагаю закрыть вопрос, так как он порождает бесконечные дискуссии, и если надо продолжим обсуждение в общем чате.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Теоретически, Мета предназначена именно для дискуссий, результат которых хорошо бы сохранить.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vuEQixrBKCc

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, [**скрипт для сокращения ссылок на комментарии**](http://stackapps.com/a/7204/42078). Спасибо.

Comment: @D-side, [**http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/17399**](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/17399). Спасибо.

Comment: Если хотите узнать откуда берётся мнение *"что члены IT сообщества грубые, злые и, не умеющие общаться, люди."*, то для примера зайдите на https://t.me/ru_python_beginners где вы можете легко получить отклик в виде слабосодержательного оскорбления матом или (если повезёт) можете услышать легко проверяемые ошибочные заявления, преподнесённые надменным безапелляционным тоном. Наглядный пример зачем нужна модерация на технических форумах (повысить сигнал/шум и не отпугивать ненахрапистых грамотных и/или любознательных людей). По сравнению, на SO всё спокойно-профессионально и информативно...

Comment: ...[продолжение]  С одной стороны хамы полезны, потому что можно с ними и в профессиональной деятельности столкнуться, с другой обстановка, где матерные перебранки являются допустимыми, не является особенно продуктивной.

Comment: А как же это правило? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Обновление**

Вопрос получил дополнение, попробую дополнить ответ к изменённому вопросу.

Мне кажется, мы не можем и не должны смягчать наш язык лишь для того, чтобы потрафить самолюбию других участников. В конце-концов, программирование — такой же реальный мир, в котором человек должен общаться с живыми людьми, и налагая искусственные ограничения, не встречающиеся в повседневном общении, мы лишь снизим качество этого общения.

Тем не менее, мне кажется, что некоторые участники (не могу назвать имена, т. к. не отслеживаю) и правда бывают слишком грубы по отношению к новичкам, или к плохо заданным вопросам. Думаю, имеет смысл направить их на путь Света и Доброты просто подсказывая в комментариях. Простое неодобрение от постоянных участников («ну что ж вы набросились-то на новичка, помогите ему лучше») — вполне хороший метод подсказать невежливым участникам, что они переходят грань.

Но я на текущий момент категорически протестовал бы против формализации этого правила: ведь для того, чтобы закон работал, нужно, чтобы он соответствовал фактически сложившемуся в сообществе консенсусу! Давайте для начала просто попробуем подсказывать другим, если они слишком наседают на новичков. (Ну и я использовал бы при этом простые выражения: «Не гнобите новичка» вместо «Ваше сообщение несёт негативную эмоциональную окраску».)

---

Если вам кажется, что кто-то из участников невежливо, некорректно себя ведёт, имеет смысл оставить ему комментарий насчёт этого. Если он продолжает, можно [отправить соответствующую тревогу](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovACj.png), наши модераторы прекрасно справляются с такими случаями. Или можно обсудить грубого участника [в общем чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--). Те участники, которые согласно консенсусу сообщества ведут себя неподобающе, получат отрезвляющее порицание сообщества, а в тяжёлых случаях — бан. Если же сообщество считает поведение участника нормальным, то наверное ничего не поменяется (но тут уж менять нужно не «проблемного» участника, а наш внутренний консенсус).

Это относится, разумеется, не лично к автору вопроса, а ко всем участникам.

---

**Старый ответ**

В русском языке, в отличие от американского стандарта английского, выражение «как белый человек» не несёт расистских коннотаций¹. (По большей части потому, что у России и других русскоязычных стран не было колониального прошлого.) Это просто нормальное разговорное словосочетание, обозначающее в приведённом вами контексте «без лишних сложностей».

Я считаю самоограничение, связанное с тем, что дословный перевод этого выражения может иметь плохие коннотации в каких-то других языках, неуместным. В противном случае нам придётся проверять чуть ли не каждый фразеологизм на уместность в контексте каждого из мировых языков.

В русском языке и без того достаточно обидных слов и словосочетаний, давайте в наших запретах ограничимся теми оскорблениями, которые имеют смысл в русском языке.

А вот употребление фразы «все нормальные люди знают...» мне кажется немного невежливым: это подразумевает, что тот, к кому эта фраза обращена, не вполне нормален. Я бы не запрещал её, но всё же такое читать обидно.

Почему я против запрета? Дело в том, что в нормальной дискуссии должно быть оставлено право критики, должно быть право сказать без трёхэтажных непрямых конструкций «этот код плохой», «ваше решение ужасно», «вы делаете неправильно». Различные политкорректные эвфемизмы наподобие «этот код можно сделать ещё чуточку лучше», «ваше решение не вполне идеально», «то, что вы делаете, является тоже вариантом нормы» заставляют постороннего читателя думать, что критикуемая вещь не так уж и плоха, и можно использовать её — с плачевными последствиями.

У программистов точность высказываний ценнее чувств тех, кто не может смириться с реальностью.

---

Мне не кажется, что запрещать разделение людей на группы имеет смысл. В конце-концов, люди и правда делятся на группы. Есть джуниоры и сениоры, есть фронтэндщики и бекэндщики, есть пэхаписты и хаскеллисты, есть программисты и менеджеры, все они разные, и по-разному решают задачи. Вот переход в обсуждении на личности я лично не одобрил бы, но опять-таки это вопрос личного стиля каждого участника. Если кому-либо не нравится сообщение — пусть поставит минус, раз он считает, что содержание ответа менее важно, чем его форма.

---

¹ Источник: [ru.wiktionary/белый человек](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA).

Comment: Я имел виду не конкретно белый, а что в данном случае произошло разделение на группы - белые, которые делают правильно и  другие которые делают не правильно. Замените белый на умный, смышленый и пр.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman: Дописал ответ.

Comment: А почему просто не использовать какие-то сравнения? Ведь можно же было просто написать - для этого лучше использовать транзакции, они удобны в описанной ситуации. Согласитесь - нет разделения? Но видно желание помочь!

Comment: Сказать ваш код плохой - нормально. Сказать, что умные (белый, правильные и т.д.) люди так не пишут - не нормально.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman: А почему не использовать? «Умные люди так не пишут» — оскорбительно, да. А вот «опытные разработчики стараются избегать использования синглтонов» — очень в тему.

Comment: а зачем в этой фразе упоминание опытных разработчиков? что она добавляет? если вы напишите, что вы избегаете использовать синглтоны так как это приводит к этому и этому - это не будет в тему?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman: Потому что «я не использую синглтоны» вызывает очевидное возражение «ну и что?». «Вы не должны использовать синглтоны» вызывает очевидный вопрос «почему?». А длинное объяснение преимуществ и недостатков синглтонов катит на приличный ответ.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman: Ну и вообще-то мы никогда не говорим сухими фразами. состоящими только из контента. _Нормальные люди_ :-P добавляют модальные обороты, показывающие кроме смысла сообщения ещё и своё отношение к нему. Это — нормальное человеческое общение.

Comment: Если человек не считает вас авторитетом в вопросе синглетонов, то это его право. Я думаю, что сообщество через голосование сумеет придать вес вашему ответу. Но почему вы хотите заставить его (через чувство вины и через угрозу изгнания из группы) последовать вашему совету?  Я не против эмоций, я предлагаю просто добавить еще одну эмоцию - эмпатию. Показывайте отношение к предмету, а не к человек и/или группе людей. Если вы скажите, что вы испытываете лютую башенную ненависть к синглетонам - я вас точно поддержу. Но надеюсь людей, которые их используют вы не ненавидите?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman: _Угрозу изнания из группы_? Вы серьёзно? У вас очень странный круг общения, должен заметить: никто из моих знакомых ещё не впал в депрессию от того, что ему подсказали, как делают опытные разработчики. Ну и я не вижу причин навязывать _эмпатию_, простите. У нас тут не Смольный институт благородных девиц. Предложить участнику «ну будьте же вы добрее» можно, но **требовать** этого? Увольте, без меня.

Comment: @VladD, все ок, в западных интернетах уже пару лет принято *смертельно оскорбляться* по любому поводу. Теперь и у нас )

Comment: Да. Я серьезно. Просто поставьте себя на место начинающего. Ему говорят, что профессионалы так не делают - это прямая угроза на изгнание из группы. Если он не будет делать как делают профессионалы, то его не возьмут (сиречь выгонят) из группы профессионалы. Вы заметили, что только, что отделили меня из группы? Так как мой круг общения странный для вас, но вы не знаете мой круг общения. Это не попытка вас задеть, но попытка показать как простые слова могу разделять. Я не требую, я предлагаю подумать и улучшить общение.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman: Я не считаю то, что вы говорите, соответствующим действительности. Да, если профессионалы делают так, а он по-другому, то он ещё не **в группе**, и лучше бы ему это понимать. Если он не понимает, обидится и застрелится, узнав, что он ещё не самый крутой — премию Дарвина ему в руки. Вы, заметьте, единственный с этим предложением, так что вы **фактически** отделены от группы. Мне кажется, что вы пытаетесь навязать традиции вашего круга общения комьюнити, в которых таких традиций нет. (Да, я могу и ошибаться в этой части.)

Comment: Я могу с натяжкой принять, что детям в первом классе не ставят оценки, чтобы не травмировать их слабую психику. Но взрослые сформировавшиеся люди (опять разделение, да) должны справляться с тривиальной критикой.

Comment: @VladD да. Я вижу, что я единственный кто заговорил об этом. Я не пытаюсь навязать никаких традиций. Я пытаюсь выяснить отношение сообщества к этому. Я признал, что изначально не верно поставил вопрос и поэтому его исправил.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman: (оффтопик) У вас во фразе «Я предлагаю запрещать людям что-то!» нет случайно опечатки? Звучит немного не по-русски.

Comment: @Nofate с критикой поступков, действий, решений обязательно должны справляться! Я полностью тут с вами согласен. Я лишь говорю, что критиковать надо поступки, действия, решения, а не человека/личность.

Comment: @VladD это опечатка. спасибо.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman: Исправление сделало вопрос более мягким. Изначальная фраза «Я считаю, что подобные выражения использовать недопустимо» выглядит как жёсткое навязывание совершенно непривычных стандартов общения. Если бы вы просто сказали «давайте будем немного добрее к новичкам», ваш вопрос наверняка вызвал бы намного больше симпатии. У нас всё же более приняты этические, а не психологические аргументы. (Снова разделение, что поделать?)

Comment: @VladD согласен с вами, изначально вопрос был неправильно сформулирован.  Я твердо высказал свое отношение. Но цель была узнать мнение сообщества. Я тут без году неделя и пробую разобраться, что тут принято, а что нет. Я не навязываю стандарты - я стараюсь выяснить "устав монастыря" через дискуссию и призываю людей просто подумать над этим вопросом.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman: Я вас услышал. Дополнил ответ в связи с изменением вопроса.

Answer (score 10):

Как мне кажется, большую роль играет контекст, ведь [оскорбить можно и вполне обычным словом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4020/6). Вводить ограничение на использование каких–либо слов, чтобы не обидеть кого–либо, не представляется возможным (конечно же, за исключением нецензурной лексики).

При этом, *обязательным требованием* использования сайта является профессиональный, по возможности, **литературный язык** изложения мыслей. Строгий литературный язык поможет удержать диалог в рамках решаемой задачи исключив эмоциональные различия культур, в которых могут находится участники. (То, как реагирует человек, выросший, к примеру, в «небольшой деревне на периферии», крайне сильно отличается от реакции «коренного москвича среднего достатка», далеко не все шутки кажутся одинаково смешными и вызывают совершенно разную реакцию, в случае негативной коннотации.)

Задавая или отвечая на вопрос, представьте, что вы – профессор, который обсуждает с другими профессорами некоторый научный вопрос на сцене перед студентами ВУЗа, которые пришли послушать умных мужей и просветиться (то есть это не развлекательное шоу, каламбур – неуместен). Если вы считаете, что использование того или иного выражение допустимо в таком контексте, не стесняйтесь использовать его и на сайте, но при любых сомнениях уместности выражения, лучше его не использовать.

Comment: Ох, слышали бы вы шутки, которые позволяют себе перед аудиторией _некоторые_ профессора!

Comment: @VladD Профессора формируют мнения своих студентов. Если профессор сказал что–то «необычное» и не получил в ответ критику от коллег, значит индустрия не находит ничего «необычного», выражение уместно и будет в будущем использоваться всеми без стеснения, как минимум, до тех пор пока не найдется тот, кого оно обижает, и не вызовет резонанс. Как мне кажется, это вполне нормальная практика.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky иногда и профессор может ошибиться. https://gist.github.com/unclebob/2508746/