# Пользователи имеют право высказывать своё мнение!

Tags: обсуждение, блокировка

Надо восстановить этот ответ и разбанить [@Squidward](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/176051/squidward)

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5454/178988

Обращаю внимание: там 3 плюса и 3 минуса, т. е. 50% сообщества с ним согласны.

Ответ удалён не пользователями, а неким модератором, поставившим на него тревогу: максимум могло быть 3 тревоги, а для удаления надо 6.

Comment: Ответ, в нынешнем виде, вновь завалят тревогами и удалят. Бан же прокомментировать никак не могу.

Comment: Qwertiy, я думаю, вам имеет смысл послать своё резюме в фбк.

Comment: *там 3 плюса и 3 минуса* — от меня добавьте, пожалуйста, «минус» и «тревогу» к обсуждаемому ответу: я его не видел до удаления.

Comment: И от меня минус и тревогу, я не видел раньше.

Comment: Ответ просуществовал немногим больше часа, так что говорить о реакции сообщества вообще, исходя только из поступивших голосов, очень ненадёжно.

Comment: @D-side, именно поэтому модераторы и не должны в таких случаях принимать решение _вместо_ сообщества.

Comment: @Qwertiy если у этого вопроса наберётся хотя бы 6 минусов, это докажет, что модератор был прав, что сообщество всё равно сделало бы то же самое. Ждём.

Comment: и вообще, я не разбираюсь во фрейдистских теориях, но до сих пор не исправленный заголовок «пользователи имею право…» как бы намекает.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, теперь исправленный :)

Comment: @D-side, минус не эквивалентен тревоги спама. У нас полно заминусованных ответов есть, которые совсем никто не собирается удалять ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy, ложечки, конечно, нашлись…

Comment: @Qwertiy минус на том ответе – может быть. А вот минус на вашем вопросе можно считать согласием с решением модератора и признать эквивалентным тревоге на ответе. Чисто в целях количественной оценки.

Comment: Вот, 7 минусов уже. ЧТД.

Comment: @D-side это не очень верно, сейчас по минусам большинства считать согласие с решением модератора (да и с каким решением?). Лично я не видел пост Squidward . Вопрос в том, как я могу оценить сейчас ситуацию? Наверное, никак. Либо же нужно опубликовать удаленный ответ в виде скриншота и добавить в этот вопрос.

Comment: @Nikita для удаления любого сообщения нужно 6 тревог "грубый или оскорбительный". 6. Ни о каком большинстве речи не идёт. А ["кусочек для ознакомления" сохранился в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38081223#38081223).

Comment: @D-side я имел в виду вопрос Qwertiy и вашу цитату "вот минус на вашем вопросе можно считать согласием с решением модератора и признать эквивалентным тревоге на ответе.". Что касается ответа Squidward, Qwertiy нам ясно дал понять, что 6 тревог так и не набралось, а ответ был удалён модератором.

Comment: @D-side Достаточно одной тревоги от модератора, либо подтверждения от него же, что тревога "полезна". Восстановление поста - это, практически, конкретному участнику грубо нарушить https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice. Только потому, что на посте нажало + три человека.

Comment: @Nikita суть ответа  Squidward - он подробно рассказал всем, как он иронично называет негров, гомосексуалов, оппозиционеров, провластных, школьников, небогатых и духовных. Высказал свое недовольство результатами выборов в америке, словосочетанием Christmas Tree и т.н. "карманной" оппозицией. На посте три плюса, три минуса и тревога от модератора, по которой пост был удален духом. Не на что там смотреть.

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо! Теперь мне всё понятно, тогда да, я бы тоже поставил минус и тревогу.

Comment: @PashaPash по-моему, ваш комментарий нужно было адресовать не мне. Я и так это знаю :) Речь, если что, шла о том, "что если б модератор не вмешался". Мой тезис в том, что произошло бы то же самое, просто несколько позже.

Comment: @Nikita, там в достаточно эмоциональной форме выражено, что не стоит всегда идти на поводу у запада с его "политкорректностью", а надо соответствовать собственным традициям и принимать решения основываясь на них.

Comment: @Qwertiy Причем тут запад и политкорректность? От запада там максимум негры. Все остальное - обычное локальное русскоязычное хамство. Не стоит оправдывать обычное бытовое хамство и нетерпимость каким-то "особым", "традиционным" путем.

Comment: @PashaPash, не надо трактовать эмоциональные примеры вне контекста. Там есть контекст и понимание должно складываться вместе с ним.

Comment: @Qwertiy а еще есть правила сайта, которые нельзя нарушать. вне зависимости от контекста.

Comment: @PashaPash, _"От запада там максимум негры."_ - нет, от запада там ------ политкорректность с её "родитель 1, родитель 2", выпиливанием обращений "he/she/guys" из исходников Хромиума и всё остальное. Я полностью согласен с его ответом, что нечего на это всё равняться. Допустимость любой фразы можно определять только в неком контексте. И это одновременно и в смысле исходного вопроса - одна и та же фраза может быть обидной или необидной в зависимости от обстановки, и в свете формулировки его собственного ответа - она допустима в данной ситуации, чтобы гиперболой подчеркнуть свою мысль.

Comment: @Qwertiy вы считаете политкорректность и "родитель 1, родитель 2" проблемой, я - нет. He / She - это не политкорректность, это просто вежливость, и об этом знает любой, кто хоть раз писал спецификацию или другую сопроводительную документацию. И это кажется смешным и гиперболизированным, пока не попадешь в ситуацию, когда ты оказываешься на другой стороне. Я как-то раз зарегистрировался на сайте, где основа ЦА - девушки. Очень неуютно было получать оттуда уведомления, в которых явно предполагалось, что я - женского пола (при том, что пол в настройках сайта был вбит)

Comment: @Qwertiy т.е. то, что вы считаете политкорректностью, на самом деле достаточно эффективный механизим для устраниения неравенства. Просто вы не можете его оценить, т.к. вы - белый мужчина *среднего* достатка, живущий в расово однородной среде. И просто не чувствуете перекос в стиле общения в вашу пользу.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну и опять же, вас достаточно сильно защищает наличие рода у существительных в русском языке. При слове "пользователь" не возникает ощущения, что что-то идет не так. Попробуйте заменить в любой инструкции слово "пользователь" на "пользовательша", или "разработчик" на "разработчица" и почитать ее, пытаясь применить к себе. Необычные ощущения гарантированы.

Comment: @PashaPash, и почему же, если это _"просто вежливость",_ то это до сих пор не встроено в движок SO? Вежливость, это использовать правильное местоимение. Принципиально удалять все слова, у которых форма зависит от пола - это просто бред. А тот же "guys" вообще скорее означает "ребята", т. е. к полу напрямую не относится. Это как когда где-то иск был, что в слове "история" - "history" скрывается местоимение "его" - "his", как бы "his story" - поле для придирок бесконечно - нафига за этим гнаться и подстраиваться?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60461/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-pashapash).

Answer (score 8):

### Пользователи имеют право высказывать своё мнение при условии [соблюдения правил сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

Ответ Squidward в его текущем виде не имеет почти никакого отношения к вопросу. Т.е. на вопрос, заданный топикастером:

> Считает ли вы подобные комментарии нуждающимися в коррекции? Если да, то как улучшить качество подобных комментариев?

Отвечает только одно предложение:

> Даже если бы словосочетание "белый человек" было в приведённой цитате дословным, а не устоявшимся выражением с совершенно безобидным разговорным значением, оно не было бы оскорбительным, потому что интонация заведомо шуточная.

Все остальное содержимое ответа - не имеет к теме "non inclusive language в комментариях и вопросах", и вообще к ruSO **никакого отношения**.

Можно поддерживать называние некоторых групп людей уничижительными наименованиями, можно не поддерживать. Можно считать их употребление признаком "шуточной интонации", можно не считать. Это ваше личное дело.

Но создавать об этом пост на мете, и подробно рассказывать о "шуточных" наименованиях  - это прямое нарушение одного из основных правил - [Будьте дружелюбными](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). Вот прямая цитата из справки:

> **Нетерпимость любого вида**. Любые выражения, предназначенные для оскорбления или разделения людей или обществ на основании расовых и половых отличий, сексуальной ориентации, религии и пр. **будут караться**. **Без исключений**. (Это лишь несколько примеров; если не уверены – не пишите.)

**Без исключений**.

Если опытный участник, хорошо ориентирующися в правилах, и наверняка читавший эту статью справки, приходит на мету и постит не имеющий *прямого отношения к обсуждаемому вопросу, и не являющийся прямым ответом* текст, с подробностями того, как он называет людей и общества "на основании расовых и половых отличий сексуальной ориентации, и пр" - он умышленно нарушает одно из основных правил сайта. Последующее общение в чате подтверждает умышленность поступка, участник заявляет что он будет так поступать и впредь - бан.

---

Текст выше - объяснение причин бана, а не моя личная позиция.

Моя личная позиция, как участника, а не как модератора - ответ Squidward на мете оскорбляет лично меня. Т.к. я в нем вижу сразу несколько пунктов, которые прямо читаются как "я называю таких как ты, pashapash, вот так вот". И это "вот так вот" лично мне достаточно неприятно. Свобода != Вседозволенность.

Comment: Там формулировка, которая сама по себе не может являться оскорблением. В принципе, ответ действительно где-то на грани или немного за ней, но в целом, с учётом контекста, я всё-таки склонен отнести его к допустимым. Тем более, он выражает очень важную мысль и многие с ней согласны.

Comment: @Qwertiy там формулировка, которая сама по себе является оскорблением. Весь первый абзац оскорбляет конкретных людей (и меня в том числе, минимум 3 раза). Ответ может выражать какую угодно мысль - но **к обсуждаемой в вопросе теме правки комментов он не относится**. Мне, как участику SO, абсолютно параллельно, как Squidward кого называет. Я не хочу это выслушивать и читать - просто потому, что мне это неприятно. И не только мне.

Comment: @Qwertiy Простой пример - то, что кто-то использует мат в повседневной жизни, даже в отношении себя - не дает ему права создавать пост с матерными словами на мете. **Вне зависимости от формулировки**. И тем более применять мат в отношении конкретных людей или групп людей. Простой пример - если бы я завершил этот коммент фразой (заранее извините, просто пример) "а если участник этого не понимает, то он дурак, и мне с ним не по пути" - вы бы оскорбились. А ведь именно такая формулировка использована в ответе Squidward. По сути, он прямо назвал всех *несогласных* с ним дураками. Этого достаточно?

Comment: Какая ещё "тема правки комментариев"? Я ничего такого не обсуждал.

Comment: @Qwertiy Вы читали вопрос, ответ к которому предлагаете восстановить? Какой теме он посвящен?

Comment: @Qwertiy или вы согласны с ответом Squidward как с самостоятельным постом, вам он понравился просто как заявление о какой-то личной позиции, не имеющей к вопросу https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4481/ прямого отношения. И на этом основании вы предлагаете его восстановить?

Comment: Ответил в [другом комментарии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5457/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%8e%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%91-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5/5461?noredirect=1#comment20535_5457) - и про то, как относится к вопросу, и про то, с чем я согласен.

Answer (score 2):

Моё мнение: использование грубых слов запрещено вне зависимости от контекста на многих сайтах, но SO к ним не относится. Например, см. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offensive-language.

Правило Be-Nice явно указывает на *намерения*, а не *лексикон* — если читать текст целиком, а не по диагонали. Более того, модератор, который видит личные оскорбления в абстрактном списке грубых слов, явно нарушает правило **Be welcoming, be patient, and *assume good intentions***, которое испарилось в русском переводе.

Кстати, текущая английская версия пояснительного текста к этому пункту — моя заслуга. В него были внесены мои правки.

Последний абзац моего сообщения неудачен: изначально планировался "пример использования", но сейчас очевидно, что он скорее работает против точки зрения. Соответственно, должен был быть удалён конкретно последний абзац. Или исправлен до политкорректной формы.

> Ответ Squidward в его текущем виде не имеет почти никакого отношения к вопросу.

Ложь. Ответ содержит точку зрения, аргументацию и примеры. Аргументация — часть ответа и не может быть оффтопиком.

> это прямое нарушение одного из основных правил - Будьте дружелюбными

Ложь. Оскорбление и обсуждение оскорбления — разные вещи. Правила говорят быть дружелюбным, соблюдать коммутативность отношения и так далее.

> Нетерпимость любого вида

Ложь. Сообщение не содержит оценочного мнения о группах людей, она касается только лексикона и его неоскорбительного использования.

> Последующее общение в чате подтверждает умышленность поступка

Ложь. Чат содержит аргументацию позиции "грубое слово не всегда оскорбительно".

> участник заявляет что он будет так поступать и впредь

Частично истина. Продолжать использовать грубые слова в неоскорбительных контекстах — да, продолжать писать на Мете посты с сомнительным лексиконом — нет, информация отсутствует.

Comment: "Сообщение не содержит оценочного мнения о группах людей, она касается только лексикона и его неоскорбительного использования." – с "я называю" этот набор лексикона превратился в оценочное мнение в глазах достаточного количества людей, чтобы по вам открыли огонь.

Comment: @D-side Вы прочитали сообщение целиком или остановились на первом десятке слов?

Comment: Поскольку приведенная цитата не из первого десятка слов, то, очевидно, я прочитал не только его.

Comment: @D-side Я про первый десяток слов в обсуждаемом сообщении, а не в этом. Вы проигнорировали суть ("оскорбительность слов зависит от контекста"), прочитав только список в начале ("я называю {A} словом {B}"). Для большей лексической ясности: "называю" следует читать как "могу называть в некоторых ситуациях", если это вдруг неясно из последующего текста.

Comment: То, что это понимаю я, не мешает не понимать это более широкому (чем "я и только я") кругу лиц, который засыпал вас тревогами. А вы сами признаёте, что в ответе много что можно понять неправильно. И в этом плане "сомнительный лексикон" вообще штука рискованная, поскольку если его употребление поймут неправильно, то резко не в вашу пользу. Что, кхм, и произошло. По этой причине в вопросах и ответах ими лучше не пользоваться вовсе, даже если прямого запрета на это нет.

Comment: @D-side Моя формулировка, конечно, спровоцировала contextomy, но именно изобилие argumentum ad lapidem от моих оппонентов после многочисленных пояснений развило конфликт. / Нейтрально-положительная позиция уже была озвучена в другом ответе, у меня позиция была экстремально-положительная, и как любая нестандартная точка зрения требовала сильной аргументации. Если бы я написал абстрактное "давайте использовать оскорбления", я бы получил оценку –10/+0, а не –3/+3, и я бы сам квалифицировал такой ответ несмешной шуткой или толстым троллингом, а не серьёзной позицией.

Answer (score -13):

маленькая иллюстрация по поводу обсуждаемого «пропагандиста за свободу в выборе формы высказывания своего мнения» (правки состоят, фактически, из изменений регистра некоторых букв):

- https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/511/2
- https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/567/6
- https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/591/2
- https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/607/3
- https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/607/4
- https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1067/6
- https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1099/5
- https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/2109/2
- https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/2319/3
- https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/2331/2
- https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/2410/3
- https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/2872/3
- https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/3159/4
- https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/5440/4

p.s. я не злопамятный, это движок все ходы записывает.

Comment: Чем плохи правки, улучшающие читабельность постов?

Comment: И к чему это? Чуть человек не может защитится, так сразу на него оставшиеся 33 греха заводят. Нехорошо это, особенно юзеры правки годные ИМХО.

Comment: @Nofate, правки замечательны. но, на мой взгляд, несколько диссонируют с позицией, озвученной в удалённом (и обсуждаемом здесь) ответе.

Comment: Правки относятся к оформлению, они не меняют содержание и не связаны с выражением мнений.

Comment: @Aid, ответ мой не про какие-то там «грехи». см. мой предыдущий комментарий.

Comment: @Nofate, согласен, не меняют содержание, но меняют форму. т.е., **по сути своей** противоречат тому мнению, которое высказано в удалённом (и обсуждаемом здесь) ответе.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin не вижу никакого противоречия

Comment: @Nofate а как вам такие правки? Не считаете ли вы что их нужно откатывать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/513981/revisions  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/511117/revisions https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/516208/revisions https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/512401/revisions

Comment: @Nikita, чувак на медальку зарабатывает, что плохого?

Comment: @Aid это понятно, но его правки же никак не улучшают читаемость... Или вы считаете, что этот золотой значок можно заработать только таким читерским путём? Значки по факту означают, что участник внёс некоторый вклад в развитие и улучшение сообщества. Ну а как с этим сочетаются "пустые" правки?

Comment: @Nikita, на правках не зарабатывают после 2.000. Так что если правка не деструктивна - Бога ради. Можно и не читерством, но это долго.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, сравните, пожалуйста, две мысли: «я считаю, что при выборе формы высказывания своих мыслей надо считаться с мнением окражающих» и «я считаю, что можно высказываться в той форме, которая мне представляется приемлемой». как вы думаете, противоречат ли друг другу эти мысли, и какая из них могла привести к написанию обуждаемого удалённого ответа, а какая — к правкам, ссылки на которые приведёны в моём ответе?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin возможно, он считал что высказываться разрешено в любой форме - но другие участники могут улучшить эту форму если им что-то не нравится при условии сохранения смысла.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, явно нет. речь в вопросе была в первую очередь про комментарии: «Я считаю, что подобные выражения использовать недопустимо - особенно в комментариях» (цитата из вопроса). а комментарии, как известно, отличаются от других сообщений своей неизменяемостью (по крайней мере для рядовых участников).

Comment: @PavelMayorov, но мне представляется, что и удалённый ответ, и озвученные правки, теоретически, могут следовать из несколько иной «связующей» мысли: «я считаю допустимым **для меня** высказываться в той форме, которая **мне** представляется приемлемой, но недопустимым высказываться **другим** в той форме, что неприемлема **для меня**».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin это уже додумывание

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да, это была лишь попытка соединить несоединимое, вполне вероятно, не соответствующая действительности. можете не обращать на неё внимание. // возвращаясь к теме: всё-таки надеюсь, что вы поняли, почему я считаю противоречащими друг другу упомянутые правки и суть изложенного в удалённом ответе.

Comment: Я вот вообще не понял, как это к вопросу относится...

Comment: @Qwertiy, разве что косвенно: «допустимо ли высказывание мнения, облечённое в неприемлемую/неудобную форму».

Comment: @Aid, то есть вы оправдываете фармерство значка вставкой незначащих пробелов. Те правки по сути не привносят пользы.

Comment: @mymedia, я подхожу с другой стороны: эти правки никому не мешают, не заставляют других пользователей терять время на редакцию этих сообщений (> 2.000); приносят ему пользу в виде значка. Так что один плюс, один ноль, выходит затея одобряется, раз в плюсе.

Comment: @Aid, однако из-за таких действий ценность знака девальвируется. Получается, значок уже не способен служить мерилом уровня вклада участника. И это минус. Кроме того, некоторые иные пользователи почему-то считают злом беспричинное поднятие старых вопросов.

Comment: @mymedia, почему обесценивается? Даже на вставка пробелов весьма затратно при таком объеме. И я не одобряю, а скорее... никак не отношусь, мне кажется это нормальным. Хочется - Бога ради.

Comment: @Aid, проблема в том, что такие правки не требуют особой умственной деятельности, можно даже не вчитываться. Так что это вклад сомнительного качества. Нужно ли его поощрять (знаком)? Я думаю, нет. > "мне кажется это нормальным", т.е. оправдываете, как я и написал выше.

Comment: @mymedia, он увидел цель - знак, увидел путь достижения - лёгкие правки и достигает её. А до качества... Да каждое второе сообщение-вопрос легко затмит эти правки по количеству "сомнительности" по качеству.

Comment: @Aid, ну вот если бы Александр Шиманский, внося правки, улучшал бы такие вопросы — другое дело.

Comment: @mymedia, он на себя этими правками работает. А потом даст кому-то хороший ответ. А забанить - обидится и уйдёт, кто-то останется без хорошего ответа. Разве это хорошо? И вообще - чего Вы привязались? Хотите его забанить/пожурить - к модераторам или к нему. Иначе нечего демагогию разводить.

Comment: @Aid, я пока не предлагаю устраивать экстерминатус, как это произошло со Сквидвардом. Но считаю одобрение (или просто попустительство) таких правок недопустимым.

Comment: @mymedia, then go to the admins.

Comment: @Aid, боюсь, закончится это печально :(

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Почему вы так любите с маленькой буквы предложения начинать? Имхо, это надругательство над восприятием ваших вопросов другими.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, [кратко](https://unixforum.org/index.php?s=&showtopic=125913&view=findpost&p=1163093). подробнее — почитайте [всю эту тему сначала](https://unixforum.org/index.php?showtopic=125913&hl=%F0%E5%E3%E8%F1%F2%F0).