# Выборы модераторов сообщества 2017: ответы кандидатов на вопросы сообщества

Tags: обсуждение, выборы

Каждый участник, выдвигающийся на позицию модератора сообщества, имеет возможность поделиться своими мыслями с коллегами [по основным наболевшим вопросам](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5983/) нашего сообщества. Ниже представлены восемь вопросов от участников к вам, как кандидату, в дополнение к двум обязательными вопросам к рассмотрению.

### Ссылки на ответы кандидатов:

<sub>(В хронологическом порядке)</sub>

- [rjhdby](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6059/)
- [ЮрийСПб](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6069/)
- [Sergey Gornostaev](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6070/)
- [A K](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6072/)
- [Suvitruf](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6120/)
- [Grundy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6121/)
- [Paulo Berezini](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6129/)
- [Qwertiy](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6133/)

### Инструкция: как отвечать на вопросы

1. Скопируйте [шаблонный текст вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/f27997f1-e535-4df4-a708-cf5ef5ba39a9/view-source).
2. Вставьте его в новый ответ.
3. В начале поставьте своё имя и ссылку на профиль.
4. Пишите свои ответы после каждого блока цитаты и перед `---`, вот так:

   ```
   > Текст вопроса.

   Ваш ответ здесь.

   ---
   ```

### Памятка для кандидатов

- Ваша задача, как кандидата, крайне проста — опубликовать ваши мысли по всем обозначенным ниже вопросам одним ответом *на этот вопрос*.
- Пожалуйста, добавьте ваше имя (псевдоним на сайте) в самом начале ответа, чтобы другие участники понимали, чьи ответы они читают в данный момент.
- Пожалуйста, используйте форматирование как в этой публикации для выделения вопросов и ваших ответов к ним.

Как только все кандидаты разместят свои ответы, мы будем использовать данный вопрос как основу для принятия решений, чтобы каждый участник, который будет голосовать, понимал, почему он решил голосовать именно за данного кандидата.

#### Несколько слов о модераторах сообщества

Модератор сообщества – призвание, а не должность. Вам не обязательно быть «лучшим» специалистом среди коллег (хотя разбираться в предмете все–таки стоит), чтобы быть модератором сообщества, но вам обязательно необходимо быть хорошим человеком, добрым, отзывчивым. На Stack Overflow на русском мы в первую очередь ставим во главу угла наших коллег, уважение и доверительные отношения друг к другу. И если ранее ваша «общественная репутация» в глаза коллег строилась на базе ваши знаний, вопросов и ответов, то после того, как вы станете модераторам, сообщество будет ценить вас за вашу добродетель не меньше, чем за профессиональные навыки.

Без модераторов крайне сложно создать по настоящему дружное, интересное сообщество, а без сообщества, Stack Overflow – это просто набор битов на жестком диске. Мы, люди, и есть Stack Overflow! Если вы верите в то, что можете менять мир вокруг себя к лучшему, добро пожаловать в нашу модераторскую команду!

Желаю удачи, кандидаты!

> <sub>Тут же хотелось бы обратиться к сообществу, тем, кто будет отдавать свой голос за того или иного кандидата.</sub>
>
> <sub>Коллеги, пожалуйста, подойдите крайне ответственно к выбору модераторов! Модераторы — это фундамент сообщества. Они являются опорой для нас всех в первую очередь в случаях, когда что–то идет не так. Прежде чем отдать свой голос, подумайте, кого бы вы хотели увидеть в момент, когда с вами или с вашим коллегой на сайте произойдет что–то не так, когда вам понадобится помощь? Того кто спокоен, рассудителен, отзывчив, педантичен и добр? Или кого–то другого, например, кто знает больше анекдотов?</sub>
>
> <sub>Представьте, что вам нужно выбрать делового партнера, которому вы бы смогли доверить ваше благополучие. Делайте ваш выбор исходя из того, что кандидат уже сделал для сообщества, а не обещает сделать, судите на общечеловеческих навыках, а не знаниях программирования. В работе с людьми навыки программирования пригодятся мало.</sub>
>
> <sub>**От вашего выбора зависит будущее сообщества. В нашем сообществе это не просто слова.**</sub>

### Вопросы

*Внимание!* Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что благодаря стараниям отдельных участников сообщества, некоторые вопросы получились очень живые, и содержат контекст или пояснения, которых нет в списке ниже, в списке лишь сам вопрос или его основная идея. Если вы видите в вопросе ссылку, пожалуйста, перейдите по ней, чтобы увидеть вопрос целиком и контекст к нему.

---

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

---

> Как вы поступите, если увидите «комментарий–шутку», смешную только автору комментария, от давно известного вам участника сообщества, с которым вы находитесь в приятельских отношениях?
>
> <sub>Вопрос и контекст ситуации полностью: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5995/6</sub>

---

> Как вы предлагаете решать проблему новичков, которые плохо знают правила (например, не прочитали справку), и задают вопросы, лежащие на грани офтопика (или за ней)?
>   Речь идет не о явном спаме или вопросах, вовсе не относящихся к компьютерам и/или программированию, а скорее о вопросах от незлонамеренных новичков, не знающих, что тут принято, а что нет.

---

> Что вы будете делать, если заблокировав участника, задающего вопросы качества ниже требуемого, отправив ему при этом шаблонное письмо, получите в ответ угрозы и требования откатить блокировку и вернуть все удаленные вопросы?
>
> <sub>Вопрос и контекст ситуации полностью: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5997/6</sub>

---

> Система голосования за закрытие, удаление и многое другое на Stack Overflow устроена таким образом, что, став модератором, вам всегда будет достаточно лишь одного вашего голоса для того, чтобы изменения вступили в силу. Готовы ли вы нести *единоличную ответственность* за каждое ваше решение относительно судьбы вопросов, ответов и комментариев, без права на ошибку? Что вы будете делать, если обнаружите, что ошиблись?

---

> Расскажите, как вы решаете проблемы или выполняете задачи модерации сайта и сообщества? Что конкретно вы для этого уже сделали? Каков результат? Будет здорово, если вы скажете пару слов о том, почему это важно для всех и для вас лично.
>
> <sub>Вопрос и контекст ситуации полностью: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6048/6</sub>

---

> Назовите 4 главных качества, которыми, на ваш взгляд, должен обладать модератор Stack Overflow на русском.

---

> Как вы собираетесь действовать в ситуации, когда трактовка одного или нескольких правил (официальных или принятых сообществом на Мете) одного из участников или группы участников расходится с вашим пониманием этих же правил?

---

> Работать на благо сообщества вы можете и без статуса модератора. Так зачем вы действительно решили стать модератором?

Comment: Частично совпадают с прошлогодними)

Comment: @Qwertiy 1, 2, 9 и 10 — стандартные.

Comment: на 2 вопрос ответ очевиден - вызвать другого модератора на бой, собрать тотализатор, принять ставки и выяснить кто прав :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский или вызвать на рэп батл

Comment: @NickVolynkin Большое спасибо!

Comment: Так, а почему мой вопрос не попал в список? Он же входит в список восьми топовых.

Comment: @alexolut Это все [tag:модераторский-произвол].

Comment: Не выборы, а фарс! Требую сатисфакции!

Comment: @АлексейШиманский почему только 2? Способ же универсальный. Участник бузит? В морду! Ошибся? Всё равно в морду. Зачем ромб? Чтобы бить им морды. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, не слишком угловата палица?

Comment: @Other вмятины красивше будут. :)

Comment: Я особо не вдавался во все моменты, но на сколько я помню данный участник сообщества: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/220996/post-zeew
Достоин данной должности! ИМХО)

Comment: @Morozov Спасибо! У нас в сообществе очень много достойных людей! С свою очередь, модератор — позиция добровольная, участник должен сам лично выдвинуть свою кандидатуру.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Ну наверное я что то не так прочёл здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election
Смутило предложение: "Выборы сейчас находятся на этапе выдвижения кандидатов. Срок выдвижения кандидатов истекает через 6 дней.".

Comment: @Morozov Ага, все верно! Только выдвигаться надо самостоятельно!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Вы свели мой вопрос к одному конфликтному комментарию. А он вообще не о комментариях был.

Comment: @Morozov, если вы хотите видеть в модераторах активного отвечающего по меткам [tag:android] и [tag:java] то голосуйте за меня)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб после избрания на пост ваша активность в этих метках (почти наверняка) упадет )

Comment: @Nofate, ну.... Может и так. Зато это компенсируется возможностью быстрее закрывать/удалять спам и прочее. Может так даже потом эффективность и поболе будет общая)

Comment: Ответ снова попал в блок «Важное». Перезагрузил его. Когда пропадёт из блока — можно будет заблокировать обратно.

Comment: И это баг, кстати.

Comment: @NickVolynkin важное ушло, можно снова лочить. Не забыть бы еще голоса откатить, если они были в момент между блокировками.

Answer (score 29):

## [ЮрийСПб](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17609)

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

Провести воспитательную беседу, если не поможет - временный бан. Поддержание высоких стандартов общения важнее для сообщества.

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

Спрошу о причине закрытия, попытаюсь найти взаимопонимание. Если позиции согласовать не удастся - предложу вынести обсуждение на мету для привлечения сообщества к выработке консенсуса по прецеденту.

---

> Как вы поступите, если увидите «комментарий–шутку», смешную только автору комментария, от давно известного вам участника сообщества, с которым вы находитесь в приятельских отношениях?
>
> <sub>Вопрос и контекст ситуации полностью: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5995/6</sub>

**Ответ по краткой формулировке:**

Если комментарий не вполне соответствует принципу `be nice` - предложу комментатору вспомнить себя новичком, вспомнить как сложно было формулировать вопросы и попрошу пересмотреть необходимость размещения этого комментария под постом. Если комментарий представится мне совсем уж за гранью - потру и выскажу своё "фи" в корректной форме, ибо для подобных комментариев у нас есть отличное место - чат.

**Ответ на расширенный вопрос по ссылке:**

Вопрос закрою с кастомной причиной: "К сожалению, ваш вопрос не подразумевает однозначного ответа, ведёт к спорам, засим оффтопик и должен быть закрыт или удалён. [ссылка на справочную статью про то, какие вопросы можно, а какие нельзя/не следует задавать]" . Наверное даже и удалю сразу, если его точно никак не исправить. ТС вопрос всё равно видеть будет, так что мой коммент с причиной закрытия для него будет виден. Также удалю все комменты не по делу, чтобы они ТС не смущали при просмотре удалённого вопроса.

Искрометному шутнику напишу в личку и попрошу не провоцировать новичков в который раз, сопроводив письмо не завуалированной угрозой бана за неоднократность подобных случаев, в случае, если уверен, что ранее просьбы не провоцировать модераторами уже озвучивались.

В итоге площадка для спора закроется, ТС получит направление для размышлений о том, что было не так в его вопросе. Шутник, возможно, кинет обидку, но тут уж ничего не поделаешь - цена власти.

Возможный текст письма шутнику:

"Приветствую! Пишу в связи с инцидентом под вопросом (ссылка). Как модератор, который должен поддерживать выполнение принципа `be nice` на сайте прошу несколько умереннее реагировать на явно оффтопичные вопросы новичков. Для сообщества будет гораздо полезнее закрывать такие вопросы с объяснением оффтопичности оного в причине закрытия."

Приписка, если известны случаи предупреждения модераторами шутника о недопустимости подобного поведения ранее:

"К сожалению, т.к. это уже не первый подобный случай я буду вынужден заблокировать временно вашу учётную запись в случае повторения подобных инцидентов. Надеюсь, что до этого не дойдёт и мы с вами сможем и далее объяснять новичкам правила сайта и закрывать оффтопичные вопросы в дружелюбной атмосфере"

---

> Как вы предлагаете решать проблему новичков, которые плохо знают правила (например, не прочитали справку), и задают вопросы, лежащие на грани офтопика (или за ней)?
>   Речь идет не о явном спаме или вопросах, вовсе не относящихся к компьютерам и/или программированию, а скорее о вопросах от незлонамеренных новичков, не знающих, что тут принято, а что нет.

Лично я пишу шаблонное "К сожалению ваш вопрос оффтоп, загляните в справку для подробностей. Попробуйте локализовать проблему для возможности однозначного ответа" и голосую за закрытие (с откатом голоса при положительных изменениях). Не думаю, что можно сделать что-то лучшее не вводя жёстких барьеров для новичков, что лишь отпугнёт оных.

---

> Что вы будете делать, если заблокировав участника, задающего вопросы качества ниже требуемого, отправив ему при этом шаблонное письмо, получите в ответ угрозы и требования откатить блокировку и вернуть все удаленные вопросы?
>
> <sub>Вопрос и контекст ситуации полностью: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5997/6</sub>

Пожалуюсь в чатик на несправедливость с меткой [модераторский-произвол](/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb) и попрошу участника вернуться в русло конструктивного общения. Если это не поможет - посмотрю какие ещё модераторские инструменты можно применить для пресечения нарушителя принципа `be nice`.

---

> Система голосования за закрытие, удаление и многое другое на Stack Overflow устроена таким образом, что став модератором вам всегда будет достаточно лишь одного вашего голоса для того, чтобы изменения вступили в силу. Готовы ли вы нести *единоличную ответственность* за каждое ваше решение относительно судьбы вопросов, ответов и комментариев, без права на ошибку? Что вы будете делать, если обнаружите, что ошиблись?

Готов и уже пробовал в действии. Золотые знаки по меткам работают аналогично - один голос для закрытия дубликатов. Выработал уже для себя осторожность в этих случаях и пользуюсь возможностью отзыва голоса при возникновении новых обстоятельств.

---

> Расскажите, как вы решаете проблемы или выполняете задачи модерации сайта и сообщества? Что конкретно вы для этого уже сделали? Каков результат? Будет здорово, если вы скажете пару слов о том, почему это важно для всех и для вас лично.
>
> <sub>Вопрос и контекст ситуации полностью: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6048/6</sub>

Отслеживаю новые вопросы, правлю метки, направляю новичков в сторону более качественной формулировки, кидаю тревоги на некорректные сообщения. Результат? Наблюдал развитие участников от не умеющих сформулировать вопрос до многотысячереповых отвечающих, помогающих новичкам. Тешу себя мыслью о том, что в этом есть и часть моей заслуги. Думаю, вполне очевидна важность комфортного использования сайта всеми заинтересованными сторонами. Мне же просто приятно способствовать поддержанию комфортной для меня и других среды общения и обмена знаниями.

---

> Назовите 4 главных качества, которыми, на ваш взгляд, должен обладать модератор Stack Overflow на русском.

Хладнокровие, выдержка, терпимость к рутине в очередях тревог и проверок и способность разбирать конфликтные ситуации.

---

> Как вы собираетесь действовать в ситуации, когда трактовка одного или нескольких правил (официальных или принятых сообществом на Мете) одного из участников или группы участников расходится с вашим пониманием этих же правил?

Поднять обсуждение на мете. Выработка сообществом более чёткой формулировки решит проблему в смысле определения какую именно трактовку разделяет большинство заинтересованных сторон. После этого надо будет лишь найти в себе силы следовать принятому решению, которое, возможно, не совсем мне близко.

---

> Работать на благо сообщества вы можете и без статуса модератора. Так зачем вы действительно решили стать модератором?

Для увеличения эффективности уже проводящихся мероприятий по нанесению добра.

Comment: Вопрос про комментарий — совсем не про комментарий. Пожалуйста, прочитайте то, что по ссылке.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну, я, конечно же, решу ситуацию легко, изящно и к вящей выгоде всех заинтересованных сторон) Ответ дополнил)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб В целом ответы на вопросы нравятся. И вы как кандидат тоже. Но тут вообще не понятна необходимость использования кастомной причины, когда есть вполне стандартная "primarily opinion-based" или в русском варианте "необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ" которая от вашей кастомной мало чем отличается.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov кастомную причину в данном случае, считаю, стоит написать ради показа ТС-у более персонального сообщения. Стандартная причина может создать у него впечатление, что все на сайте против него. А это, кмк, не очень приятно для него и не очень полезно для привлечения новых участников на сайт) Если бы злых комментов не было под вопросом, то тогда стандартная причина вполне бы подошла.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Можно же закрыть и добавить добрый комментарий, где поблагодарить участника за смелость задать вопрос (а это правда требует смелость) и желание прийти к истине и спокойно объяснить, что ответы на данные вопросы сродни религии/вкусовый пристрастий/любимому цвету и т.д. И поэтому неформат на данном сайте. Ну то есть слова утешения/подбодрения/направления в нужном направлени можно вынести в отдельный комментарий, не дублируя уже существующию причину закрытия.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, можно и так) Таких случаев, надеюсь, будет мало и да - в каждом таком случае можно более пространный коммент написать)

Comment: Я не знаю, сюда ли писать об отзывах, но когда писал под андроид - и задавал крайне глупые вопросы, Юрий всегда тактично и терпеливо излагал суть проблемы, и направлял в нужное русло. Надеялся, что выставишь свою кандидатуру, потому что на мой взгляд именно таким и должен быть модератор.
Собственно всё то, что было заявлено в ответах, я лично видел в том или ином виде, так что не сомневаюсь в данном кандидате в роли модератора.

Comment: @Silento, спасибо) Если меня выберут - я не подведу)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, А зачем вам становиться модератором? В чем плюс того что вы будете тратить больше времени на данный сайт?

Comment: @EraNewGames, в данный момент слишком часта ситуация когда я захожу сюда, а вопросов, которые мне интересны и на которые я могу нет. А время как-то надо убить. Так будет чем заняться)

Answer (score 14):

## [A K](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/213987/a-k)

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

По правилам поступлю. Я не считаю высокую репутацию индульгенцией. Заслуживает бана — значит без всяких скидок "давайте побыстрее выпустим его, он сможет много хороших ответов дать".

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

Сколько видел движок сайта — многие операции подразумевают откат, восстановление или отмену. Поэтому всегда есть время поговорить и спросить мнение другого человека. Возможно, меня переубедят, возможно я поменяю точку зрения. Если к общему знаменателю придти не получается — нужно смотреть по конкретным обстоятельствам: можно и в чате спросить у старожилов, можно у коллег по модерированию, можно уточнить у Николаса, можно на мете вопрос поднять.

---

> Как вы поступите, если увидите «комментарий–шутку», смешную только автору комментария, от давно известного вам участника сообщества, с которым вы находитесь в приятельских отношениях?
>
> <sub>Вопрос и контекст ситуации полностью: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5995/6</sub>

Здесь мягкий вариант ситуации, а по ссылке — более жесткий. В простом случае, когда шутка находится в рамках приемлемого может хватить просто обозначить своё присутствие в комментариях, либо если давний участник присутствует в чате — написать в чат (новички редко заглядывают туда), вполне возможно, что получится урезонить обоих.

В острых ситуациях нужно прямо обращаться к участникам с требованием соблюдать порядок и быть готовым забанить обоих на сутки: чтобы не успели наговорить на горячую голову и немного остыли.

---

> Как вы предлагаете решать проблему новичков, которые плохо знают правила (например, не прочитали справку), и задают вопросы, лежащие на грани офтопика (или за ней)?
> Речь идет не о явном спаме или вопросах, вовсе не относящихся к компьютерам и/или программированию, а скорее о вопросах от незлонамеренных новичков, не знающих, что тут принято, а что нет.

Я знаю лишь один по-настоящему действенный способ: каждый раз в подобных случаях приводить ссылки на конкретные статьи справки или топики на мете. Это очень нудная, неблагодарная работа — однако всё остальное на мой взгляд просто не работает.

---

> Что вы будете делать, если заблокировав участника, задающего вопросы качества ниже требуемого, отправив ему при этом шаблонное письмо, получите в ответ угрозы и требования откатить блокировку и вернуть все удаленные вопросы?
>
> <sub>Вопрос и контекст ситуации полностью: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5997/6</sub>

Чисто физиологически человеку нужно порядка 25 минут, чтобы отойти и успокоиться. Сразу отвечать — бесполезно, сразу можно только уведомить коллег и Николаса, чтобы были в курсе ситуации.

Ответ можно отправить позже. Я в подобных случаях методично апеллирую к фактам и правилам, "ничего личного".

---

> Система голосования за закрытие, удаление и многое другое на Stack Overflow устроена таким образом, что став модератором вам всегда будет достаточно лишь одного вашего голоса для того, чтобы изменения вступили в силу. Готовы ли вы нести *единоличную ответственность* за каждое ваше решение относительно судьбы вопросов, ответов и комментариев, без права на ошибку? Что вы будете делать, если обнаружите, что ошиблись?

Как там? "Бойцовый кот есть самостоятельная боевая единица сама в себе, способная справиться с любой мыслимой и немыслимой неожиданностью" ))

У меня много проверок в очередях и я по опыту знаю, что в большинстве своём это качественные проверки. Поэтому вполне могу в случае необходимости принять единоличное решение и нести персональную ответственность.

Насчёт ошибок? Не вижу проблемы. Ошибки есть у всех, если найдутся — значит, нужно будет переделать правильно. Я свой код трёхлетней давности научился принимать как есть, а что до ошибок — то я не боюсь сделать ошибку, я лишь стараюсь не повторять их дважды.

---

> Расскажите, как вы решаете проблемы или выполняете задачи модерации сайта и сообщества? Что конкретно вы для этого уже сделали? Каков результат? Будет здорово, если вы скажете пару слов о том, почему это важно для всех и для вас лично.
>
> <sub>Вопрос и контекст ситуации полностью: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6048/6</sub>

Чаще всего и дольше всего я сижу в нашей бездонной очереди на закрытие вопросов. Какая-то медитативная штука, как семечки подсолнуха: глубина-глубина, отпусти меня...

Если же говорить о моей специализации — то меня не "штырит" ни локализация, ни метки, у меня своё уникальное "хобби" на стеке: мне нравится писать посты на мете.

Писателем как я мечтал в юности я не стал, но привык воспринимать и осознавать себя как "человека пишущего". Я и метачитатель и метаписатель )) Четвёртое место в годовом рейтинге меты, много "хороших" постов, "бронза" в обсуждении, раз даже [почти поймал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5568/213987) реверс. Судя по статистике я чаще пишу в метках "модерация", "вопросы" и "ответы" — и это в общем-то [подмножество](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=40346710#40346710) модераторских меток.

---

> Назовите 4 главных качества, которыми, на ваш взгляд, должен обладать модератор Stack Overflow на русском.

В порядке убывания важности:

1. Человечность. (Это очень нечёткое определение, там ключевое слово — про гуманизм)
2. Ответственность

Я не хочу дописывать третий и четвёртый пункт, чтобы подчеркнуть важность этих двух качеств.

---

> Как вы собираетесь действовать в ситуации, когда трактовка одного или нескольких правил (официальных или принятых сообществом на Мете) одного из участников или группы участников расходится с вашим пониманием этих же правил?

Это повод для обсуждения в чате, либо сразу на мете. Иногда лучше — превентивного обсуждения, иногда — дождавшись конкретного случая.
Главное в правилах — соблюдать их, даже если они тебе не нравятся.

Конкретный пример: мне очень хочется, чтобы на so расширили онтопик. Но поскольку тут моё мнение идёт вразрез с мнением большинства — подчиняюсь общему порядку.

---

> Работать на благо сообщества вы можете и без статуса модератора. Так зачем вы действительно решили стать модератором?

Мне здесь нравится. Модератором я смогу сделать больше.

Comment: Согласен с вами по многим пунктам. Про человечность - особенно.

Comment: Думаю, что у вас есть необходимый набор качеств. Вы владеете словом (что бы там ни говорили про запятые) и проявили себя на Мете. В ответах и комментариях видно уважение к собеседникам. По комментарию к ответам rjhdby видно, что вы скорее склонны поддержать коллегу, даже когда между вами есть формальная конкуренция. Мне

Answer (score 9):

## [Sergey Gornostaev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/204271/sergey-gornostaev)

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

Прежде всего надо убедиться в адекватности тревог и создают ли их разные пользователи или одни и те же. Во-первых, я уже сталкивался с обиженными пользователями, которые бегают за обидчиком и жалуются на все его ответы и комментарии. Во-вторых, в спорах рождается истина, даже если сами споры какую-то часть общества тревожат. Наконец, если споры действительно многочисленны и бесплодны, а тревоги обоснованы, с виновником торжества стоит поговорить. В случае непонимания с его стороны, подвергнуть санкциям. В долгосрочной перспективе "скандальный талант" приносит больше вреда, чем пользы.

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

Обсужу моё мнение с этим модератором приватно. Если не договоримся, можно собрать модераторский кворум.

---

> Как вы поступите, если увидите «комментарий–шутку», смешную только автору комментария, от давно известного вам участника сообщества, с которым вы находитесь в приятельских отношениях?
>
> <sub>Вопрос и контекст ситуации полностью: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5995/6</sub>

Дружба дружбой, а служба службой. Буду удалять.

Если углубляться в контекст:

- Вопрос закрывать, как дубль. Переписку между новичком и приятелем удалять. И новичку, и приятелю вынести предупреждение.
- Правила и законы работают только тогда, когда они для всех едины, а наказание за их нарушение неотвратимо. Стоит один раз сделать кому-нибудь поблажку, и сообщество будет припоминать это регулярно.
- Не готов дать дословные тексты. Новичку укажу на недопустимость нецензурных выражений. Постараюсь мягко и ненавязчиво донести мысль о том, что он пришёл **просить помощи**, а потому ему стоит уважительно относится к другим пользователям. В том числе к тем, кто в их перепалке не участвовал, но оскорблён неподобающим поведением был. А текст приятелю зависит от степени приятельских отношений. От "ты ставишь меня в неудобное положение" до "я подъеду минут через десять и буду тебя бить".

---

> Как вы предлагаете решать проблему новичков, которые плохо знают правила (например, не прочитали справку), и задают вопросы, лежащие на грани офтопика (или за ней)?
> Речь идет не о явном спаме или вопросах, вовсе не относящихся к компьютерам и/или программированию, а скорее о вопросах от незлонамеренных новичков, не знающих, что тут принято, а что нет.

Нужен шаблонный текст, мотивирующий на чтение правил через призыв к совести и благоразумию. С первым вопросом можно помочь, исправив его должным образом. Не проявляющие совести и благоразумия должны получать всё более строгую реакцию на каждое следующее нарушение, вплоть до бана.

---

> Что вы будете делать, если заблокировав участника, задающего вопросы качества ниже требуемого, отправив ему при этом шаблонное письмо, получите в ответ угрозы и требования откатить блокировку и вернуть все удаленные вопросы?
>
> <sub>Вопрос и контекст ситуации полностью: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5997/6</sub>

Не буду на угрозы реагировать. Если вопросы и ответы пользователя не имеют ценности, удалю учётку. Иначе заблокирую на более долгий срок.

Давным-давно один "гений" сначала нахамил и угрожал мне в переписке, а потом стал угрожать судом. Отправил ему скан-копию искового заявления со скриншотами его зажигательных текстов. На этом переписка закончилась.

В ещё более старые времена у меня иногда находилось время и желание выезжать к угрожающим связями с целью демонстрации того, что в эту игру могут играть двое.

---

> Система голосования за закрытие, удаление и многое другое на Stack Overflow устроена таким образом, что став модератором вам всегда будет достаточно лишь одного вашего голоса для того, чтобы изменения вступили в силу. Готовы ли вы нести *единоличную ответственность* за каждое ваше решение относительно судьбы вопросов, ответов и комментариев, без права на ошибку? Что вы будете делать, если обнаружите, что ошиблись?

Нести ответственность готов, но всё же предпочту уступать эту роль сообществу и вмешиваться в процесс закрытия вопросов только в случаях действительно того требующих.

---

> Расскажите, как вы решаете проблемы или выполняете задачи модерации сайта и сообщества? Что конкретно вы для этого уже сделали? Каков результат? Будет здорово, если вы скажете пару слов о том, почему это важно для всех и для вас лично.
>
> <sub>Вопрос и контекст ситуации полностью: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6048/6</sub>

Я регулярно исправляю тексты с неправильным употреблением предлога "с" вместо "из"!

Если серьёзно, чаще всего я исправляю форматирование, теги и заголовки. Последнее - это настоящая беда, каждый второй считает заголовок "Почему так?" достаточным. Периодически просматриваю очереди. Правда, не нашёл в себе пока сил среагировать на первые сообщения. А я ещё я пишу комментарии "Если ответ помог вам, [отметьте его решением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)" и, видят боги, не всегда к своим собственным ответам.

---

> Назовите 4 главных качества, которыми, на ваш взгляд, должен обладать модератор Stack Overflow на русском.

1. Невозмутимость
2. Справедливость
3. Убедительность
4. Внимательность

---

> Как вы собираетесь действовать в ситуации, когда трактовка одного или нескольких правил (официальных или принятых сообществом на Мете) одного из участников или группы участников расходится с вашим пониманием этих же правил?

Собирать модераторский кворум. Возможно, выносить обсуждение спорного правила на суд общества на Мете, если модераторы не договорятся между собой и будут не против такого способа решения проблемы.

---

> Работать на благо сообщества вы можете и без статуса модератора. Так зачем вы действительно решили стать модератором?

Я всё время нахожусь в поисках нового опыта.

Comment: "удалю учётку". Не думаю, что у модератора здесь есть такие полномочия. Но может быть ошибаюсь.

Comment: @alexolut есть.

Comment: @NickVolynkin после этого мыло попадает в черный список или что происходит (помимо самого удаления акка)?

Comment: @alexolut про мыло не знаю.

Comment: @alexolut если я не ошибаюсь то аккаунт не удаляется а обнуляется.

Answer (score 9):

## [Qwertiy](//ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy)

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

В зависимости от характера споров. Если споры технически и обоснованные, то всё хорошо (хотя, конечно, маловероятно, что такие споры будут получать тревоги - может, надо посмотреть на ставящего их и немного пообщаться). Если споры оффтопичные - переносить в чат и поговорить, чтобы в следующий раз болтал в чате, а не в комментах. Ну а уж если там что-то плохое, то поообщаться и при необходимости забанить.

Конечно, ценность вклада играет роль (да вспомнить тот же [Time to take a stand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342440/time-to-take-a-stand)), но права на агрессию уж точно не даёт.

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

Если это какая-то мелочь, либо я вижу, что ситуация изменилась с того момента, могу и восстановить/переоткрыть. Если речь идёт о чём-то, что затрагивает всё сообщество - однозначно на мету с вопросом ([пример](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5457/178988)). Но в большинстве случаев - просто пообщаться с модератором и обсудить, какие у каждого из нас причины.

> Как вы поступите, если увидите «комментарий–шутку», смешную только автору комментария, от давно известного вам участника сообщества, с которым вы находитесь в приятельских отношениях?
>
> <sub>Вопрос и контекст ситуации полностью: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5995/6</sub>

Если шутка **смешная только для автора комментария,** то этот комментарий можно удалить и, при необходимости, пообщаться с комментатором.

Но если открыть контекст вопроса по ссылке, то там наоборот говорится:

> Комментарий у него тоже шутливый, даже саркастический. **Похоже, что шутка понравилась всем, кроме новичка** — комментарий заплюсован.

В таком случае я оставлю комментарий, а новичку просто скажу, что его никто не хотел обидеть. Поощрять нытьё "ой, мне тут как-то не так ответили", если все считают, что ответили так, точно не следует. Такие пользователи обычно рано или поздно либо чему-то учатся, либо ловят бан (причём многократный). Естественно, за негативную реакцию на комментарий-шутку как-то административно реагировать нельзя, но и способствовать такому поведению тоже не следует.

> А если ... be nice ...

Тут в любом случае индивидуальный подход. И есть две грани:

1. Шутка безобидная, но новичок из тех, кто обижается на всех подряд.
2. Шутка очень обидная и не понравилась всем.

В этих случаях, думаю, действия очевидны. А в промежуточных - по ситуации. Я стараюсь оценивать намерения, а не результат. Можно обидеть случайно, а можно специально. Если это сделано специально - удалить и предупредить написавшего. Если случайно - у модератора ведь есть права на правку комментария - можно что-то подкорректировать, можно просто пообщаться с обидевшимся. Вариантов много.

> Как вы предлагаете решать проблему новичков, которые плохо знают правила (например, не прочитали справку), и задают вопросы, лежащие на грани офтопика (или за ней)?
> Речь идет не о явном спаме или вопросах, вовсе не относящихся к компьютерам и/или программированию, а скорее о вопросах от незлонамеренных новичков, не знающих, что тут принято, а что нет.

Как было посчитано, сайт может без вреда содержать 4% оффтопика.

Если новичок задаёт **хороший интересный вопрос** *немного* за гранью оффтопика, то интересность вопроса перевешивает. Вполне можно написать комментарий в духе "Вопрос хороший, но на будущее стоит учесть, что он несколько выходит за рамки тематики сайта." Вопрос я при этом оставлю открытым и даже поставлю ему плюс.

Если же **вопрос плохой**, то его стоит помочь улучшить, либо закрыть, если улучшить невозможно.

> Что вы будете делать, если заблокировав участника, задающего вопросы качества ниже требуемого, отправив ему при этом шаблонное письмо, получите в ответ угрозы и требования откатить блокировку и вернуть все удаленные вопросы?
>
> <sub>Вопрос и контекст ситуации полностью: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5997/6</sub>

Ничего. Он уже забанен. Если после бана не одумается и продолжит в старом стиле, словит ещё один бан за новые заслуги. А грубый ответ на бан я просто проигнорирую.

Из контекста:

> Вчера он завел новую учётку и продолжает спрашивать с того же IP.

Вроде бы система авоматически банит IP, но если нет, то забанить IP на день. Написать Николасу, чтобы смёрджил учётки.

> Система голосования за закрытие, удаление и многое другое на Stack Overflow устроена таким образом, что, став модератором, вам всегда будет достаточно лишь одного вашего голоса для того, чтобы изменения вступили в силу. Готовы ли вы нести *единоличную ответственность* за каждое ваше решение относительно судьбы вопросов, ответов и комментариев, без права на ошибку? Что вы будете делать, если обнаружите, что ошиблись?

Я довольно гибко отношусь к правилам, поэтому маловероятно, что я неожиданно кому-то наврежу. Если будут сомнения, всегда есть кнопка "пропустить". Если ошибся, то все действия на сайте обратимы и это хорошо.

> Расскажите, как вы решаете проблемы или выполняете задачи модерации сайта и сообщества? Что конкретно вы для этого уже сделали? Каков результат? Будет здорово, если вы скажете пару слов о том, почему это важно для всех и для вас лично.
>
> <sub>Вопрос и контекст ситуации полностью: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6048/6</sub>

1. Внимательно просмотриваю сообщения в очередях проверок.
2. Стараюсь помогать улучшать вопросы, если пользователь того заслуживает.
3. Улучшаю сообщения правками.
4. Активен на мете.

И многое другое :)

> Назовите 4 главных качества, которыми, на ваш взгляд, должен обладать модератор Stack Overflow на русском.

1. Честность
2. Гибкость
3. Адекватность
4. Внимание

> Как вы собираетесь действовать в ситуации, когда трактовка одного или нескольких правил (официальных или принятых сообществом на Мете) одного из участников или группы участников расходится с вашим пониманием этих же правил?

Действовать в сторону наибольшего удобства пользователей вне зависимости от правил. Рассмотрим пример: 50% пользователей хотят видеть тему онтопиком, а 50% не хотят. Сайт технически предоставляет возможность скрывать вопросы по меткам, но не предоставляет возможности задавать где-то нетематические вопросы. Поэтому компромисс такой: тема рассматривается как онтопик, а сопротивляющимся даётся подсказка, как можно использовать инструменты сайта, чтобы её не видеть.

> Работать на благо сообщества вы можете и без статуса модератора. Так зачем вы действительно решили стать модератором?

1. Расширение доступа к удалённой информации.
2. Возможность принимать решения по заданным вопросам.

---

## По вопросам из комментариев

> Скажите. кого я сейчас опишу. Целый день сидит без дела и большую часть сил и времени тратит на навязывание своего мнения и проецирования своего представления о мире, в котором он целый день сидит без дела и большую часть сил и времени тратит на навязывание своего мнения и проецирования своего представления о мире. Это троль или модератор? Если модерирование не оплачивается, то зачем Вам это нужно? Если у Вас куча время, то значит Вы плохой специалист или у Вас неправильное понимание мира и Вам уж точно нельзя чем-то управлять, пусть даже таким ресурсом.

Начну с пары примеров.

[Jon Skeet](//stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) - пользователь на 1 месте enSO - известный разработчик на Java и C#, наиболее известен (по крайней мере, для меня) разработкой NodaTime - кроссплатформенной библиотеки для работы  со временем с учётом часовых поясов и кучи всяких неочевидных моментов. Является автором книги C# in Depth и ведёт собственный блог.

[Eric Lippert](//stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) - на 26 месте не enSO. Разработчик языка vbscript, один из создателей платформы .net и языка C#, тоже ведёт свой блог.

Наличие времени на ответы на вопросы, ведение блогов и написание книг вовсе не характеризует специалиста как плохого. Скорее наоборот, большинство хороших специалистов что-то из этого делают. На самом деле, это способ систематизации и саморазвития. Можно заглянуть в [вопрос на эту тему](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305/178988), но как оказалось, я там не отвечал.

Что же касается именно модерирования, то мне оно видится как расширение возможностей по описанным в этом ответе направлениям.

Comment: Единственный пункт, который очень сильно смущает "В таком случае я оставлю комментарий, а новичку просто скажу, что его никто не хотел обидеть.". Если комментарий содержит сарказм, то есть насмешку, то он противоречит одному из главных правил [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). Неужели, это нормально когда комментарий может хотя бы кого-то обижать? Зачем ему здесь находиться на сайте для обмена IT-знаний?

Comment: В пункте про "Если шутка смешная только для автора комментария, то этот комментарий можно удалить" нет тоже оговорки про [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). А если шутка смешная не только автору, пусть даже многим, но сама шутка обидная, то можно?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, уточнил ответ.

Comment: Мне stackoverflow нравится именно этой дружелюбной атмосферой, а сарказм бы всё портил. Из поста ["Шутки здесь неуместны"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2697/220571) явно следует, что шутка — по умолчанию кандидат на удаление. И если всё-таки придерживаться здешних правил, то шутка, которая хотя бы малость саркастичная, то без исключений должна удалятся. То есть если и оставлять некоторые, то как исключение. Комментарии тем более надо стараться чистить, если они не несут положительной информации (вне зависимости от смысла). Всё по возможности переносить в посты. А шуткам здесь не место…

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, любое действие должно соответствовать ситуации. Если кто-то утверждает, что исключений не бывает, то ему либо нельзя верить, либо он действительно всегда действует по правилам, [что лучше с ним не сталкиваться](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Comment: То, что я сказал, следует из нескольких разных FAQ-постов и является не только написанными, но ещё и исполняемыми на деле правилами. Даже если вас изберут модератором (вполне может быть), ваши действия должны в первую очередь опираться на правила, даже если вы бы хотели что-то поменять, а затем только на ваше усмотрение (надеюсь вы с этим согласны). Если вы хотите что-то поменять, то по-хорошему — только через мету и только через одобрение сообщества.

Comment: Вопросы: Будете саботировать неуместность шуток или нет в случае вашего избрания? Если кто-то отметит комментарий-шутку, как оскорбительную или "более не является необходимым", как отреагируете? Если модератор удалит шутку (даже безобидную), просто по причине неуместности, каковы ваши действия?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, если я что-то не удалю, это всегда может сделать кто-то ещё. Отреагирую в зависимости от ситуации (о чём написал в ответе). Если кто-то удалит, то без посторонних просьб сам восстанавливать не буду.

Comment: Извините, что беспокою сильно, просто выборы. Последние вопросы на сегодня: сделали бы вы о том, что писали в [посте](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5457/220571) единолично (если бы имели полномочия) или также бы написали пост на мете с желанием узнать мнения других? Изменилась ли у вас позиция по поводу справедливости бана для Squidward и уместности данных постов?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, ну можно повнимательнее? Куда ведёт ссылка "пример" в предложении _"Если речь идёт о чём-то, что затрагивает всё сообщество - однозначно на мету с вопросом (пример)"?_ Позиция по-прежнему, что можно было бы обойтись без бана. Да и пост можно было бы подпрасить, если уж так не хотелось его в том виде оставлять. И +14 -18 на моём вопросе подтверждают, что ситуация там действительно спорная.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Вы вырываете заголовок поста "Шутки здесь неуместны" из контекста. Он посвящён смешным *вопросам* и был написан в период формирования более жёстких правил оффтопика на большом СО. Другими словами, он не имеет к обсуждаемой ситуации абсолютно никакого отношения.

Comment: Единственный нормальный кандидат. Хочу только напомнить, что чувство юмора у каждого своё, а сам по себе юмор не несет ничего криминального. И не стоит трактовать правила в пользу того или иного пользователя, если правила сомнительны - нужно создавать критерии, по которым может быть однозначная трактовка, а если это невозможно - удалять правила и писать новые. Неоднозначность правил еще хуже их полного отсутствия. Это дает широкие возможности модератору и очень мало мотивации для простых участников, которым может быть неприятно жить под тенью тирана.

Comment: @OlmerDale, если ты перепутал меня с другим пользователем, то, может, перепишешь эти комментарии к нему (он тоже баллотируется), тут удалишь, а мне напишешь лично для меня?

Comment: @OlmerDale, ты как-то неправильно считаешь. У меня репутация 53203, ответов 2219, вопросов 187. Плюс на ответе даёт +10, на вопросе +5. Принятые ответы с их +15 проигнорируем. Среднее количество плюсов на сообщении 53203 / (2219*10 + 187*5) = 2.30. Теперь считаем у тебя по той же формуле: 1925 / (78*10 + 3*5) = 2.42. Получается, средний рейтинг твоих сообщений выше, чем моих. Так в чём заключается плюсование моих ответов?

Comment: @OlmerDale, _"а разве Вы не должны этому радоваться, что кто-то за Вас перенес напряжение с Вас на кого-то?)"_ - порадоваться-то я могу, но если кто-то будет просматривать комменты, то не факт что он обратит внимание на сообщение "всё это про другого кандидата" - за это и волнуюсь)

Comment: Убедили, удалил. Тогда вот ещё вопрос. Скажите. кого я сейчас опишу. Целый день сидит без дела и большую часть сил и времени тратит на навязывание своего мнения и проецирования своего представления о мире, в котором он целый день сидит без дела и большую часть сил и времени тратит на навязывание своего мнения и проецирования своего представления о мире. Это троль или модератор? Если модерирование не оплачивается, то зачем Вам это нужно? Если у Вас куча время, то значит Вы плохой специалист или у Вас неправильное понимание мира и Вам уж точно нельзя чем-то управлять, пусть даже таким ресурсом.

Comment: И это я не на Вас наседаю, это абсолютно всех касается. Но если Вы подумаете над этим и сформулируете такой же убедительный ответ, как предыдущий, может Вам это поможет очков  набрать.

Comment: @OlmerDale, ответ дополнен.

Comment: Я разработал десяток сайтов, подитожил книгой. Если бы я писал только книги, то меня бы не считали специалистом, а считали книгописцем. Если я буду уделять время чуть-чуть разработке, чуть-чуть книги, то я буду не писакой и недо разработчиком. Получается что если бы я выбирал модерирование как расширение способностей разработчика, то я бы просто ошибался, так как например, написание книг описывающих личный опыт повышает лишь умение конкретизировать информацию на профессиональном уровне.

Comment: То есть книга Вас обяжет назвать "вот это фиговину" "вот таким-то термином, который возможно Вы не знали, благодаря  проведеному анализу, открыли его для себя. Модераторство не сможет поднять Ваш профессионализм ни на каком уровне.Модераторство, это возможность банить, а редактировать и прочие сообщество может и без Вас. Так же модераторство это вникание в конфликты и умение их решать не прибегая к банам. Получается что модераторство круто для тех кто уже развит как профессионал и  хочет повысить навык в общении и понимание проблем людей.

Comment: Все хотят крови, все хотят банить, все просто озлобленные человечки. станьте тем, кто хочет решать бытовые конфликты без применения банов. Здесь все хотят стать полицейскими, которые решают все проблемы забиванием дубинкой и тотальным террором. Я бы как владелиц ресурса не взял бы ни одного. Кроме того, реально  нужно понять, что модераторство не поможет стать профессиональнее. Кроме того, эта борьба не должна ошпарить Вас, она должна задать  курс, который Вы в любой момент можете откорректировать.

Comment: @OlmerDale, я не стремлюсь банить. Бан - это крайняя мера, но иногда она неизбежна. Что касается работы с людьми - все из нас работают с людьми и умение разбираться в людях и решать конфликты весьма полезно.

Comment: Топовый претендент обещает выносить на мету размусоливание неоднозначных решений, но по факту показывает чтоне в состоянии решить проблему самостоятельно, а хочет переложить вину на АКТИВНОЕ сообщество, которое почти всегда и является причиной возникновения споров. Это не плюс, это доказательство того, что он не понимает что от него требуется. Было бы круто если бы чувачок-модератор был в состоянии показать что он достоин и понимает свои обязанности.

Comment: @OlmerDale 1. В той фразе про мету говорится об отмене действий другого модератора. Просто так взять и отменить - это в большинстве случаев неправильный вариант (ну что, два модератора будут по-тихому друг за другом отменять что ли?). 2. Площадка SO управляется сообществом - нечто типа демократии. Т. е. глобальные вопросы типа тематики или допустимости каких-то видов контента (подчёркиваю - именно видов, а не индивидуальных случаев) должны решаться голосованием сообщества. А роль модератора - поддерживать порядок, а не принимать общие решения вместо сообщества.

Comment: Ну вот смотрите. Важное для сообщества мероприятие, решается его судьба, выбирается модератор. Максимальное количество голосов 26.

Comment: Но если бы я был челом который имеет школу, а таких сейчас очень много, то я бы помимо всего прочего. решил взять судьбу в свои  руки и управлять мнением общества путем управления сообществом. для этого мне нужно создать либо 26 ботов либо 26 друзей позвать и  я  буду сразу крутым и все делать так, как решит созданное мной сообщество из 30 человек. то есть по факту 30 человек решают судьбу тысяч. Это ошибка и это не демократия, а терания во всех её проявлениях.

Comment: И чтобы как бы не было, реальность такова, что пять лет назад, здесь было просто офигинительно интересно, а сейчас политика привела к тому, что вопросы создаются ИИ и ответы им соответствующие. неужели Вы не видите? Это проблема вызвана именно самоуправством, какими-то выдуманными сообществами и ими выдуманными правилами.

Comment: Эти правила никому не нужны, кроме них. отстаивая какие-то пару десятков рублей сверху. разрушается система образования целой страны.Пусть старики вспомнят что было пять лет назад, какого уровня были вопросы и ответы.

Comment: Все сразу станет понятно и причина этому одна. это провацируют ИИ создаваемый теми кто выигрывает от этого лишнюю сотню рублей. почему об этом никто не хочет говорить? Может если можераторы будут узколобы  и говорить только о том о чем их спрашивают, то и ресурс будет такой же? Почему читая ответы мне кажется что это воспитатель в детском саду набирает команду ответственных за поведение других детей. Вам не кажется что это слишком банально? И это я не к чему-то конкретному и к Вам относящемуся, это я просто к слову и чтобы дать ещё раз задуматься о происходящем.

Comment: Может у кого-то идеи появятся.  Надоело видеть упадок.

Comment: @OlmerDale, _"Максимальное количество голосов 26"_ - это о чём? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/81/constituent - проголосовало 812 человек, из них 320 (сам не проверял это число) - два года назад. Получается, на этих выборах уже проголосовало 492 человека, каждый из которых поставил от 1 до 3 голосов.

Comment: а я по голосам здесь судил :) Так да, 800 это уже лучше. А если голосование всем навязывается автоматически, то почему всего 800? Неужели в России сообщество всего из 800 человек? Это же ничтожно мало..

Comment: @OlmerDale, потому что примерно половина вообще не голосует - [страницу выборов при наличии возможности проголосовать](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/80/caucus) посетило 1977, а [проголосовало](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/81/constituent) только 820. Какая нужна репутация, чтобы голосовать, я точно не знаю, но [156 - достаточно](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/81/constituent?userid=210231). У нас [примерно](//ru.stackoverflow.com/users?page=175&tab=reputation&filter=all) 175*36=6300 пользователей с репутацией 102 или больше, но, очевидно, не все они активны. 1000+ есть у ~936.

Answer (score 8):

## [rjhdby](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/210178/rjhdby)

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество
> ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые
> впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

Поговорю, если не поможет, то спрошу совета у бывалых :)

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и
> т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и
> т. д.?

Поинтересуюсь причиной. Попробую переубедить. Что делать не буду точно, так это отменять решение самостоятельно.

---

> Как вы поступите, если увидите «комментарий–шутку», смешную только
> автору комментария, от давно известного вам участника сообщества, с
> которым вы находитесь в приятельских отношениях?
>
> <sub>Вопрос и контекст ситуации полностью: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5995/6</sub>

В каждой шутке есть доля шутки. Если комментарий в целом полезен, не оскорбителен и не провоцирует флейм, то оставлю. Если явный оффтопик, то удалю и попрошу так больше не шутить. Без привязки к персоналиям.

Если конкретно по описанной ситуации, то:

1. Вопрос закрою как [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/263536/java-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-c-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81-%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5)
2. Комменты, включая шутошный, удалю.
3. С обоими проведу разъяснительную беседу.

---

> Как вы предлагаете решать проблему новичков, которые плохо знают
> правила (например, не прочитали справку), и задают вопросы, лежащие на
> грани офтопика (или за ней)? Речь идет не о явном спаме или вопросах,
> вовсе не относящихся к компьютерам и/или программированию, а скорее о
> вопросах от незлонамеренных новичков, не знающих, что тут принято, а
> что нет.

Не вижу в этом большой проблемы. Сообщество достаточно хорошо саморегулируется тревогами/голосами/комментариями. Если проблема действительно существует, то решать ее надо на уровне интерфейса. Вообще - это не самая простая задача из области юзабилити и на гора решение выдать не готов.

---

> Что вы будете делать, если заблокировав участника, задающего вопросы
> качества ниже требуемого, отправив ему при этом шаблонное письмо,
> получите в ответ угрозы и требования откатить блокировку и вернуть все
> удаленные вопросы?
>
> <sub>Вопрос и контекст ситуации полностью: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5997/6</sub>

Перебаню на более долгий срок.

---

> Система голосования за закрытие, удаление и многое другое на Stack
> Overflow устроена таким образом, что став модератором вам всегда будет
> достаточно лишь одного вашего голоса для того, чтобы изменения
> вступили в силу. Готовы ли вы нести единоличную ответственность за
> каждое ваше решение относительно судьбы вопросов, ответов и
> комментариев, без права на ошибку? Что вы будете делать, если
> обнаружите, что ошиблись?

Готов. Отменю решение.

---

> Расскажите, как вы решаете проблемы или выполняете задачи модерации
> сайта и сообщества? Что конкретно вы для этого уже сделали? Каков
> результат? Будет здорово, если вы скажете пару слов о том, почему это
> важно для всех и для вас лично.
>
> <sub>Вопрос и контекст ситуации полностью: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6048/6</sub>

Разбираю очереди проверок. Ставлю тревоги. Новичкам в комментариях даю советы по улучшению качества вопросов.

Тяжела и неказиста жизнь простого альтруиста. Мотивация очень простая - мне хорошо, когда вокруг меня хорошо. Вообще люблю делать этот мир лучше. Как-то так.

---

> Назовите 4 главных качества, которыми, на ваш взгляд, должен обладать
> модератор Stack Overflow на русском.

Спокойствие (невозмутимость, стрессоустойчивость). Усидчивость. Широкий кругозор/знание предметной области (в области ИТ так просто обязательно). Готовность помогать людям.

---

> Как вы собираетесь действовать в ситуации, когда трактовка одного или
> нескольких правил (официальных или принятых сообществом на Мете)
> одного из участников или группы участников расходится с вашим
> пониманием этих же правил?

Сильно зависит от контекста. Так то каждый имеет право на собственное мнение. Если же рассматривать вопрос в контексте каких либо спорных ситуаций, то имеет смысл вынести обсуждение на ту же мету.

---

> Работать на благо сообщества вы можете и без статуса модератора. Так
> зачем вы действительно решили стать модератором?

Раз выборы проводятся, значит новые модераторы действительно нужны. Я считаю, что подхожу на эту роль.

На самом деле вопрос больше про публичную ответственность. Кто-то должен этим заниматься. Я смогу. С другой стороны, если появятся кандидатуры, которые объективно справятся лучше меня, то буду голосовать за них.

Comment: Очень нравятся ваши ответы и позиция, но, к сожаленью, не нравится ваш ник. Возможно, он имеет смысл и значение, но выглядет как бессмысленный набор букв. Тем более что модератор должен быть примером для сообщества, а я считаю, что это ники-абракадабры — неэстетично. Но я не претендую, чтобы вы что-то меняли. Просто делюсь своей позицией.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Так исторически сложилось и это не бессмысленный набор букв. Зато точно ни с кем не спутаешь :)

Comment: @rjhdby хронники Амбера? :)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev бурные студенческие годы, толкинисты в нескучном... Как давно это было. :) Собственно нику уже около 20 лет, странно было бы менять. :)

Comment: А я не понимаю такую странную дискриминацию -- по никнеймам, аватаркам. Это настолько непринципиально... Судите по делам о человеке, а не по аватарке! Ужас, на so кальмар в модераторах или ёжик, как не стыдно! )) Ник вставлять руками не надо, везде есть автокомплит: наберите первую букву, дальше техника поможет.

Comment: @rjhdby а как вашь ник читается и что значит?(про толкиниста прочитал). Моих знаний в этой области не хватает для прочтения.

Comment: @Arantler Если в русской раскладке, то это "Корвин". Взялся из "Хроник Амбера".

Answer (score 4):

## [Suvitruf aka Андрей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/15479/suvitruf)

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

Ценные ответы – это, конечно же, хорошо, но они не дают права вести себя как мудак.
Проблема в том, что для спрашивающего эти комментарии могут быть обидными, но для другой стороны это может быть не очевидно. Для начала поговорю с обеими сторонами. Если не разрешится конфликт, то в случае неоднозначностей спрошу, что думают другие модераторы на этот счёт.

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

Обсужу с ним. Если не придём к консенсусу, то с другими модераторами переговорю или на мете вопрос задам.

---

> Как вы поступите, если увидите «комментарий–шутку», смешную только автору комментария, от давно известного вам участника сообщества, с которым вы находитесь в приятельских отношениях?
>
> <sub>Вопрос и контекст ситуации полностью: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5995/6</sub>

Шутейки шутить надо в компании друзей, к коим автор вопроса вряд ли относится. И тут даже дело не в том, что такой комментарий в принципе мусорный, но и в том, что он занимает место для полезных комментариев. Нужно, безусловно, смотреть на ситуацию. Но с большей вероятностью я такой комментарий удалю.
Предупреждение обеим сторонам. За рецидивы бан.
Что касается самого вопроса...Если это по своей природе оффтопик типо " Что лучше учить, Java или C#?", то закрою/удалю сам вопрос.

---

> Как вы предлагаете решать проблему новичков, которые плохо знают правила (например, не прочитали справку), и задают вопросы, лежащие на грани офтопика (или за ней)?
> Речь идет не о явном спаме или вопросах, вовсе не относящихся к компьютерам и/или программированию, а скорее о вопросах от незлонамеренных новичков, не знающих, что тут принято, а что нет.

Закрою вопрос с отпиской и ссылкой на доку. А вообще, я уже не раз про это писал, нужно как-то форсить людей изучать правила перед публикацией.

---

> Что вы будете делать, если заблокировав участника, задающего вопросы качества ниже требуемого, отправив ему при этом шаблонное письмо, получите в ответ угрозы и требования откатить блокировку и вернуть все удаленные вопросы?
>
> <sub>Вопрос и контекст ситуации полностью: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5997/6</sub>

Вероятно, проигнорирую. На этих хейтеров насмотрелся уже за годы модерации других ресурсов.
Человек остынет через какое-то время, может даже сам извинится. Что-то ему отвечать – это как подливать масла в огонь.

---

> Система голосования за закрытие, удаление и многое другое на Stack Overflow устроена таким образом, что, став модератором, вам всегда будет достаточно лишь одного вашего голоса для того, чтобы изменения вступили в силу. Готовы ли вы нести *единоличную ответственность* за каждое ваше решение относительно судьбы вопросов, ответов и комментариев, без права на ошибку? Что вы будете делать, если обнаружите, что ошиблись?

Да, в общем-то, я и сейчас, когда очереди просматриваю, голосую только если уверен в решении.
Но ошибки случаются, да. И это нормально. Волков бояться – в лес не ходить.

---

> Расскажите, как вы решаете проблемы или выполняете задачи модерации сайта и сообщества? Что конкретно вы для этого уже сделали? Каков результат? Будет здорово, если вы скажете пару слов о том, почему это важно для всех и для вас лично.
>
> <sub>Вопрос и контекст ситуации полностью: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6048/6</sub>

Каюсь, в последний год я на сайте не так часто сижу. Всё время на свой проект уходило. Недавно зарелизились, поэтому смогу больше времени посвящать проекту.
Касательно же вклада. Стараюсь просматривать очереди. Смотрю большую часть новых вопросов, редактирую если надо. Большая активность, всё же, именно как автора ответов, нежели как модератора.

---

> Назовите 4 главных качества, которыми, на ваш взгляд, должен обладать модератор Stack Overflow на русском.

1. Желание делиться своими знаниями.
2. Терпимость.
3. Большой IT бэкграунд.
4. Ответственность.

---

> Как вы собираетесь действовать в ситуации, когда трактовка одного или нескольких правил (официальных или принятых сообществом на Мете) одного из участников или группы участников расходится с вашим пониманием этих же правил?

А какие тут ещё варианты кроме обсуждения?

---

> Работать на благо сообщества вы можете и без статуса модератора. Так зачем вы действительно решили стать модератором?

О, мой вопрос с выборов 2015 года.

Вообще, это показывает уровень ответственности (я про сам статус модератора). Но главное, что это повод/мотивация заходить и работать усердней на благо портала. Не получится забивать на сайт, так как я буду нести ответственность перед сообществом.

Comment: Спасибо, что добавили настоящее имя. Мне приятнее и легче общаться с людьми, когда я знаю, как их зовут.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, но вы как действующий модератор можете заглянуть в поле личной информации в профиле...

Comment: @mymedia тут дело не в том, что он может посмотреть это в профиле, а в том, что человек представился в посте. Если вам при встрече человек своё имя назовёт, то совсем другой тон беседы будет. Здесь примерно тоже самое. По крайней мере, я так на это смотрю )

Answer (score 1):

### [Paulo Berezini](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/216198/paulo-berezini)

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество
>   ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые
>   впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

Вежливо попрошу его не провоцировать конфликтную ситуацию в комментариях. Если не поможет, чтобы остудить пыл следует наказать участника баном на краткий срок и после присмотреть за его дальнейшим поведением.

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и
>   т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и
>   т. д.?

Спрошу, почему он принял такое решение. Так как я не конфликтный человек, то вместе мы постараемся прийти к адекватному решению ситуации. Если один из нас в этой ситуации останется недоволен, я предложу перенести наш спор в мету, для огласки и помощи всех членов сообщества.

---

> Как вы поступите, если увидите «комментарий–шутку», смешную только
>   автору комментария, от давно известного вам участника сообщества, с
>   которым вы находитесь в приятельских отношениях?
>
> Вопрос и контекст ситуации полностью:
>   https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5995/6

Вопросы:

1. Что вы будете делать с вопросом, с новичком и с вашим знакомым?
2. Почему вы приняли такое решение? На какой результат вы рассчитываете?
3. Если вы решили написать кому-либо из участников — дополните свой ответ текстом этого сообщения.
4. Данный вопрос не имеет однозначного ответа, порождает спор и уже начинает переходить на оскорбления личностей, поэтому я сразу же закрою его, для новичка оставлю комментарий [Как правильно задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking), и укажу ему на проблему в его вопросе и как себя вести. "Моего знакомого", я предупрежу что не красиво и бесчеловечно издеваться над новичками, он все это поймет, извинится и больше никогда так не поступит. В других случаях, если это не в первый раз, я рассмотрю кандидатуру "Моего знакомого" к бану.
5. Я принял такое решение, потому, что я честный и все примеряю на себе, потому что у меня был подобный опыт со стороны "Новичка" и я прекрасно понимаю как тяжело, когда ты пришел просить помощи, но не знаешь как это правильно сделать, а тебе сразу прилетают минусы и все начинают над тобой шутить и смеяться. Результатом будет мир и спокойствие.
6. Для новичка:

Добрый день. Ваш вопрос не имеет однозначного ответа и порождает спор. Ознакомьтесь пожалуйста с правилами, как правильно задавать вопрос, чтобы получить на него достойный ответ. Если у вас остались какие-либо вопросы, можете обратиться ко мне на прямую, я вам обязательно помогу.

[Ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Для "Моего знакомого":

Добрый день. Предупреждаю Вас, что нельзя шутить над людьми, которые ищут помощи и менее опытны чем вы. В следующий раз рекомендую Вам оставить комментарий, который помог бы освоиться новичку, и создать тревогу по данному вопросу. Иначе я вынесу Вашу кандидатуру к рассмотрению о бане учетной записи.

---

> Как вы предлагаете решать проблему новичков, которые плохо знают
>   правила (например, не прочитали справку), и задают вопросы, лежащие на
>   грани оффтопика (или за ней)? Речь идет не о явном спаме или вопросах,
>   вовсе не относящихся к компьютерам и/или программированию, а скорее о
>   вопросах от незлонамеренных новичков, не знающих, что тут принято, а
>   что нет.

Исходя из того, по какой тематике вопрос, я скидываю общую ссылку "как задавать вопросы" и конкретную ссылку, где описывается его случай.

---

> Что вы будете делать, если заблокировав участника, задающего вопросы
>   качества ниже требуемого, отправив ему при этом шаблонное письмо,
>   получите в ответ угрозы и требования откатить блокировку и вернуть все
>   удаленные вопросы?
>
> Вопрос и контекст ситуации полностью:
>   https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5997/6

Вынесу его учетную запись на обсуждение, и через некоторое время мы решим что с ним делать и подлежит ли его кандидатура реинкарнации.

---

> Система голосования за закрытие, удаление и многое другое на Stack
>   Overflow устроена таким образом, что став модератором вам всегда будет
>   достаточно лишь одного вашего голоса для того, чтобы изменения
>   вступили в силу. Готовы ли вы нести единоличную ответственность за
>   каждое ваше решение относительно судьбы вопросов, ответов и
>   комментариев, без права на ошибку? Что вы будете делать, если
>   обнаружите, что ошиблись?

Отвечу цитатой из фильма:

> Тебе дан редкий дар Питер, Чем больше сила, тем больше и ответственность.
>
> ф. "Человек паук"

Людям свойственны ошибки, и я тоже человек. Я готов ответить за свои ошибки и принять что я не прав. Я всегда говорю: "Мало кто умеет говорить что он не прав или не знает что-то. Вот тут я не прав".

---

> Расскажите, как вы решаете проблемы или выполняете задачи модерации
>   сайта и сообщества? Что конкретно вы для этого уже сделали? Каков
>   результат? Будет здорово, если вы скажете пару слов о том, почему это
>   важно для всех и для вас лично.
>
> Вопрос и контекст ситуации полностью:
>   https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6048/6

Я очень много времени провожу за очередью проверок. Я очень часто смотрю все новые вопросы, подряд. По выходным я открываю вопросы, которые я не успел посмотреть за неделю, либо выбираю метку какая мне нравится и ищу проблематичные вопросы, ответы, правлю, даю рекомендации. Результат всегда положительный, многие благодарят, многие обращаются лично в VK и спрашивают там разные вопросы. Один из последних: "Как научиться программировать и с чего начать, какой язык?". Я отвечаю всем, я люблю общение. Некоторые просят дать им задание и проследить за выполнением. И все это бывает обычно, после простого редактирования вопроса.

---

> Назовите 4 главных качества, которыми, на ваш взгляд, должен обладать
>   модератор Stack Overflow на русском.

1. Трудолюбивый
2. Честный
3. Ответственный
4. Дружелюбный

---

> Как вы собираетесь действовать в ситуации, когда трактовка одного или
>   нескольких правил (официальных или принятых сообществом на Мете)
>   одного из участников или группы участников расходится с вашим
>   пониманием этих же правил?

Я пересмотрю свою точку зрения. Всем советую почитать книгу "Мужчины с Марса, женщины с Венеры", она показывает различия в мышлении мужчины и женщины. Если я с чем то не согласен ставлю себя на место другого человека и пытаюсь понять проблему с его стороны, я так поступаю всегда, когда я не согласен. И да я могу сразу же пересмотреть своё отношение к правилам, потому что я не правильно думал.

---

> Работать на благо сообщества вы можете и без статуса модератора. Так
>   зачем вы действительно решили стать модератором?

Я проактивный человек - только тот, кто может управлять собой, может управлять другими. Статус модератора позволяет помогать, решать вопросы и проблемные ситуации более быстро.

Comment: Всё круто, но вот это странно выглядит: «многие обращаются лично в VK и спрашивают там разные вопросы». А почему не задают ещё один вопрос на сайте?

Comment: В [своей заявке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/2#post-728700) вы дословно переписали [текст справки со страницы оформления заявки](https://hsto.org/webt/59/dc/4d/59dc4d51004e6643360649.png). Зачем?

Comment: @NickVolynkin я уже на это отвечал, отвечу более развернуьто: я просто не понимаю, даны критерии, я им соответствую, зачем придумывать что то новое. Пример "Вы должны знать технологии java" я должен написать "Я знаю сильно типизированный объектно-ориентированный язык программирования, разработанный компанией Sun Microsystems" или написать "Я знаю технологии Java", вроде не запрещено соответствовать требованиям. Не задают вопрос на сайте потому что вопрос: "какой язык программирования учить java или python" некорректный

Answer (score -4):

## [Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy)

> Как вы поступите с участником, который создает большое количество ценных ответов, но порождает массу споров в комментариях, которые впоследствии отмечаются сигналом тревоги?

Забаню.

---

> Как вы поступите в ситуации, когда другой модератор закроет, удалит и т. д. вопрос, который, по вашему мнению, не стоит закрывать, удалять и т. д.?

Если лучше разбираюсь в теме вопроса - переоткрою, если нет - оставлю как есть.

---

> Как вы поступите, если увидите «комментарий–шутку», смешную только автору комментария, от давно известного вам участника сообщества, с которым вы находитесь в приятельских отношениях?
>
> <sub>Вопрос и контекст ситуации полностью: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5995/6</sub>

Вопрос - закрою, комментарии - почищу, знакомому - бан.

---

> Как вы предлагаете решать проблему новичков, которые плохо знают правила (например, не прочитали справку), и задают вопросы, лежащие на грани офтопика (или за ней)?
> Речь идет не о явном спаме или вопросах, вовсе не относящихся к компьютерам и/или программированию, а скорее о вопросах от незлонамеренных новичков, не знающих, что тут принято, а что нет.

Вопросы закрывать, новичков отправлять на страницы справки и мету.

---

> Что вы будете делать, если заблокировав участника, задающего вопросы качества ниже требуемого, отправив ему при этом шаблонное письмо, получите в ответ угрозы и требования откатить блокировку и вернуть все удаленные вопросы?
>
> <sub>Вопрос и контекст ситуации полностью: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5997/6</sub>

Ничего, участник и так забанен.

---

> Система голосования за закрытие, удаление и многое другое на Stack Overflow устроена таким образом, что став модератором вам всегда будет достаточно лишь одного вашего голоса для того, чтобы изменения вступили в силу. Готовы ли вы нести *единоличную ответственность* за каждое ваше решение относительно судьбы вопросов, ответов и комментариев, без права на ошибку? Что вы будете делать, если обнаружите, что ошиблись?

Уже есть *единоличная ответственность* за дубликаты. В случае ошибок всегда можно переоткрыть.

---

> Расскажите, как вы решаете проблемы или выполняете задачи модерации сайта и сообщества? Что конкретно вы для этого уже сделали? Каков результат? Будет здорово, если вы скажете пару слов о том, почему это важно для всех и для вас лично.
>
> <sub>Вопрос и контекст ситуации полностью: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6048/6</sub>

- 1,375 правок
- 579 полезных тревог
- 2,920 голосов

---

> Назовите 4 главных качества, которыми, на ваш взгляд, должен обладать модератор Stack Overflow на русском.

- честность
- неподкупность
- справедливость
- невозмутимость

---

> Как вы собираетесь действовать в ситуации, когда трактовка одного или нескольких правил (официальных или принятых сообществом на Мете) одного из участников или группы участников расходится с вашим пониманием этих же правил?

Задам вопрос на мете.

---

> Работать на благо сообщества вы можете и без статуса модератора. Так зачем вы действительно решили стать модератором?

- смотреть удаленные комментарии
- доступ к информации пользователей
- возможность забанить несогласных!

Comment: Не пора ли в имя добавить ™? :)

Comment: "Если лучше разбираюсь в теме вопроса - переоткрою, если нет - оставлю как есть" А как вы определите уровень компетентности другого модератора?

Comment: Почему-то не во всех ответах есть слово "забаню", непорядок! Вам есть ещё куда расти!

Comment: @AK, потому что в остальных _ и так забанен_ :-D

Comment: @Suvitruf, модераторов не так много, компетенции каждого уже известны

Comment: @alexolut, не, вдруг DC будет против :-D

Comment: @Grundy, а почему у вас с августа нет ни одной проверки? Вы уже всех забанили и вам стало не интересно модерировать сайт?

Comment: @mymedia, больше стал редактировать/флагать вопросы непосредственно с сайта.

Comment: Самый неадекватный и нудный чувак на ресурсе. Если его сделать модератором, то он просто задавит своим божественным эго всех остальных. Считает себя гением и богом, любые дебаты пытается завершить провокацией с дальнейшим сливом модераторам. В то время напрашивается вопрос - если ты такой умный. то какого фига у тебя так много бесплатного время, что ты можешь быть ещё и модератором. С такими-то способностями работы вообще нет чтоль..

Comment: И ещё гениальные ответы скорее всего пересказанные хелпы, так как вних напрочь отсутствует человеческий опыт, который так не хватает новичкам. К тому же автор лично мне говорил что для ответов не нужно что-то знать. Видимо это и есть причина рассуждений. которые в некоторых случаях больше причинят вреда, чем пользы. Но как было уже сказано ранее, спорить с богом бесполезно. К тому нудный чувак до безбожества. Нудный, провакатор, бог..

Comment: Но в защиту хочу сказать, что остальные кандидаты ничем не лучше этого. Поэтому кого бы Вы не выбрали, Вы одинаково нанесете вред ресурсу. неумение самостоятельно думать и принимать решения будет ответом на вопрос, почему этот проект проваливается. Доверить людям власть, это хорошо, пока не задумаешься, а кому она нужна. Какой ненормальный хочет тратить свое время на МОДЕРАТОРСТВО? Программист хочет быть востребованным, но не  МОДЕРАТОРОМ. Чтобы найти хорошего модератора, нужно нанимать за хорошие деньги человека желающего зарабатывать модераторством.

Comment: Grundy - это Сталин нашего времени!