# Дебаты между кандидатами на "2017 Выборы модератора"

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, выборы

Может устроить некое подобие дебатов между кандидатами? 
Либо можно устроить трансляцию о них: пусть каждый о себе расскажет(некоторые уже написали о себе), что считает правильным/неправильным. Либо пройдемся по каждому пункту вопросов на выборах.

Comment: Я рассчитываю на то, что они будут дебатировать [в ответах на вопросы сообщества](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6051/181472).

Comment: @NickVolynkin это несколько разные форматы, как мне кажется

Answer (score 5):

С этой целью был создан специальный вопрос: [Выборы модераторов сообщества 2017: ответы кандидатов на вопросы сообщества](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6051/). Подразумевается, что каждый кандидат развернуто напишет основные идеи своей политики относительно волнующих сообщество вопросов. Это и есть основные дебаты. В дополнение, вы (как и сами кандидаты) могут задавать друг другу вопросы как [под постами выдвиженцев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election), так и [в основном чате сообщества](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--)!

Comment: Ну уж чат перед выборами точно большинство избирателей не читает.

Comment: Да и сами выдвиженцы тоже.