# Сбор вопросов застрял в важном

Tags: дефект, мета, заблокированные-вопросы

[Вопрос со сбором вопросов для кандидатов](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5983/178988) получил историческую блокировку и потерял метку [важное](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5), однако, он до сих пор отображается в блоке важного:

> [image: скриншот]

Баг репорт, описывающий такое же поведение, оформлен на главном мета сайте сети: [Post remains featured in the bulletin even if [featured] tag is removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297870/339911). Ответа пока не имеет.

При этом замечено ещё странное поведение результатов поиска по метке. Например, [этот запрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5?tab=Newest) может то содержать, то не содержать в результатах заблокированный вопрос при повторном обновлении страницы.

Comment: Как я вижу, остальные вопросы в блоке тоже без важной метки. Хотя, быть может, просто обновление не прошло.

Comment: @Other, интересное наблюдение.. Я исходил из того, что снятие метки [с вопроса с ответами](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6051/178988) сработало - он не показывается в этой секции. Может и правда просто кэширование...

Comment: Точно, я ж замечал, что он как-то долго из кэша уходит, а потом забыл про это.

Comment: Попробую его перезагрузить. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, у Вас есть кнопочка "обновить важное" рядом с блоком? :)

Comment: @Other нет. Разблокировал, метку добавил и убрал снова. Когда из блока уйдет — снова заблокирую.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ушёл. Правда другой вопрос ([тык](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6051/207618)) не ушёл, хотя 9 часов как уже нет метки.

Comment: @Other, вообще-то он появился - на моём скриншоте его нет же? https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEHwr.png

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, действительно. Но уйти он должен, когда бы не появился :)

Comment: @Other первый заблокировал обратно, второй перезагрузил, ждём )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, вручную задолбаешься перезагружать, надо чинить [tag:bug].

Comment: @Other конечно надо, но это могут сделать только разработчики.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, репорт бага от модератора вполне может привлечь разработчиков.