# Важное опять глючит

Tags: дефект, блок-важных-вопросов

Смотрю на правый блок и вижу там:

[image: Скриншот правого блока]

Открываю [важное](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5) и вижу:

[image: скриншот вопросов по метке]

Что в обоих списках делает [этот вопрос](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9051/178988) при том, что на втором скриншоте он явно без метки?

[image: скриншот вопроса]

Судя по истории метка была снята 2 дня назад:

[image: скриншот истории]

PS: Связанный вопрос: [Сбор вопросов застрял в важном](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6157/178988)

Comment: Баг, проявляющийся раз в 2 года)))

Comment: @Suvitruf, на это раз не только блок, но ещё и список вопросов по метке - а это уж совсем странно.