# Вопрос периодически появляется в блоке "Важное на мете", хотя на вопросе нет метки "важное"

Tags: дефект

На вопросе [Сбор вопросов для будущих кандидатов в модераторы сообщества 2020](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10742), нет метки "важное", но он иногда появляется в блоке "Важное на мете":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну и проблема давно [известна на глобальном уровне](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297870/339911). Недавно там конкурс объявлял для привлечение внимания, но это ожидаемо не возымело эффекта на сотрудников компании :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ bugs, bugs everywhere... Странно, почему то пропадает, то снова появляется. Если бы проблема была в кэше, например, то вопрос бы там постоянно висел. Странный феномен.

Comment: Мне кажется, это как-то связано с количеством текущих вопросов с меткой [meta-tag:важное]. Плюс, там вроде бы ротация какая-то есть. Если их много, то показываются частями. Кстати, оно ещё и в [результаты поиска по метке попадает](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5?tab=Newest). Любопытно.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ возможно еще как-то связано с тем, что вопросы залочены: судя по списку связанных у [этого вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6157), проблемы обычно со всякими сборами вопросов будущим модераторам и вопросов связанных с выборами, которые после завершения события лочатся.

Comment: Да. Блокировка это, как я понимаю, обязательное условие проявление бага.

Comment: Я тоже это вижу и удивляюсь. Но для меня это уже не отъемлемая часть интерьера СО так сказать, я даже привык ;)