# Участник продолжает спамить, как быть?

Tags: обсуждение, троллинг

Вот этот [участник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/346603/%d0%9e%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%9e%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd) — явно троль — уже достал всех в очереди проверок (ну по крайней мере меня).

Он вечно пишет что-то такое ([example](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/493601)):

> Можно купить на аликспресс, только доставки ждать долго придется

Предлагаю его забанить.

Comment: есть примеры? на данный момент его профиль пуст

Comment: @Grundy Я не знаю может это не он. Но купи на экспресс в очереди проверок все время.

Comment: @Grundy example: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/493601

Comment: добавь ссылок на примеры в вопрос. По идее вполне можно флагать как спам, и через какое-то время ему выпишется бан системой

Comment: @Grundy Другие примеры пропали в толще двадцаток (

Comment: Какие очереди проверок? Я все его сообщения 8 дней назад отметил как спам, они тут же были все удалены духом (так работает у модераторов кнопка "спам"), после этого возможность публиковать ответы была заблокирована системой, новых ответов не было (проверил ещё раз). Возможно, речь идёт о том, что это в очередях остались эти проверки как "проверки на внимательность"? А банить... ограничился мод. сообщением на первое нарушение.

Comment: @AK А, да. Просто эта проверка уже сто раз была...

Comment: @AK Можете чего-нибудь там настроить ? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если пользователь постит явный спам ([раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1143933/178988), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1143936/178988) и [три (самый интересный)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1143938/178988)), то надо на соответствующие сообщения ставить тревогу спам. По идее, в таком случае бан сработает автоматически.

Важно ли, кто именно постит спам? Вроде бы и нет, но не совсем. Кажется довольно маловероятным, что высокореповый пользователь вдруг начнёт внезапно размещать спам - можно задуматься о том, не взломан ли аккаунт. И ещё в пограничных случаях доверие к пользователю с единственным ответом, который, к тому же, похож на спам, явно меньше, чем если такое же сообщение запостит человек, уже проявивший себя положительно.

В любом случае, к данной ситуации это вроде не относится.

Comment: Я не могу видеть удаленные сообщения, сделайте скрины?

Comment: И спасибо за ответ написанный без пафоса !

Comment: А то "личность отвечающего", "В данном случае" и т.д...

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, набирай 10K и сможешь. Вот, держи: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cezof.png. Для немодераторов там была бы ссылка для просмотра в истории из-за удаления как спам.

Comment: Пасип, @Qwertiy. А до 10 килограммов репы мне еще сеять и сеять;)

Answer (score 7):

Личность отвечающего/вопрошающего не должна влиять на оценку вопроса/ответа.

В данном случае должны оцениваться сами вопросы/ответы.

Приведенный пример вполне подходит под определение "спам" и может быть отмечен соответствующим флагом.

Если пользователь продолжит оставлять некачественные посты, его действия будут ограничены самой системой.

Comment: А почему не забанить? https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6051/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-2017-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0/6121#6121

Comment: @Зонтик, потому что _Если пользователь продолжит оставлять некачественные посты, его действия будут ограничены самой системой._