# Отмена результатов выборов владельцев чата

Tags: обсуждение, чат, правила, нытьё

Так сложилось, что вчера менеджер сообщества отменил результаты [выборов владельца основного чата ruSO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5496/176217).

> [image: has removed]

Формулировка причины довольно расплывчата:

> В следствии огромного количества тревог в чате, результаты голосования отменены (причина: связано оно с выбранными владельцами или нет, но чат стал не удовлетворять требованиям предъявляемым к содержимому, размещаемому на платформе Stack Exchange). Будущее данной инициативы подлежит дальнейшему обсуждению сообществом.

Довольно странно во всём этом, что решение было принято неожиданно быстро, то есть, как будто принималось не голосом разума, а на эмоциях. Многочисленные просьбы озвучить в чате реальную причину не увенчались успехом. Некоторые сообщения из чата:

> Atomic_alarm:
>   [@NicolasChabanovsky т.е. по причине , возможно, никак не связанной с "владельцами" рума потеряла 2-ух овнеров. Я правильно вас понял?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=42200543#42200543)
>
> Atomic_alarm:
>   [@NicolasChabanovsky какие еще нужны подтверждения если простой вопрос, заданный 4-рьмя разными людьми был проигнорирован?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=42200078#42200078)
>
> alexolut:
>   [@NicolasChabanovsky я не услышал ответа на вопрос, что мог сделать овнер, дабы препятствовать возникшей сегодня ситуации в чате? При выборах речь шла о переносе сообщений в основном, сняли овнера - количество людей, имеющих возможность переноса уменьшилось. Это как-то упрощает решение проблемы сегодняшнего случая? Или я чего-то не понимаю?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=42197356#42197356)
>
> alexolut: [@NicolasChabanovsky Вы лучше скажите, будут санкции на тех, кто флагал всё подряд или нет? Если будут, то на основании каких правил, если нет - то какой вообще смысл в этих разговорах и почему лишили овнерства?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=42195967#42195967)

Давайте попробуем избегать недосказанностей в дальнейшем и объяснять причину своих действий, не прикрываясь общими формулировками о взаимном уважении и необходимости соблюдать политику be-nice. Ведь по сути уважение к сообществу и его выбору было попрано.

> Foggy Finder: [То есть получается когда нужно назначить овнеров мнение сообщества имеет значение, а снимать можно по первому чиху - на моей памяти это уже 2-ое (а может и 3-е) снятие овнерства без обоснованной причины. Если есть мнение, что овнер не справляется с обязанностями возможно есть смысл поднять этот вопрос тоже на мете или условным голосованием в чате?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=42199157#42199157)

Comment: Для меня действия Николаса выглядят тоже как типичное точечное "причинение добра".

Разумеется Николас в своем праве делать то что ему кажется лучше для ru.so, даже если комьюнити бурчит.

Но вот лучше ли? 
Лично мне кажется эти действия просто обидели минимум двух уважаемых участников и не принесли особой пользы.

Comment: Ну то есть мотивировка непонятна. Ну вот зачем наказывать невиновных если они ничего плохого не сделали, и не могли? Это решает проблему хоть как-то? Ладно если к Abyx можно если очень-очень постараться предъявить неполиткорректность и невежливость в общении с иностранными гостями, то alexolut то тут причем?

Comment: Пожалуйста, не играйте со словами. (1) Ответ был. (2) Публикуйте его весь, а не только часть.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky вы про [это сообщение](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=42206881#42206881) в качестве ответа?

Comment: я думаю, что @NicolasChabanovsky имеет ввиду [это](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42200747#42200747) сообщение

Comment: @FoggyFinder это ширма на мой взгляд. Цитирую себя же: *"не прикрываясь общими формулировками о взаимном уважении..."* Флаги ставились на множестве сообщений, чего только стоит [такая ситуация](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=42194531#42194531). Первичны флаги, на них приходят люди из других культур, они не готовы реально обрабатывать наши флаги и даже [сами говорят об этом](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=42194580#42194580). А участники чата ruSO встречно не готовы к массовому появлению иностранцев. Итог: нарушение гипотетического be-nice и то что мы видим.

Comment: так и есть - полностью поддерживаю

Comment: @Kromster если речь, о том, что снятие с поста после полугодовалого интервала нельзя так назвать, то давайте переименуем заголовок во что-то более подходящее. Учитывая бессрочность назначения, я воспринял это именно как отмену результатов, так как мы вернулись к предвыборному состоянию, когда овнерами чата являлись только лишь ромбовидные модераторы. Про причину как раз таки и хочется узнать, но пока что я вижу лишь повод.

Comment: нашел текст с "отменой", добавил его в тело вопроса.

Comment: Ребят, извините что не в тему, но что ещё за "овнер" и "овнерство"? Прям так и напрашивается аналогия из мира жёлтых СМИ: — Ты кто по чату ruSO? — Я Овнер! А ты? — А я обычный Юзверог. Ладно бы там перевода не было адекватного, но блин зачем извращать русский язык в очередной раз? Тем более модераторам (пусть и бывшим) чата StackOverflow **на русском**. // Перенесено из ответа, продолжение в чате: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71654/discussion-on-answer-by-edem-----

Comment: Сочувствую, но что вас держит в несовершенной системе? Уведомления от ботов о строках для локализации? Если система чатов SE сломана и ни у кого нет воли ее починить, почему бы не создать чат в какой-нибудь сторонней системе, где нет такой проблемы.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight не очень понимаю, что Вы подразумеваете под «держит». Существующий чат интегрирован в SO, это многое должно объяснять. Бот не нужен, к тому же он [сломан](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290749/339911), есть другие, более удобные способы узнавать о новых строках, требующих перевода.

Comment: немного [юмора](https://image.prntscr.com/image/XSpTVH_MTWmRK_cDsRluUA.png) )

Comment: Я к тому, нужно ли вам действительно "овнерство" в чате, в котором одни проблемы. Вот даже Localization Bot багнутый, в чем тогда смысл этой интеграции. Если так тяжело, может найти другой путь.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight любая система несовершенна. Но вопрос что вам держит в чатах SE/SO пожалуй даже стоит отдельного рассмотрения.

Answer (score 6):

Постараюсь быть максимально кратким.

Чтобы понять не только следствие, но и проблему, необходимо вернуться в самое начало.

### Проблема *модерации* чата

С переходом на платформу Stack Exchange у сообщества появился чат, которого ранее никогда не было. Причем был создан он вполне конкретным участником — @Athari. Затем чат получил еще двух владельцев: меня (@NicolasChabanovsky) и @Grundy. По большому счету, @Athari и @Grundy длительное время задавали темп.

В прошлом году права на владение общей комнатой были отозваны у @Athari и @Grundy, и сразу были добавлены выбранные сообществом модераторы с основного сайта. У @Grundy права были отозваны за «шуточные» злоупотребления доступных владельцу комнаты полномочий: перемещение чужих сообщений ради шутки  в другие комнаты. У @Athari, на сколько помню — в следствие его крайне активной позиции по тому, что является оскорблениями на платформе Stack Exchange, а что – нет, которая расходится с позицией участников русскоязычного сообщества и компании–разработчика.

Со временем стало ясно, что ни выбранные модераторы, ни управляющий сообщества не используют систему чатов настолько, чтобы выступить «гарантом соблюдения правил» (модератором чата).

<sub>Не скажу за всех, я лично не использую чат, так как являюсь человеком не социальным, общение с людьми мне дается крайне тяжело, особенно, динамическое.</sub>

Таким образом,

> Проблема: сложилась ситуация, в которой основная комната сообщества осталась без модераторов в какой–либо форме.

#### Модерация чата

@Athari и @Grundy долгое время справлялись с модерацией комнаты. Решали они это по–разному: тревогами, их обработкой и переносом неуместных в основном чате сообщений в специализированные комнаты. Возможно у них были и другие средства, но факт в том, что за исключением редких дней, в сообществе было относительно «тихо и спокойно».

#### Почему выборы

Выборами мы хотели найти людей, которые будут поддерживать спокойствие в комнате, то есть, по сути, *модераторов чата*. Именно об этом говорится в [публикации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5496/):

> если вы считаете, что нам следует (не следует) выбирать владельца общего чата, для его *модерирования*.

Крайне хотелось видеть владельцами общего чата сообщества людей: (1) которым доверяют коллеги; (2) которые хотят поддерживать порядок в комнате, выступать гарантом соблюдения прав участников и правил и ценностей сообщества.

#### Правила и ценности сообщества

Все наши ценности и правила отражены на Мете и [справочном центре](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help). Например:

- [Зачем нужен Stack Overflow на русском?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/173/6)
- [Что делать, если вопрос вызывает злость?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-friendly)
- [Будьте дружелюбными](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)
- **[non inclusive language в комментариях и вопросах](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4481/6)**
- [Ответ о «допустимых» на сайте словах](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4020/6).

Этот список можно продолжать долго. Суммируя: мы хотим помогать коллегам, делиться знаниями, учить других и учиться чему–нибудь новому, но никак не ссориться. Мы хотим, чтобы любой разработчик вне зависимости от пола, возраста цвета кожи, национальности, вероисповедания, достатка и прочих несущественных различий мог быть частью русскоязычного сообщества разработчиков, чтобы ему или ей было комфортно сосуществовать с остальными. Наш главный критерий — неудержимое стремление к знаниям, к программированию.

### Отзыв права владения общим чатом

> Думаю, не многие будут оспаривать факт, что вопрос взаимного уважения за последние несколько месяцев поднимался в чате ни один раз. И он получал такой резонанс, что выливался, не только за пределы данного чата в другие, но и на MSE. Это не означает, что это как–либо связано с личностными качествами выбранных сообществом участниками, имея в виду их личные предпочтения, но определенно это явный недосмотр команды модераторов чата. Замечу, команда модераторов сайта не имеет отношения к модерации чата. Именно по этому и было голосование.

**Поясню проблему чуть более развернуто.**

Выбранные сообществом владельцы общей комнаты, ее *модераторы*, «модерируют»/«не модерируют» чат крайне асимметрично, с уклоном в сторону не соответствующую ценностями сообщества. Это выражается в:

- Разжигание вражды и постоянные оскорбления. Ребята заняли вполне четкую позицию — то, что не обидно им, не обидно никому. Это вылилось как в оскорбление с их стороны по отношению к другим, так и в «отсутствие проблем» с тем, что участники оскорбляли друг друга. Подчеркну, данная позиция расходится с ценностями сообщества. Наша позиция — добродетель. Мы здесь не для шуток друг над другом, а, наоборот, для того, чтобы преодолевать технические (а иногда и жизненные) проблемы вместе, сообща, помогая и поддерживая друг друга.
- Инициировали «бунт тревог». Именно с подачи и с постоянной поддержкой выбранных владельцев начали сыпаться «шуточные» тревоги. Тревоги на все сообщения подряд. (А когда к нам приходили ребята из других не русскоязычных сообществ для обработки тревог, в их адрес ни раз сыпались беспричинные оскорбления и выпады). Ситуация была доведена до абсурда: если посмотреть статистику тревог по всей сети Stack Exchange, наш чат выделяется очень сильно. Коллеги, в нашем чате от 5 до 15 участников. Как так? Это не модерация, а дестабилизация!
- Использование инструментов владельца комнаты не по назначению. Подчеркну, сообщество выбирало людей, которые бы смогли выступить гарантом базовых ценностей сообщества и прав участников, но никак не «тиранами». Проблема проявилась в очень неоднозначном требовании отчитываться кому что не нравится в чате перед *владельцам чата лично (!)*, вместо использования тревог! Выбранные владельцы комнаты еще и закрепили это *требование* в боковой панели чата. Нонсенс! В мгновение ока все участники чата были лишены базовых прав: возможность отметить оскорблением то, что *по мнению участников является оскорблением*, то что *им* неприятно, чего бы *они лично* не хотели бы видеть, сделать это *приватно*. Вкупе с тем, что владельцы публично установили риторику «надо меньше обижаться» (то есть они практически ни в чем оскорблений не видят), выглядело очень обидно и больно за ребят, в чью сторону начались повторяющиеся открытые выпады.

  Возникает вопрос: кто наделил владельцев комнаты судебной властью? Кто назначил их последней инстанцией в принятии решений о том, что хорошо, что плохо? Сообщество лишь попросило удалять/переносить из комнаты нетематическое содержимое, а не устанавливать диктатуру. Не говоря о том, что выбранная риторика идет в разрез с ценностями сообщества!
- Минутка статистики. Всего за последние 90 дней в нашем чате 63 сообщения были отмечены тревогой, из них 19 отмеченных сообщений принадлежат выбранным владельцам! Владельцы приняли участие в обработке или выставлению тревог 24 раза (то есть либо сами отмечали тревогой, либо проверяли тревогу, оставленную другим участником), в том числе 8 раз в проверке или выставлению тревог на своих сообщениях (своем или другого выбранного модератора). За последние 12 месяцев (30*12 дней) всего было отмечено 99 сообщений, аз последние 6 месяцев (30*6 дней) — 71 сообщение. Таким образом, соотношение 28 к 71: в чате стало почти в три раза больше шума в последние полгода, чем в полгода до (напомню, выборы закончились примерно 7 месяцев назад).

По сумме вышеописанного, считаю, что нам, сообществу, и не только нам, будет лучше вернуться к более спокойному состоянию. 
[Хочу подчеркнуть](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5987/6):

[image].

Модерирование сообществ — дело крайне непростое и неоднозначное, с ним справится не каждый. То, что вы хороший разработчик, никак не поможет вам в этом деле, а вот навредит — наверняка.

---

Мне крайне неприятно писать все это и рассматривать конкретных людей. Спешу предложить вам обезличить вопрос, удалив все упоминания о конкретных участниках (выбранных владельцах) и переписать *вопрос и ответ* в формате «Что не следует делать владельцам комнаты», согласно [рекомендациям](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4790/6). Или удалить его вовсе.

Comment: 1) В данном сообщении содержится передергивание фактов (пруфов не будет, но и в ответе их тоже нет)

Comment: 2) А что поменяется-то?

Comment: @Abyx Подскажите, пожалуйста, подтверждение каких именно фактов требуется? Что именно изменится — покажет время, но сам факт необходимости изменений виден невооруженным взглядом.

Comment: А есть какое-то обоснование к таким пунктам ("разжигание вражды", "использование инструментов владельца комнаты не по назначению").

Comment: "владельцы" чата - это какая-то неделимая сущность получается? Может надо объединить наши с @Abyx учетные записи тогда?

Comment: @GreenDragon Подскажите, чем вас текст в пунктах не устраивает и как бы вы их обосновали?

Comment: Изменения нужны, но суть вопроса в том - мог(может) ли овнер румы повлиять на сложившуюся проблему и если да - то как?

Comment: Я бы обосновал ссылками, т.к. совершенно непонятно что вы под этим понимаете (например, я вообще не знаю какие инструменты есть у владельцев рум и как можно было разжигать вражду не набрав кучу флагов на сообщение).

Comment: у @Athari были отобраны за компанию :-) когда решили выбирать владельцев

Comment: Для того, чтобы поддерживать порядок в комнате -- нужно не только налепить шерифский значок, но и выдать кольт. Я хочу спросить: перед тем, как обвинять "они обязаны были обеспечить порядок в чате" -- им были выданы соответствующие инструменты или компания-разработчик не будет ничего делать для исправления ситуации? Мне кажется, что это ситуация как в анекдоте "мы им выдали жезлы -- а дальше пусть крутятся как могут". Простите, когда забанили рум овнера -- это было не смешно. Год только при мне просим баги чата поправить, чат не локализован. Как в этой ситуации набирать новых модераторов?

Comment: Насчёт имён конкретных участников - если Вы посмотрите историю ревизий вопроса, то увидите, что я старался по максимуму их убирать. Они были добавлены позднее другим участником.

Comment: @GreenDragon Может ли? — Да, особенно когда владелец причастен к причине. Любая и каждая проблема имеет очень много разных подходов и решений. Какой–то подход сложно заметить, какой–то очевиден, и о результатах мы можем только догадываться. Ясно одно: тот кто не видит проблемы, никогда и не найдет решения. Если бы владельцы видели проблему в выше описанном, мы бы имели факт ее обсуждения где–либо (о справедливости этого видно и по этому вопросу, и по вопросу «сломанной системы тревог»).

Comment: @AK Опять же, проблему решать можно множеством путей. Например, (1) тем же переносом сообщений, (2) постоянным диалогом с явно выделяющемися нарушителями спокойствия, (3) диалогом с модераторами и со мной о блокировке доступа конкретным провокаторам. Кто видит проблему и хочет ее устранить, всегда найдет множество решений. Более того, указанный вами вопрос не был поднят во время обсуждения инициативы, а говорится постфактум, оправдывая все описанное выше. Мы выбирали модераторов, которое если бы модерировали, столкнулись бы с проблемой крайне быстро, а не после отзыва прав.

Comment: @GreenDragon По использованию возможностей не по назначению, вопрос очень даже конкретно расписан. Подскажите, или вы хотите ссылку на сам «призыв» в чате увидеть? Что касается разжигания вражды — примеров достаточно (пожалуйста, поищите и по звездам и просто по словам в чате, найдете все, что пожелаете), например, [вчера был инцидент](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42193151#42193151).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, я не самый активный чатланин и о том, что вы называете "призывом" узнал только теперь. Но если я правильно его понял - то этот призыв и был попыткой владельцев решить проблему, которая очевидно исходит не от пишущих участников, а от читающих. И призыв это ведь только просьба,рекомендация, что никак и никого ограничить не смогло.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky то есть количество флагов вы считаете критерием успешности модерации чата? Напоминает *эффективных* менеджеров...

Comment: @PavelMayorov Пожалуйста, не путайте частное и общее. Критериев много: шум в комнате, уважение модераторов к участниками и тд. В свою очередь, если в чате все время публикуется оскорбления, то это сигнализирует о явной проблеме.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky это вы путаете. То что в чате флаги - не означает что в чате оскорбления.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Так я вроде и не писал нигде, что тревоги эквивалентны оскорблениям.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky так оскорблений-то не было...

Comment: @PavelMayorov Подскажите, пожалуйста, что вы имеете в виду? Где именно их не было, в чате в течении последнего полугода?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky да, в чате их не было. За полгода не поручусь - но проблема оскорблений в чате явно надумана.

Comment: Это какое-то издевательство, пинговать в чате забаненного. // сс @AK

Comment: @alexolut Откуда я должен был узнать о том, что вы забанены в чате? В первый раз об этом слышу.

Comment: @AK ну, претензия как бы не к Вам, потому и в копии. В профиле чата должно быть видно, наверное. По-крайней мере, мне видно. Ну и в [снесённой теме](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6746/176217) это озвучивалось. Надо 10к набирать срочно!

Answer (score 6):

[Чем room owner отличается от обычного юзера?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271269/152799)

- RO может менять название комнаты, пинить звездочки, настраивать RSS и добавлять события
- RO может запретить обычным юзерам писать в комнате (timeout, не заморозка)
- RO может временно забанить пользователя в этой комнате (kick+mute)
- RO может перемещать сообщения в другую комнату
- RO может читать удаленные сообщения

(Что может делать модератор - написано [здесь](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271270/152799))

#### Как работают флаги?

Флаг (flag as spam/offensive) показывается активным (не AFK) пользователям с 10к репутации по всем чатам SE, и модераторам. Пользователи голосуют за флаг, модераторы утверждают или отменяют флаг в обход голосования, при этом модераторы видят кто нажал флаг.

[Мета SE рекомендует следующее](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271268/152799):

> Remember: Only flag things that are truly inappropriate or offensive.
>
> When you flag a message, you draw the attention of every mod and 10 k user currently on the chat network. This means you should only be flagging things that they’re going to see as offensive as well, which includes:
>
> - Personal attacks (characterized by you, e.g., “You’re a moron.”)
> - Anything that shocks the conscience (yes, this is subjective — let your conscience be your guide.)

Тут надо отметить что флаги с русским текстом попадают на голосование случайным пользователям, и т.к. иностранных пользователей больше, то с большой вероятностью не-русскоязычный пользователь не поймет что было написано в спорном сообщении.

По моему опыту общения в англоязычных чатах SO и SE, флаги раздражают пользователей у которых выскакивает голосовалка. И мне кажется что в чатах есть некоторый консенсус что флаги лучше не использовать если можно обойтись без них, это также подтверждается цитатой с Meta SE выше.

Руководствуясь этим (10к юзеры не рады флагам вообще и не понимают по русски), я закрепил в комнате сообщение (15 ноября 2017)

> [Пожалуйста, не используйте флаги (⚑), пингуйте @alexolut или @abyx или модераторов.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=41164952#41164952)

Это видимо то "Использование инструментов владельца комнаты не по назначению." о котором упоминает Николас в своем ответе:

> Проблема проявилась в очень неоднозначном требовании отчитываться кому что не нравится в чате перед владельцам чата лично (!), вместо использования тревог! Выбранные владельцы комнаты еще и закрепили это требование в боковой панели чата. Нонсенс!

Далее я в одном из сообщений упомянул the N word, это сообщение флагнули и я получил бан чата.
Мне это не понравилось. (До этого флагом забанили @alexolut, но мне было всё равно, а тут пришли за мной)

**И тут всё завертелось.**

Николас сказал что флаги это хорошо.

Я пошел в главный чат SE спросить их мнение, но там я увидел **это**:

[image]

И тут я всё понял. Я был не прав.
Если чат говорит "используй флаги",
если другие используют против меня флаги,
то зачем я борюсь с флагами?!

И так я начал использовать флаги. И заодно апрувить чужие флаги, потому что могу.

---

Прошло несколько месяцев, наступил январь.

Кто-то (нет, не я) флагнул "к-слово" (что-то про кошек), и в чат прибежал коллега @LINQ, с pt.SO.

Он начал это своё

> [Can you please stop flagging?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42193013#42193013)
> It's annoying

Ха! Он видимо читал тот пост с меты SE выше. Но я-то уже знал что тот пост - чушь. Так что я написал

> @LINQ make a feature-request on SE meta, ask'em to disable the flags

И тут он ответил

> @Abyx Nice to see that you're a room owner that can't treat others with respect

Ради лулзов я запинил это сообщение.

Потом была шутка про испанцев, индейцев и Колумба (который кажется не был испанцем, а LINQ вообще из Бразилии).

Флаги (нет, не мои) сыпались рекой, я их апрувил, но никого так и не забанили. Флаги на своих сообщениях я тоже апрувил, но и это не помогло.

Потом в комнату зашел какой-то иностранный модератор и я написал

> [фриза ждем](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42194582#42194582)

Тут @Nofate, который всё это время был в комнате и видел флагующих внезапно вспомнил что он тоже модератор и заморозил комнату.

> [Nofate has frozen this room.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42194591#42194591)

Затем он написал "Судя по всему, в замороженой комнате флагать нельзя", я нажал на флаг - оказалось что можно `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`.

Затем Николас лишил меня и alexolut овнерства.
А Nofate всё еще модер т.к. Николас считает что модеры не должны модерировать чат.
Хотя [пост на мете SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271270/152799) считает иначе, впрочем мы уже выяснили что это неправильный пост.

---

Очевидно что в этом чате я овнером больше не буду.
Но.
Посмотрите на список привилегий RO в начале поста - там самое полезное это "смотреть удаленные сообщения".
Фиды RSS настроили предыдущие овнеры (спасибо им за это),
timeout я не разу не юзал т.к. не было ситуации когда *все* делали что-то плохое,
kick/mute я не разу не юзал (знал бы кто флагал - применил бы, но я не модер),
перенос сообщений - только по просьбе перенести в другой чат, либо вместо флагов для "удаления" сообщений.

Так что, *look at all the  I give*, как говорят наши зарубежные коллеги.

---

Станет ли что-то лучше? Нет конечно, с чего бы.
Что можно сделать с флагающими? Ничего. "Feel uneasy - flag it", как говорит нам справка к чату.

Comment: _считает что модеры не должны модерировать чат._ — Модератор — позиция добровольная, волонтерская. Не не должны, а не хотя (это эмпирическое утверждение). На сколько помню, именно дискуссия между модераторами привела к необходимости выборов владельцев чата, что вполне логично: мы все разные, у всех свой набор сильных и слабых сторон. Если никто в команде модераторов не чувствует в себе достаточно уверенности в способности быть модератором чата, почему бы не пригласить того, кому это будет легко даваться?

Comment: Мне кажется, ваше видение добавляет свет, но не противоречит описанным проблемам.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky все позиции в ruSO добровольные и волонтёрские, кроме одной. Только вот получилось так, что подписывались на одно, а наказаны за другое. Это, я считаю, несправедливо.

Comment: @alexolut Пользуясь терминами AK, модератор — шериф, который следит за порядком, в том числе, чтобы никого из жителей его штата не ущемляли в правах. У нас сложилась ситуация, когда команда выбранных владельцев комнаты (модераторов чата) в одностороннем порядке пересмотрела часть правил сообщества. Например, что есть суть оскорбление. Мы вместе несколько лет шли к тому, чтобы создать систему правил, в рамках которых пусть еще не все, но многие могут сосуществовать без трения, а выходит, что в чате «надо меньше обижаться».

Comment: Функция модерирования не выполняется, так еще и на правах владельцев, без обсуждения, вносятся правила, идущие в разрез с идеологией сообщества. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что в отзыве несправедливого?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky зачем снова требовать того, на что избранные оунеры не подписывались? Вы же вроде как [признали эту ошибку](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=42202143#42202143). Или теперь уже расширили задачу "переносить сообщения" и на детект оскорблений? Я, например, могу выявить ситуацию, когда в чате начинают активно обсуждать задачу по C# и перенести дискуссию в тематический .Net чат. Но, пардон, для всяких оскорблений есть флаги и утверждаются они по мажоритарной схеме, каких-либо расширенных прав для их обработки не требуется. Причём тут вообще оунеры?

Comment: @alexolut Ошибка ошибкой, но я привел конкретную выдержку из сообщения о выборах: «...выбирать владельца общего чата, для его модерирования.». Оскорбления для меня крайне близки к политической теме. Но это лирика, суть вот в чем «Ребята заняли вполне четкую позицию — то, что не обидно им, не обидно никому. Это вылилось как в оскорбление с их стороны по отношению к другим, так и в «отсутствие проблем» с тем, что участники оскорбляли друг друга.»  Такого ранее не было (как минимум, если бы я об этом знал, я бы явно обозначил это комментарием к вашей кандидатуре).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, Всё было тихо и спокойно до ноября 2017. Участники иногда матерились, я эти сообщения переносил в урну и вежливо просил так не делать. Кмк это и есть модерация. Иногда были флаги, приходили коллеги с других чатов и говорили что им это мешает - я как мог просил не использовать флаги. Нормально же всё было. Ну а теперь всё. Зачем разговаривать с людьми если можно просто нажать флаг. ----- Но это лирика. А суть вот в чем: чем мой моральный стандарт хуже Вашего? Откуда Вы знаете что Ваши сообщения никого не оскорбляют?

Comment: @Abyx Текущая проблема — проблема последних трех месяцев (может чуть меньше), верно. Никто не говорит, что что–то хуже или лучше. Проблема в том, что вы не видите оскорбления там, где оно есть, открыто это поддерживаете, а на объяснение, почему данный факт обижает других, отмахиваетесь. Обратите внимание, [я пытался вам это показать](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=41293675#41293675), обратите внимание к чему это был ответ.

Comment: Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что если рассмотреть каждую из указанных проблем отдельно, посмотреть на вашу неоценимую помощь коллегам на основном сайте, прошлые положительные достижения в чате, то я бы вероятно, сказал, что решение может казаться не очевидным. Но если посмотреть на происходящее в сообществе в сумме по итогам последних трех месяцев, рассмотреть все за и против, посмотреть на ваши действия относительно существующих проблем в чате, то решение уже вполне очевидное.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky , это не "решение". Проблема осталась.

Comment: Я приводил аналогию с шерифом и выданными ему инструментами, приведу ещё одну: рыба гниёт с головы. Если в самом stackoverflow на управленческих этажах (Николас и выше) нет единодушного понимания, нужны флаги или не нужны и каждый трактует как хочет – то вот давайте не будем валить на простых модераторов чата, что они виноваты в том, что не справились. Трактуй так, трактуй эдак – всегда можно будет найти ссылку, о том, что нужно использовать флаги, не нужно использовать флаги. У меня есть конструктивное предложение: давайте эскалируем вопрос на уровень руководства so, пусть дадут чёткий ответ.

Comment: @AK Подскажите, пожалуйста, вопрос о чем? Нужна ли система тревог в текущей форме?

Comment: @Abyx у меня возникло впечатление, что вы считаете, что вас и alexolut убрали из RO за  какое-то "несогласие с системой флагов". Это не так, вам про это Николас написал выше. Несколько раз. Вся эта **чехарда с флагами не имеет никакого отношения к снятию**. Вам же прямо сказали - проблема в том, что ваше и alexolut отношение к тревогам (в виде флагов/просто жалоб) весьма странное для владельцев комнаты. "Не оскорбляет меня - значит, не оскорбляет никого" - плохой подход к модерированию.

Comment: @AK - снятием не пытались решить проблему флагов (в любом виде). Решали проблему "текущая политика модерирования поощряет оскорбления". Насчет того же колумба - ситуация, владелец комнаты (по сути, локальный модератор) начинает шутить потенциально оскорбительные/расисткие шутки, прикрываясь "это комната на русском, проходите мимо" - это ненормально. "я всего-лишь послал его на мету, не объяснив суть проблемы, а потом *всего лишь* начал шутить шутки про Колубма и индейцев" - это умышленное грубое оскорбление конкретного участника. Точно непонятно, за что сняли, стоит еще прямее написать?

Comment: @AK , это всего лишь одна из сотен чат-комнат SE. Ничто не мешает нам создать новую чат-комнату, со своими овнерами и своим трактованием Be Nice. То что мы проводили выборы овнеров чат-комнаты - это само по себе что-то странное - какой-то микроменеджмент. Это как если бы министр образования назначал бы старост классов.

Comment: @PashaPash это неправильное впечатление, и я не понимаю откуда оно у Вас. Флагфест только привлек внимание Nicolas к чату. Nicolas увидел нарушение своего видения Be Nice, и убрал нас из овнеров т.к. мы не поступаем так как поступил бы он.

Comment: @Abyx Пожалуйста, не сводите это все к одной персоне и к одному событию. Оскорбления видны далеко не только мне: я обсуждал ситуацию с коллегами, они согласны, что выбранная и реализованная риторика противоречит правилам. Более того, я крайне развернуто пояснил все предпосылки к решению.

Answer (score 5):

Некрасивая ситуация вышла. Было несколько уважаемых членов сообщества, законно выбранных, которые добровольно по мере сил тянули общественную нагрузку. Мне аналогия пришла на ум: публично спороли погоны перед воинским строем. А что, нет разве? "Отмена результатов выборов" – это значит, что на выборах мухлевали так много (боты там, подтасовка), что нужно аннулировать результаты. Простите: с момента выборов прошло более полугода, о чём речь?

Другое дело – если бы обсудили бы и сказали "блин, починить флаги нам не могут или не хотят, так что вся эта идея была изначально неудачной".

Модераторов – на заслуженную пенсию, "спасибо, ребята, родина вас не забудет", дальше – обсуждение с сообществом, что делать дальше.

В общем, не нравится мне ситуация.

Я бы хотел из уважения к заслугам участников уточнить формулировку.

Вижу два момента:

1. Ставится ли под сомнение честность и легитимность прошедших выборов модераторов чата? Мне показалось, что речь скорее о том, что система модерирования нуждается в некоторой переделке: возможно связанной с какими-техническими решениями (что-то допилить в движке) или связанной с новыми правилами сообщества.
2. Ставится ли под сомнение качество выполнения модераторами возложенных обязанностей? Я не хочу, чтобы кому-то потом пеняли "ты не тянул": если никакой вины нет – надо это публично и чётко озвучить. Если есть какие-то замечания, то это видимо нужно делать а) индивидуально, потому что речи о коллективной ответственности не шло и б) не припоминать прошлогодний снег и все грехи до пятого колена.

Спасибо за внимание.

Update после прочтения поста Abyx.

Я приводил аналогию с шерифом и выданными ему инструментами, приведу ещё одну: рыба гниёт с головы.

Если в самом stackoverflow на управленческих этажах (Николас и выше) нет единодушного понимания, нужны флаги или не нужны и каждый трактует как хочет – то вот давайте не будем валить на простых модераторов чата, что они виноваты в том, что не справились.

Трактуй так, трактуй эдак – всегда можно будет найти ссылку, о том, что нужно использовать флаги, не нужно использовать флаги.

У меня есть конструктивное предложение: давайте эскалируем вопрос на уровень руководства so, пусть дадут чёткий и однозначный ответ по поводу флагов. И будет весьма хорошо, если это решение будет такое, к нам перестанут  приходить случайные англоязычные пользователи, которые будут раздражаться принятым наверху решением и наугад голосовать по тревогам. Наверняка помимо технических способов (поменять код движка), которые наверху не хотят реализовывать есть и другие способы, чисто организационные.

Просто обвинить текущий состав модераторов – это неконструктив. Во-первых, мы обвиняем конкретных неплохих людей, вызывая у них негатив. И обвиняем в том, что находится вне их возможностей. Во-вторых, мы забываем поднять проблему на вышестоящий этаж... Можно бесконечно тасовать и выбирать модераторов – но если наверху будут двойные стандарты по поводу флагов – будет только больше негатива.

Comment: Чуть в сторону - "законность выборов" модераторов чата - очень сомнительна. Например, я, регулярно посещавший SO во время этих "выборов", полностью их пропустил, и узнал и них уже по факту. Хоть выбиралка и висела в "важном" :)

Comment: @PashaPash я Вам больше скажу, далеко не каждый голосовал при выборах ромбоносных модераторов!

Comment: @alexolut да, но за ромбов голосовало гораздо больше людей. а тут - из 600+ посетителей - всего 30 голосов

Comment: @alexolut на выборах ромбов, к примеру, проголосовало 788 из 1,575 посетивших страницу (и из 1,949 потенциальных избирателей, посетивших сайт)

Comment: @PashaPash 600+ это просмотры которые? Они не уникальны кстати. Ну и Вы ещё учтите соотношение людей, сидящих на сайте и в чате.

Comment: @alexolut, почему просмотров? Знак даётся именно за голос.

Comment: @Qwertiy еще и знак за выборы владельца чата дают? Ну вапсще!

Comment: @alexolut, ой.. неправильно понял.

Comment: @Kromster тоже [высказался в комментариях](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6713/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0?noredirect=1#comment26338_6713) по поводу названия. Давайте переименуем, если это позволит более правильно отразить возникшую ситуацию.

Comment: @Qwertiy кстати, нет желания довесить метку [meta-tag:важное]?

Comment: @alexolut, ну мне не жалко поставить (поставил), но у нас сейчас и так больше 4 вопросов с ней, так что в блоке ты его вряд ли увидишь.