# Имеет ли значение, какой номер голоса отдан кандидату на выборах?

Tags: обсуждение, выборы

"1-ый голос", "2-ой голос" и "3-ий голос". Есть ли разница, кому из кандидатов какой голос отдан?

Речь идет про приоритет. Например, если участнику А я отдал свой первый голос, участнику Б - второй, а участнику В - третий, то участник А получает 10 "попугаев", участник Б - 5 "попугаев", а В - одного "попугая", а эти "попугаи" потом используются для подсчета количества голосов.

Или же "стоимость" голосов одинакова и у меня просто есть 3 места, на которые я могу определить какого-то кандидата?

Comment: Вкратце: вес первого голоса больше, чем второго. "В начале голосования каждому кандидату начисляются голоса от тех, кто выбрал его в качестве ***первого*** номера." Остальное -- см. в [этом вопросе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1999/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2).

Comment: @AK соответственно, и второго, больше чем третьего. Я понял, спасибо вам.

Comment: Участник А получает всех ваших попугаев. Если у него уже слишком много попугаев, часть попугаев переходит к Б. Если у него совсем мало попугаев — то он вылетает и все попугаи переходят к Б.

Comment: @NickVolynkin я понял. Значит "1-ый голос" является решающим, а остальные 2 как бы резервные. Думаю, как-то так их назвать и было бы логичнее. А то эти "1, 2, 3" сбивают с толку, да еще и ставят все голоса в один ряд. А тут оно вон что.

Comment: @smellyshovel решающими являются все голоса. просто это голосование по принципу "хочу видеть в модераторах А. если А не пройдет, или за него проглосовало и так слишком много - то Б. Если Б не пройдет, или за него проглосовало и так слишком много - то хотя бы С".

Comment: @PashaPash кстати, можно выбрать только 2 и 3. Без первого. Я так понимаю, в этом случае они будут восприняты как 1 и 2 соответственно. То есть важен не абсолютный номер, а относительный.