# Результаты выборов в модераторы 2017

Tags: обсуждение, выборы, вехи

[Выборы  в модераторы сообщества Stack Overflow на русском за 2017 год](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/2) завершились, все голоса отданы! На основе выбора, сделанного сообществом, модераторами стали:

[image: ЮрийСПб] [image: Qwertiy]

Эти участники в самое ближайшее время будут назначены как [выбранные сообществом модераторы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators). Пожалуйста, поблагодарите их за желание помочь сообществу в развитии! В будущем, не стесняйтесь поддерживать их советами и отзывами о их деятельности.

Спешу выразить огромную благодарность всем кандидатам на позицию модератора сообщества, а также всем, кто принял участие в голосовании! Уверен, мы сделали отличный выбор!

Для получения более подробной информации о результатах выборов вы можете загрузить данные по [ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/2) или [посмотреть отчет онлайн](https://www.opavote.com/results/6345242919829504).

Comment: Мои поздравления новым модераторам!

Answer (score 23):

Для желающих, [отчёт о процессе подсчёта результатов](https://www.opavote.com/results/6345242919829504) в формате пораундовой анимации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кажется, кто-то вошел во вкус :)

Comment: @Drakonoved приложил ссылочку на исходный материал, там всё расписано в деталях.