# Итоги выборов модераторов 2019

Tags: обсуждение, выборы, вехи

[Выборы  в модераторы сообщества Stack Overflow на русском за 2019 год завершились!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/3) От лица сообщества хочу выразить огромную благодарность всем участникам, которые  выдвинули свою кандидатуру на должность модератора сообщества, а также всем тем, кто принял участие в голосовании!

На основе выбора, сделанного сообществом, новыми модераторами стали:

[image: Suvitruf] [image: A K]

<sub>Для получения более подробной информации об итогах выборов вы можете загрузить данные по [ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/3) или [посмотреть отчет онлайн](https://www.opavote.com/results/4969828467081216/0).</sub>

Новые модераторы в самое ближайшее время получат заслуженный [«ромб»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators). А пока, давайте вместе поблагодарим ребят за желание помочь сообществу в развитии!

Comment: А может, как когда-то на ptSO, добавим ещё одну позицию? А то между вторым и третьим местом в третьем раунде разрыв 0.6%.

Comment: Поздравляем...!

Comment: Присоединяюсь к поздравлению !)

Comment: Достойные быть админами

Comment: Если бы два человека (бюллетени №№ 629 и 630) проголосовали за кандидатов в другом порядке, то результат выборов был бы иным. Это к тому насколько мал разрыв между кандидатами.

Comment: Мда, четко определившаяся тройка... Хочу поддержать предложение @Qwertiy.

Comment: @Qwertiy А сможете создать вопрос-предложение, желательно с меткой [tag:важное]?

Comment: Поздравляю ребята!

Answer (score 20):

Аналогично [выборам 2017 года](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6229/213987) собрал анимацию о процессе подсчёта результатов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теоретические пояснения по работе алгоритма есть в [этой теме](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1999/213987), там же и анимация для первых выборов (2015 г).

Answer (score 20):

Поздравляю [Suvitruf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/15479/suvitruf) и [A K](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/213987/a-k) с победой на выборах и вступлением в ряды модераторов "Stack Overflow на русском". Вы являетесь достойными этого звания участниками сайта, и это наша общая победа, т.к. мои голоса в том числе были отданы и за вас.  Надеюсь, с вашим участием в [списке настоящих модераторов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) жизнь на сайте станет ещё интереснее, а количество выданных банов сократится  по причине разруливания возможных проблемных ситуаций путём диалога! И участники с большим вкладом не будут покидать сайт в расстроенных чувствах.

Теперь мне хотелось бы высказать огромную признательность всем тем людям,  которые поддержали меня в этой борьбе за  должность модератора. Ещё ни разу за всю историю ruSO не было такого разрыва по голосам между теми, кто преодолел планку и нет. Это, имхо, хороший показатель для первого раза. Не стоит забывать, что выбранные недавно кандидаты попали в список модераторов не сразу, сначала им пришлось  потерпеть неудачу на [предыдущих выборах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/2). Так что я верю, что ещё не всё потеряно и оказанная мне поддержка не пропадёт даром. Спасибо вам!

Дополнительно хочу поблагодарить [Qwertiy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy) и [Vadim Ovchinnikov](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/220571/vadim-ovchinnikov) за предложение  увеличить количество доступных позиций и публикацию вопросов для разбора подобной ситуации:

- [When can candidates be called up after the election?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329113/339911)
- [Numero de vagas e moderadores eleitos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7826/60587)

Мне было очень приятно ощущать вашу поддержку!

Comment: Ещё не всех   (¬‿¬ )

Comment: @Suvitruf типа "настоящей тирании вы ещё не видали - stay tuned"?

Comment: Поживём - увидим)