# Голоса 1 2 3 чем-то различаются?

Tags: обсуждение, выборы

На выборах можно отдать три голоса: 1-й, 2-й, 3-й. Они равнозначний или какой-то из них наибольший, какой-то наименьший?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77560/260198 там всё не так просто)

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik thx ;)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как устроено голосование на выборах модераторов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1999/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: Прошу переоткрыть этот вопрос, поскольку ответ на него довольно простой и не требует знания алгоритма MeekSTV.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Готово.

Comment: @AK закрывать назад ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Голоса неравнозначны. 1й голос - самый главный, именно он учитывается в первую очередь.

2й и 3й голоса - "запасные". Если тот кандидат, за которого вы проголосовали первым, по какой-то причине вылетит (а при подсчёте голосов будут по-очереди вылетать кандидаты с наименьшим их числом) - ваш голос автоматически перейдёт второму кандидату. И аналогично с третьим.

Comment: Тогда при выборе N модераторов логично было бы иметь по N голосов каждого типа. Однако, этого нет. Хотя мы выбирали 2-х модераторов, у нас было только по одному голосу каждого ранга  (или я ошибаюсь?)

Comment: @avp ну а это уже пошли детали алгоритма. Вкратце: нет, не логично, не очень понятно как такие "двойные" голоса считать.

Comment: А есть референс откуда инфа?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ из описания алгоритма MeekSTV. Ну и плюс это довольно распространённый подход, скажем поступление в ВУЗы идёт по тому же самому принципу.

Comment: @PavelMayorov премного благодарен почитаю