# Как устроено голосование на выборах модераторов 2023?

Tags: поддержка, выборы

Устаревший вопрос: [Как устроено голосование на выборах модераторов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1999/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2)

Думаю стоит написать новый ответ т.к. сейчас голосование приходит другим образом

Ну или можно написать новый ответ на старый вопрос, но мне кажется, лучше ответить на новый вопрос т.к. так будет удобнее увидеть ответ не пролистывая до второго ответа ну или мы обязуемся заплюсовать новый ответ на старый вопрос, чтобы он был первым :)

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145393/discussion-on-question-by-eziomercer------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer) или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что лучше будет поступить так:

1. Сделать ответ на старый вопрос общим (это может сделать модератор).
2. Поправить старый ответ. По сути, устарела там **только третья часть ответа** (про третью стадию выборов) и частично раздел "Результаты и другая информация".