# Какие предусмотрены пути опротестования решения администрации?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, блокировка

Уважаемые коллеги, меня волнует следующий вопрос.

Насколько я понимаю, решение о санкциях по отношению к конкретным участникам принимаются келейно группой из администрации и модераторов. Поскольку все эти люди вполне могут ошибаться, то не исключено, что решение о блокировке или других санкциях — ошибочное.

Какой предусмотрен механизм апелляции и опротестования такого решения?

Насколько я понимаю, посты на Мете, в которых участник выносит проблему на суд сообщества, администрацией *не приветствуются*. Каким же образом можно обойти несправедливое решение? Предположение о том, что администрация никогда не ошибается, я отвергаю как фантастическое.

---

Непосредственный повод для вопроса — годичная блокировка @FoggyFinder за нарушение, цитирую, «правила дружелюбия пассивной агрессией множество раз в чатах и на Мете».

---

---

Поскольку на вопрос даны ответы, позволю себе выделить короткое резюме принятого ответа.
Пути опротестовать совместное решение модераторов и КМ **нет никакого**. Жалобы на неверное решение попадают назад к тем, кто принял это решение. Смиритесь, вы ничего не сможете добиться.

Comment: Ого, FoggyFinder наоборот всегда казался крайне дружелюбным пользователем.

Comment: @yolosora знаю FF по f# чату, тоже удивлён. Но кагбэ нам ещё скоро и не удивляться, что VladD оказывается тоже агент вражеской разведки и всегда мутил воду.

Comment: Администрацией, насколько я знаю, не приветствуется вынос решения на мету без предварительной попытки оспорить его через личные сообщения. Администрация и модераторы - тоже люди, и они иногда ошибаются. Но ошибку всегда стоит сначала обсудить с тем, кто ее допустил. Прямой вынос на мету *вместо* попыток обсудить проблему - не самый лучший путь к решению.

Comment: @PashaPash это где-то отражено? Я имею ввиду в правилах, справке, еще где-то.

Comment: @GreenDragon я очень надеюсь, что это отражено в форме уведобления о блокировке. Со стороны модератора в этой форме куча подсказок и отсылок к правке.  Но не могу проверить - давно под бан не попадал. Если нет - стоило бы отразить.

Comment: @PashaPash не знаю как на основном сайте, но в чате ты просто видишь плашку что вы заблокированы на определенный срок вместо блока для ввода сообщений и все. Участник не видит ни кто его забанил, ни указания на место с кем можно связаться для выяснения причин, ничего. В правилах и справках я ничего не нашел, КМ регулярно пишет, что со всеми вопросами надо идти на Мету. Если администрация не считает это лучшим решением, так вы уж разберитесь, предложите лучшее и сделайте так, чтобы участник легко мог найти алгоритм своих действий в таких ситуациях.

Comment: @GreenDragon в чате блокировка срабатывает без уведомления участнику. на сайте - есть обязательное уведомление, на него можно ответить. Не уверен расписан ли в форме ответа путь к обсуждению блокировки. Если нет - возможно, стоит расписать.

Comment: @PashaPash Эээ... я один никогда не видел здесь возможности личных сообщений?...

Comment: @Harry есть подобие лички при уведомлении о бане. для остальных - есть почта КМ в профиле Николаса.

Comment: @Harry: Угу, но это не помогает в той ситуации, если нужно оспорить действия КМ. Жаловаться человеку на него самого? Разве это эффективно?

Comment: @PashaPash первый раз слышу про личные сообщения на этом сайте...

Comment: @PavelMayorov а они есть, причем через них буквально вчера участник вполне успешно обсудил бан с КМ и был разбанен.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, просто тебя никогда не банили :-D Плюс модераторы могут делать закрытые чаты в которые только по приглашениями

Comment: @Grundy да ладно? А как же история с флагопокалипсисом в чате?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а там разве был бан на сайте, а не только в чате? :-)

Comment: Где можно узнать конкретную причину? Что опять не удовлетворило нашу ранимую администрацию? Или скоро за любой чих и отсутствие подобострастия будем в бан улетать? :) Не видел ничего оскорбительного в словах @Qwertiy, также и в сообщениях человека, указанного в этом вопросе, и уж годичная блокировка, ИМХО, это как-то чересчур. Возможно я не прав, было бы интересно узнать, дабы самому в такую же ситуацию не попасть. Спасибо.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin Ваш вопрос по сути является конструктивным, а по форме содержит некислый заряд агрессии. Если бы вы имели возможность убрать иронию ("наша ранимая администрация"), так как ирония и сарказм нонче вне закона (sic!), вырезать "за любой чих" и "отсутствие подобстрастия" (мммм, это наверное можно подогнать под "пассивная агрессия"). Но не удивляйтесь, если ваш комментарий [подправят или даже удалят](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7140/213987), а вас забанят. А если серьёзно, послушайте [универсальный совет Майорова](https://habr.com/company/tm/blog/93946/#comment_10773488).

Comment: @AK: А почему, собственно? Потому что это обидно? Мне вот тоже многое в текущей ситуации обидно, но что-то никто не отменяет своих действий.

Comment: Чтобы не потерять веру в людей, я оставляю за собой право считать комментарий AK содержащим не меньше сарказма, чем комментарий PeterSamokhin.

Comment: @AK не было цели наполнить комментарий агрессией, и ни единого оскорбления и ни единой нотки розжига ненависти в своём комментарии я не вижу. Да и, как мне кажется, вранья или даже преувеличивания в нём нет :) Но если даже такой комментарий вызовет гневную реакцию администрации — даже бана не надо; в таком случае я не вижу дальнейшего смысла и интереса присутствовать в сообществе ruSO.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin Ну, за один пока не вроде не банят, нужна серия.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Общая информация:

- Модераторы и администрация - это разные люди. [Модераторы - это представители сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators). Администрация - это сотрудники Stack Exchange.
- Бан может выдать как модератор, так и сотрудник SE. Чаще всего бан выдает именно модератор.
- В уведомлении о бане не будет указано, кто именно вас забанил (кроме случаев, когда модератор или сотрудник не укажет свое имя по личной инициативе). Ниже, для простоты, я использую просто "модератор".
- Для решения о бане не всегда собирается комиссия. В простых случаях бан применяется одним модератором.

Всегда стоит допускать вероятность ошибки. Модераторы - люди. Они иногда ошибаются. Если забаненный участник считает, что бан вынесен несправедливо (или по сути, или по срокам) - стоит попросить пересмотреть решение.

Краткая инструкция для забаненных:

1. Внимательно перечитайте сообщение о бане. Остыньте. Не торопитесь. Убедитесь что вы поняли, что именно имел ввиду забанивший.
2. Если вы считаете, что имело место недоразумение (например, вы нарушили правила по незнанию), или что наказание слишком сурово - продолжайте. Если поняли, что действительно нарушили правила и если наказание соответствует нарушению - смиритесь. Мера суровости: Обычно за первое серьезное нарушение правил банят на срок до 7 дней.
3. Вы можете ответить на сообщение о бане напрямую через интерфейс сайта, но только один раз. Следующая возможность ответа - только на следующее сообщение от модератора.
4. Если вам не ясна причина бана - скажите об этом прямо.
5. Если вы считаете, что имело место недоразумение - скажите об этом прямо.
6. После отправки ждите ответа от модератора. На ваше обращение обязательно ответят, но это может занять некоторое время.
7. Если ответ модератора не пролил свет на причины бана, или модератор ответил не по существу - напишите письмо администратору, [Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky?tab=profile)

Что стоит учитывать:

- Информация о банах видна всем модераторам. Забанить "втихаря" вас не могут. Если модератор предвзят - другие модераторы это заметят и примут меры.
- Модераторы связаны [Moderator Agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement). Они не могут раскрыть вам детали обсуждения.
- Модераторы - добровольцы, у них есть основная работа вне SO. Не ждите мгновенного ответа.

Луч надежды: даже если вам ответили, что бан не пересмотрят - модераторы могут продолжить внутреннее обсуждение и пересмотреть бан позже. Но не особо на это надейтесь :)

Если администрация совместно с модераторами решили оставить бан в силе - все, его пересмотреть нельзя. Смиритесь.

Comment: 7. Если бан выписал Николас, то какой смысл писать ему письмо?

Comment: "Они не могут раскрыть вам детали обсуждения" Они не могут раскрывать данные, идентифицирующие пользователя. Информация о бане оной не является, не?

Comment: @Suvitruf личная переписка с другими модератора - это все еще личная переписка.

Comment: @Suvitruf если бан выписал Николас, и бан был действительно незаслуженным или слишком суровым - модераторы,  как представители сообщества,  примут все возможные меры для пересмотра.

Comment: @PashaPash: Спасибо за ответ. Тем не менее, ваш ответ не отвечает на исходный вопрос: что делать, если решение, вынесенное совместно обсуждением КМ и модераторов, несправедливо. Ослабьте вопрос от «насколько я понимаю» до «в случае, если».

Comment: @VladD в вашем вопросе нет слова "**совместно**". Есть слово "келейно", которое означает всего лишь "тайно". В заголовке вопроса - "решения администрации", что тоже не намекает на *совместность*. Модераторы - не администрация, они выбираются сообществом, а не назначаются сверху. Вы же привели конкретный пример с Foggy - он не является ни примером решения, вынесенного "совместно обсуждением КМ и модераторов". Так что я ответил именно на ваш вопрос.

Comment: @VladD если вы хотите обсудить чисто гипотетическую ситуацию "бан обсудили, и 5 выбранных сообществом модераторов совместо с представителем администрации решили ничего не менять" - пожалуйста, задайте отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Вопрос общего характера и подходит в том числе для ситуаций когда модераторы либо поддерживают решение КМ (не важно принял он исходное либо поддержал действие модератора) либо публично не оспаривают(а т.к. такое запрещено, то приватная позиция к делу не относится).

Comment: Пока вся суть сводится к - "если не согласны с модером - пишите КМ, не согласны с ним - надейтесь на модераторов".

Comment: @GreenDragon да, это и есть механизм опротестования. модераторов и выбирали как раз для того, чтобы на них можно было надеятся в подобных ситуациях.

Comment: @PashaPash, я спрошу прямо — все 5 избранных модераторов поддерживают срок в 1 год бана для FF? Ну или 3 из 5?

Comment: @АндрейNOP не все, и решение принимается не голосованием.

Comment: @PashaPash, т.е. по результатам обсуждения в приватном модераторском чате было принято решение оставить бан и его срок в 1 год?

Comment: @АндрейNOP бан Foggy пока что обсуждается.

Comment: @PashaPash: «Келейно» в моём вопросе означает не «тайное решение», а «решение по договорённости в узком кругу лиц».

Comment: @VladD тогда ваше предположение ошибочно. Решение о бане чаще всего принимается одним модератором. По достаточно простой причине - у модераторов разный график онлайна, и собрать несколько человек для вынесения бана затруднительно. А бан обычно применяется в ситуации, когда требуются срочные меры, и некогда собирать комиссию.

Comment: @PashaPash: Нет смысла задавать новый вопрос, поскольку я не получил ответ на этот. Ведь у вас в тексте по сути лишь «чтобы опротестоваь бан от КМ или модератотов, обращайтесь к КМ или модераторам». Это не стыкуется с текстом вопроса: «Поскольку **все** эти люди вполне могут ошибаться, то не исключено, что решение о блокировке или других санкциях — ошибочное.»

Comment: @PashaPash: Чаще всего — возможно. Но забаненному как об этом узнать? Тогда первым шагом может быть апелляция к другим модераторам/КМ, но это всё ещё остаётся в рамках «модераторы и КМ келейно решили, как опротестовать?»

Comment: @VladD никак. Я понимаю, что вас эта ситуация раздражает, но это не я решаю. и не другие модераторы. Я ответил на вопрос, который вы задали. и описал механизим текущий опротестования бана. Если он вас не устраивает - предложите новый, отдельным вопросом.

Comment: @VladD т.е. от вашего личного несогласия с механизмом и от минуса на вопросе реальность не поменяется :)

Comment: @PashaPash: Поменял минус на плюс. Заткнулся и смирился.

Answer (score 6):

Т.к. сам столкнулся с баном, хочу модераторам/администраторам сказать о "слабых местах" ситуации которая случается при любом бане, на сколько я понимаю.

Я не буду оспаривать свой бан если что, я приблизительно понимаю что случилось и почему. Хотя и ситуация спорная -- спорить безсмысленно когда бан уже закончился.

Я сюда пришел что бы расписать как можно улучшить систему:

1. Весьма странно что у меня временно исчезли балы на SO при временном бане (1 бал на время бана показывался). Для чего это делается? Для какого-то устрашающего эфекта? Потом когда бан прошел - балы вернулись. Что случилось и для чего они исчезали вообще - мне непонятно. Как по мне, то это лишнее. Или, хотя бы, предупреждайте в имейле что это временная мера сделанная по таких-то причинах.
2. В моем личном случае пришло сообщение как-будто автоматически сформированное и без деталей почему я был забанен. Уверен, что это скорее исключение из правил, а не правило, но все же, таких ситуаций лучше избегать. Человек должен знать детали за что забанили хотя бы что бы понять что вообще случилось. Я это узнал только из второго имейла который мне пришел после создания темы на МЕТА. (спасибо сделавшему это!)
3. В имейле ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ УКАЗАНО В ВИДНОМ МЕСТЕ И ВЫДЕЛЕНО КРАСНЫМ "Если хотите узнать детали о бане или оспорить его, пожалуста, ответьте на этот имейл". Проблема в том, что подобные имейлы могут разсылатся автоматически ботом и часто являются "NoReply" на многих сервисах. Я банально не знал к кому обращатся что бы получить детали. Первая мысль - справка. Но там ничего. Вторая мысль - МЕТА. Про вариант ответить на имейл я вообще не подумал т.к. он выглядел как шаблонный ботовый текст. **ДЕЛАЙТЕ ТАКУЮ ПОМЕТКУ. Это прям оч.важно. И выделяйте текст красным**  -- иначе люди банально не поймут как действовать.
4. Создайте страницу в справке которая описывает как поговорить с модерацией о причинах бана, если есть такая возможность. И ссылайтесь в самом сообщении на сайте "вы забанены" на эту страницу справки. В стиле "Вы забанены еще на 7 дней. Если хотите оспорить или узнать детали у модерации, следуйте пунктам из (ссылка)справки"
5. Если сообщение "-165 - учасник был удален" связано с прецендентом с накруткой - то сообщение стоит изменить. Что бы было понятно -- это реально учасник удалился с StackExchange или же балы сняты за найденную накрутку. То есть это дожны быть 2 разных сообщения.

   > Я не уверен до конца что это связанно -- это лишь догадка... Но на всяк случай это так же нужно было написать.

   6.

   > Вы можете ответить на сообщение о бане напрямую через интерфейс сайта, но только один раз. Следующая возможность ответа - только на следующее сообщение от модератора."

   Лично я не нашел как это сделать, даже, 1 раз. Где это вообще возможно было сделать?

Comment: Насчет "автосообщения" - в случае накрутки детали обычно не расписывают, т.к. это практически прямая инструкция "как не попасться в следующий раз". Некоторые участники, к сожалению, настойчивы, и продолжают крутить вплоть до годового бана.

Comment: 5 - вы должны видеть мод сообщения в уведомлениях во входящих на сайте (насколько я знаю). Там же есть форма ответа. На email падает только копия, и ответ по email не предусмотрен - там действительно noreply. Про ответ - да, стоит добавить предупреждение. Большинство участников отвечают на сообщения о бане (и иногда очень грубо) - значит кнопка ответа достаточно заметна, если читать сообщение прямо на сайте.

Comment: `Некоторые участники, к сожалению, настойчивы, и продолжают крутить вплоть до годового бана. –` ахахаха `вы должны видеть мод сообщения в уведомлениях во входящих на сайте (насколько я знаю)` Не видел я сообщения во входящих на сайте. Я, даже, не знаю где эти входящие на сайте находятся вообще... =(

Comment: Скорее всего там же, где вы видите уведомление об этом комментарии.

Comment: Поискал там по слову "бан" на последних 5ти страницах и ничего не нашел. Как и возможности "ответить" там не увидел

Comment: Тут примерно описано: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283113/what-does-receiving-a-mod-message-look-like. Сорри, подробнее с телефона не отвечу :(

Comment: Вот прямая ссылка на сообщение - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/message/1776 - доступна только вам и модераторам

Comment: Пожалуста, к сообщению о бане на имейл прикладывайте подобный этому линк. :) Думаю это решит проблему "выноса проблемы на мету"

Comment: Его нельзя приложить, т.к. это линк на уже существующее сообщение. Он должен быть у вас в inbox. Может быть пропадает со временем.

Comment: @Andrew: Сообщения о бане написаны ужасным канцеляритом вперемежку в призывами к борьбе за светлое будущее. Индивидуально их никто не составляет, видимо, у модераторов всегда нет времени и/или желания.

Comment: @Andrew `Я не буду оспаривать свой бан если что, я приблизительно понимаю что случилось и почему.` - и все таки непонятно, накрутка была или нет?

Comment: @AntonSorokin свои ответы тебе я удалил т.к. это оффтоп относительно темы вопроса.

Comment: @PashaPash если его нельзя приложить, то можно создать вопрос в справке где будет расписано пошагово как обговорить причину бана с модерацией. И в имейле высылать линк на эту страницу справки. Если я, сидя на SO лет уже 5-7 не вкурил как это сделать, то, думаю, многие тоже не вкурят. И там же расписать причину временного анулирования балов. Та система которая действует сейчас явно неинтуитивна и здесь явно что-то нужно менять. Тем более, что модерации не нравятся вопросы на МЕТА связаные с этой темой --  есть мотивация.

Answer (score -5):

### Что делать, если вы видите потенциальную ошибку?

Если, на ваш взгляд, сотрудник компании, модератор или любой другой участник сообщества допустил ошибку — напишите ему об этом напрямую в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com) (общем или отдельном) или задайте соответствующий вопрос о шаблоне поведения, подходах к модерированию, пониманию правил и т.п. на Мете, соблюдая [принятые в сообществе нормы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4790/6). Единственный возможный вариант донести ошибку до участника на Stack Overflow — открытый диалог, основанный на данных, которые можно проверить.

Ключевую роль в нашем подходе играет эффективная коммуникация. Чтобы понять, как лучше описать допущенную другим участником ошибку, необходимо понять, где и почему она могла возникнуть.

#### Как происходит принятие решений мод. составом сообщества?

Если ситуация более или менее ясна, решение принимается самостоятельно тем модератором, кто обнаружил нарушение (как это [описал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7241/6) @PashaPash). В последствие это решение может быть изменено в ходе обсуждения.

В неоднозначных и новых для нашего сообщества ситуациях (в том числе новых для модераторов) принятие решения куда более сложное, а «шаги рассмотрения» зависят от конкретной ситуации.

Например, в упомянутом вами случае, ситуация выглядела примерно так:

1. Обнаружив нарушение, управляющий написал о нем открыто несколько раз нарушителю, пояснив в чем проблема.
2. К обсуждению подключились заинтересованные проблемой модераторы.
3. После повторных нарушений и отсутствие реакции со стороны нарушителя, управляющий оценил ситуацию, просмотрел историю последней активности нарушителя на платформе, принял решение о временной блокировке.
4. Рассчитал время блокировки, заблокировал.
5. Написал сопроводительное письмо о блокировке нарушившему правила участнику (уведомление об этом, на сколько я знаю, приходит всем модератором).
6. Далее, управляющий начал более глубокое исследование проблемы:

   - Написал несколько SQL запросов к базе данных чата и Меты.
   - Посмотрел статистику участия на нескольких сайтах Stack Exchange (блокировки на сайтах, в чатах, статистику посещения, статистику распределения голосов и много другое).
   - На основе информации полученной из базы данных чатов, проанализировал *несколько тысяч сообщений нарушителя* (за все его время на платформе) и сообщений рядом, от других участников.
   - Провел анализ участников, которые пересекались как–либо с нарушителем.
7. По результатам исследования выше, управляющий написал 25–и страничный отчет, со ссылками, снимками экрана, статистикой.
8. Отчет был отправлен модераторам сообщества.
9. Управляющий списался, а после и созвонился с тремя коллегами по команде развития сообществ для обсуждения результатов исследования, предоставил коллегам отчет.
10. Результаты обсуждения с коллегами, управляющий обсудил по почте и в чате с модераторами.
11. Были приняты решения, а затем воплощены в жизнь.

Суммарно исследование, отчет, обсуждения, чтение MSE и доп. литературы заняло только у меня ~100 часов. Как вы можете видеть, *решение принималось **коллективно, на основе данных***. Это вполне типичное рассмотрение нетривиальной ситуации в сообществе командой модераторов совместно с сотрудниками компании.

#### В чем может быть ошибка и как на нее указать?

Учитывая выше написанное, можно предположить, что причины ошибки в действиях управляющего или модераторов в общем случае сводятся к:

1. Недостатку данных о событии.
2. Неверной интерпретация данных.
3. Неверной интерпретация правил в контексте конкретного события. (Стремиться к нулю при коллективном обсуждении.)

Следовательно, чтобы указать управляющему или модератору на допущенную ошибку вам необходимо:

- Собрать, подготовить и предоставить данные о событии. Чем больше вы их соберете, чем всесторонние они будут, тем лучше.
- Предоставить ваши доводы и выводы основанные на данных, то есть вашу интерпретацию события, которая, повторюсь, должна *основываться на имеющихся у вас данных*.
- Пояснить модератору или управляющему в чем заключается ошибка восприятия/интерпретации правил. Пояснить максимально детально, на примерах.

#### Какой сайт или канал связи следует использовать для указания на ошибку?

Лучшее место для рассмотрения любых ошибок (то есть для публикации имеющихся у вас данных о событии, ваших выводов на основе этих данных, предположений по интерпретации правил и контекста ситуации) — [Мета](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/). Пожалуйста, просто опубликуйте вопрос, который содержит проведенное вами исследование потенциальной ошибки и мы все вместе, всем сообществом, его с удовольствием рассмотрим, обсудим, сделаем вывод и исправимся!

### Что делать не стоит?

1. **(Не) Обвинять**. На Stack Overflow мы руководствуемся принципом «доброго намерения». Если в процессе обсуждений выяснится, что кто–то допустил ошибку, скорее всего, он сделал это не специально, а из добрых побуждений. Ошибается только тот, кто ничего не делает.
2. **(Не) Верить и (не) распускать слухи**. Самый первый шаг, еще до публичного рассмотрения потенциальной ошибки —  самостоятельно найти в открытом доступе или запросить достоверные данные о событии у [управляющего](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338/274323). Если вы начинаете строить рассуждения на слухах, а не на реальных данных, ситуация может быть доведена до абсурда в крайне короткие сроки. Будьте бдительны: просите подтверждений, проверяйте сами.
3. **(Не) Руководствоваться абстрактными рассуждениям**. В теории — теория и практика одинаковы, однако на практике это не так. Рассуждая о проблеме, помните, что многие «возможные мотивы» поведения возможны лишь в воображении или абстрактном примере. Мы все обычные люди. Будьте конкретны.
4. **(Не) Следовать высокопарным лозунгам**. «Справедливость», «свобода», «равноправие» и прочие высокопарные понятия — слишком абстрактны (пункт третий), их можно доказать без доказательств (пункт второй) и опровергнуть любые доказательства обратного банальным обвинением в нежелании им следовать (пункт первый), хотя каждый из нас стремится к ним. К тому же, «бедные понятия» все время эксплуатируют [популисты](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC). Судите предметно, в контексте.

### Модераторы сообщества

- *Модераторы — обычные участники*, с разным профессиональным и жизненным опытом, такие же как и вы, за одним исключением — помимо технической составляющей Stack Overflow они увлечены и организационной частью.
- *Модераторов выбрало сообщество*, они его «официальные» представители.
- *[Основная задача модераторов — обрабатывать исключительные ситуации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7420/6)*, в том числе удалять сообщения, связываться по почте с участниками, блокировать доступ к сайту, если потребуется. Именно за этим они были избраны сообществом. Если вы хотите участвовать в принятии решений по вопросам, которыми занимаются модераторы, пожалуйста, выдвините вашу кандидатуру на следующих [выборах модераторов сообщества](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1983/6).
- *Модераторы нейтральны*, они действуют исходя из правил сообщества и миссии проекта, а не личных убеждений, придерживаясь наивысших стандартов поведения.
- *Модераторы следуют [соглашению о неразглашении личной информации участников](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement)*, в том числе в [контексте нарушений](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7276/6).

Сотрудники компании и модераторы имеют одинаковый уровень доступа к данным. Модераторы превосходно понимают правила сообщества, отлично знают как работает движок. Пожалуйста, относитесь к их отзывам максимально серьезно. Если команда модераторов не согласна с доводами по какому–либо вопросу, это прекрасный повод провести дополнительное исследование.

### Политика на Stack Overflow

Stack Overflow — это сайт вопросов и ответов для накопления знаний сообщества. Наша социальная система и инфраструктура вокруг нее намерено крайне тривиальна. Наш сайт не являются полноценным общество, например, как государство, у нас нет многих институтов. Пожалуйста, не пытайтесь перенести социальные термины общества очень сложной организации и размера с государство, на наш небольшой сайт. Это в корне неверно и чревато абсурдными выводами.

Связанные вопросы:

- «[Альтернативный регламент для инициатив](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6899/6)»;
- «[Границы демократических процедур](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7425/6)».

#### Опротестовать != указать на ошибку

[Опротестовать](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

> официально оспорить законность, правильность чего-либо; заявить протест

[Протест](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82)

> категорическое возражение против чего-либо; заявление о несогласии с чем-либо

Исходя из принципов нашего сообщества, «опротестование» — не является общепринятым подходом достижения целей на Stack Overflow. В нашем сообществе мы верим в людей, в их добродетель и желание помогать коллегам. Если кто–то допустил ошибку, необходимо ему на нее корректно указать, собрав данные, добавив размышлений на тему. Мы достигаем наших целей не протестом, а доводами и убеждением в ходе открытого диалога.

#### Суд сообщества

У нас нет института суда. Мета создана для обсуждения, то есть для диалога, а не «вынесения приговора» или принятия решения. На данный момент обработка таких исключительных ситуаций как блокировка — это ответственность модераторов. Если вы хотите участвовать в обсуждениях таких вопросов, пожалуйста, выдвините вашу кандидатуру на следующих выборах.

Comment: Рад, что вы ответили вовремя и по существу. /s Пункт №1 в списке "Что делать не стоит?" особенно очарователен в контексте, что вам нравится его нарушать больше, чем всем остальным вместе взятым. Пункт №3 стоит в прямом противоречии с вашим неизменным требованием не прикасаться к конкретным фактам. Что происходит с ромбами, которых избирает сообщество, и которые набираются смелости высказать мнение, все уже видели воочию. В итоге, кроме "мы правы априори" и "вот вам список невыполнимых требований" ничего не прозвучало. (Комментарий внезапно пропадёт через три секунды... две... одну... *пшик*)