# Почему мы не храним отметки о блокировках в открытом доступе

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, блокировка

<sub>Свободный перевод «[Why we don't keep public records of suspensions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293213/274323)»</sub>

---

Всякий раз, когда появляется новый заблокированный участник, всплывает тема приватности данных, то есть какой информацией модераторы могут поделиться с сообществом, а какую следует оставить конфиденциальной. Иногда модераторы, как и рядовые участники, сами не уверены в этом вопросе. Все эти недопонимания могут вызвать всевозможные ненужные проблемы.

Блокировка доступа несет моментальный эффект — [ограничение в возможностях взаимодействия в обществе](http://lawcomic.net/guide/?p=133). Если участник оскорбляет других или пытается что–либо разрушить, сообществу необходимо остановить это действие и деактивировать нарушителя. Следует учесть, что на нашем сайте цель блокировки в долгосрочной перспективе — [реабилитация](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/):

> Когда период времени ограничения доступа к учетной записи подходит к концу, ваша репутация будет пересчитана и учетная запись откатится назад до нормального состояния. Мы не храним обиды. Главная цель блокировки — обратить ваше внимание на поведение. Если ваше поведение улучшится, мы будем рады видеть вас снова.

Один из сотрудников Stack Overflow (автор этой статьи) помогает в качестве волонтера в пригородной тюрьме по субботам утром. В том Штате, где он проживает, большинство судебных процессов рассматриваются публично и любому человеку доступны отчеты о судебных разбирательствах и, что крайне важно, для работодателя не составляет никакого труда узнать, было ли у конкретного сотрудника криминальное прошлое. Когда он разговаривал с заключенными они выражали огромную озабоченность о своих семьях и смогут ли они обеспечивать их (семьи) после освобождения. Хотя дискриминация людей, бывших в заключении, незаконна, получить работу после тюрьмы крайне сложно. Некоторым работодателям, [особенно тем, кому нужна лицензия для ведения деятельности](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Employment_discrimination_against_persons_with_criminal_records_in_the_United_States#Background), запрещено нанимать бывших заключенных.

В Калифорнии примерно 65% бывших заключенных [попадают в заключение снова](https://californiainnocenceproject.org/issues-we-face/recidivism-rates/). Это выглядит ужасно, но неудивительно, поскольку реабилитация не является политически безопасной целью. На Stack Overflow на английском примерно 10% ранее получивших блокировку  участников получают ее повторно. Остальные сайты сети имеют примерно такой же низкий процент рецидивов. Некоторые из заблокированных участников, вероятно, переместились на другие сайты после блокировки, но большинство из них продолжило свою жизнь в сообществе продуктивно. Эти свидетельства показывают, что мы поступаем верно в контексте реабилитации. По мнению автора этой статьи, причина в том, что мы не сохраняем отметки о блокировках в открытом доступе.

### Какую информацию модераторы могут предоставить в открытый доступ?

Когда блокируется участник, остальные могут увидеть факт блокировки (нарушения) и [в общих словах почему человек был заблокирован](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23385/274323). Мы не видим каких–либо причин, по которым модераторам следует делать что–либо более, чем направить интересующегося вопросом участника на страницу заблокированного. Так как заблокированные участники не могут рассказать, как они видят ситуацию со своей стороны на Мете или в чате, чем меньше будет сказано, тем лучше. Трудно придумать лучший способ «отшить» участника, чем унизить его, когда он бессилен.

Все же, иногда вопросы о блокировке задаются. Справедливо, что системы правосудия, которые держат все в секрете, частенько оказываются не очень справедливыми. С другой стороны, поскольку после завершения блокировки результаты проблемного поведения участника обычно удалены, внешнему наблюдателю не так просто увидеть, что именно плохого сделал заблокированный участник. Получается, приходится либо верить модераторам на слово, либо довериться вашему товарищу. В таких случаях автор статьи рекомендует модераторам и управляющим сообществами следующее:

- **Быть честными**, что означает рассказывать правду, которая не очень льстит вам или другим людям. Иногда это может означать подчеркнуть ошибку, которую допустил модератор или управляющий. Это может означать краткую выдержку в общих словах на основе информации, которой нет в открытом доступе. Но это **точно не означает** публикацию закрытой информации, по которой можно потенциально отследить участника (автора действия). Это никогда и ни при каких условиях *недопустимо*, согласно [соглашению модератора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement). Честность всегда должна быть уравновешенной.
- **Уважать других**. (Хочется сказать, [будьте дружелюбны](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/behavior), но это может быть воспринято неверно.) Помогите разрешить недопонимание, но не очерняйте людей. Сосредоточьтесь на доказательствах того, что произошло избегая навешиванию ярлыков, в том числе приписыванию возможные мотивы. [Предполагайте добрые намерения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) и возьмите паузу, если она вам необходима, чтобы не выходить за рамки человечности в коммуникации проблемы.

Другими словами, цель «секретности» не в том, чтобы скрыть расследование от публики, а в том, чтобы защитить отдельных участников и все сообщество от ненужных слухов и драм. Если слухи уже начались (особенно если их начал заблокированный участник или он спровоцировал других к распусканию слухам), мы не видим причин молчать. Лучше быть шокированным правдой, чем оставаться в неведении. Все же, не разжигайте огонь ненависти, обнажая непристойные детали, которые можно тихо оставить в сторонке.

Никто не говорил, что быть модератором просто.

### Проверки и соблюдение баланса сил

Разумеется, у нас не всегда получается сделать все возможное, чтобы участники поняли, почему произошла блокировка. Для стороннего наблюдателя блокировка может выглядеть неожиданной или даже чей–то прихотью. Если вы примерный гражданин, вам может показаться, что модератор действует из чувства мести, когда блокирует доступ уважаемому вами участнику. Учтите, вся команда модераторов в курсе дел, а не только один модератор:

1. Система призывает модераторов предупреждать участников перед блокировкой. Высылаемые предупреждения не имеют последствий для участника, никаких общедоступных отметок об этом нет. Участники, получившие предупреждение, имеют возможность ответить на него своей интерпретацией происходящего. Многие получившие предупреждение участники никогда не были впоследствии заблокированы (87% для Stack Overflow на английском). Отправка предупреждения вносит огромный вклад в предотвращение возможной блокировки в будущем.
2. Любое предупреждение, как и информация о любой блокировке, отправляется всей команде модераторов сайта, а также [команде развития сообщества](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do) для проверки. Бывали случаи, когда мы отменяли блокировку. Обычно причина была в простом недопонимании или [ненадлежащем отклике системы](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288242/1438). Следует помнить, что у команды развития сообществ есть право отозвать привилегии модератора, если участник превышает свои должностные полномочия (к счастью, подобное происходит [крайне редко](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269728/1438)).
3. Система призывает модераторов следовать правилу увеличения срока блокировки: 7 дней, 30 дней и один год. Выбранные сообществом модераторы не могут блокировать участников более чем на один год. Повторюсь, наша цель — реабилитация участника в сообществе. Кажется невероятным, но многие люди возвращаются после годовой блокировки и начинают продуктивное участие на сайте.

Автор статьи исследовал много, очень много жалоб о злоупотреблении модераторами их полномочий, включая случаи несправедливой блокировки. В подавляющем большинстве случаев, явно видно, что модераторы очень осторожны с блокировкой участников и действуют обоснованно. Результат тому вы можете видеть сами в мудром подходе к модерированию сайтов сети Stack Exchange.

Наша сеть сайтов свободна от грубости и хаоса, сравнительно с остальными похожими проектами. И в этом огромная заслуга [модераторов–волонтеров](http://stackexchange.com/about/moderators), у которых есть право блокировать доступ к сайту отдельным участникам.

Comment: "На Stack Overflow на английском примерно 10% ранее получивших блокировку участников получают ее повторно" Остальные 90% навсегда покинули SO :D

Comment: @Suvitruf Видимо, вы не дочитали статью до конца. Остальные не получают повторную блокировку, а вместо нарушений продуктивно участвуют в жизни сообщества.

Comment: А где можно статистику посмотреть?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, прокомментируете абзац "Другими словами, цель «секретности» не в том..."? Или это просто перевод и к нашей ситуации не относится?

Comment: @vp_arth Поясните, пожалуйста, ваш вопрос. Я его не понял.

Comment: Меня интересует почему, когда сообщество попросило огласить причины/обоснование блокировки FF, было получено строгое нет? В контексте статьи, в которой "мы не видим причин молчать".

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Уже второй пост, в котором вы пытаетесь сказать нам, что всё сделали правильно. Будут ли посты с разбором ошибок администрации? Или их, по вашему мнению, не было?

Comment: @VladD я вот сижу и пишу пост, объясняющий некоторые из спорных решений администрации (в частности, бинайс, фриланс и прочее). Не все спорные решения - ошибки.

Comment: @VladD и не все решения - ошибки "администрации" в смысле "владельцев SO". Некоторые из них - ошибки КМ, некоторые - ошибки модераторов (в том числе мои). Например массовые баны в чате, которые обострили последний конфликт  - это ошибка в тактике мод команды. Стоило бы заморозить комнату, написать общее предупреждение - и банить уже явных нарушителей. Результат был бы тот же, а восприятие - поменялось бы.

Comment: @VladD касательно этого конкретного поста - если он не полезен лично вам, это не значит что он не полезен никому другому. Он явно объясняет, что модераторы могут раскрывать (и что, соответственно, участники могут у них спрашивать без получения в ответ "не скажу, NDA"). Лично мне бы этот пост (или даже ссылка на en версию) очень пригодился бы неделю назад.

Comment: @Suvitruf ["Out of the users who continued to post, 16% were re-suspended at some point."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293389/137096)

Comment: @jfs т.е, половина примерно. Спасибо.

Comment: @Suvitruf 16% это не половина.

Comment: @jfs 67% от 80% - это примерно половина.

Comment: @Suvitruf: "67% saw the suspended user go on to make at least one post."

Comment: @jfs ну да. 50% забаненных остались активными после разбана. Я не понимаю, чего вы хотите.

Comment: 1. А можно поменять статистику на статистику для ruSO? И ещё дополнить процентом участников, которые не покидают сайт после бана. 2. А кто может блокировать на срок более года (есть известный случай про [416 дней](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3776/178988), что больше года).

Comment: @Qwertiy Вы бы ещё придумали критерий "ухода с сайта". Вот я есть или меня нет? :)