# Ограничение в модерации для попавших ранее под действие блокировки участников

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, блокировка

Многие, наверное, знают, что на прошедших в 2017 году [выборах модераторов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/2) был кандидат, снятый с гонки по причине того, что находился некоторое время под баном. Как [говорят на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274114/339911), в течение года до выборов надо быть законопослушным, иначе баллотироваться нельзя.

Но что, если уже избранный модератор [попадает под действие блокировки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7200/176217)? Не стоит ли здесь провести какие-то адекватные параллели и, например, отстранять от модерирования на тот же, ранее упомянутый год? А может даже перманентно лишать ромба? Ведь нарушение правил (а бан даётся именно за нарушение правил) модератором куда больший грех, нежели обычным участником.

Я не хочу кого бы то ни было ограничивать в правах и выяснять правомерность и/или корректность выданных ранее банов, я за консистентность правил на сайте. Ваше мнение?

Comment: Если бы забанен был другой модератор, то вопрос бы тоже появился?

Comment: @Suvitruf вопрос уже был в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=44304940#44304940), но адекватного ответа не последовало. Может на Мете что-то получится. P.S. информация в последнем абзаце.

Comment: @Suvitruf, у меня нет разногласий с alexolut'ом, насколько я знаю?

Comment: @Qwertiy я просто спросил :P

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю, с чего вопрос возник, ведь нареканий как к модератору вроде нету.

Comment: @Suvitruf, думаю, просто кто-то очень любопытный :)

Comment: @Suvitruf ничего личного, просто <s>бизнес</s> правила (ц).

Comment: Модераторы же тоже люди... А у любых людей могут быть временные недопонимания, какой смысл за такие недопонимания кого-то отстранять, наоборот достойный выход из таких ситуаций это достойный пример для многих. Кроме того не вижу смысла влезать во внутреннюю кухню модераторов, и привлекать к таким ситуациям излишнее внимание.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Люди - тоже люди (далее - по тексту).

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин я не призываю отстранять. Вопрос о параллелях в подходе между баном кандидата и баном модератора.

Answer (score 6):

### tl;dr: это решат в Stack Overflow.

---

Начнём с того, что для кандидатов в модераторы требование "никаких банов за прошедший год" **мягкое**, т. е. может сниматься в исключительных случаях в отношении отдельных лиц, по запросу через форму обратной связи. Поэтому всё-таки придётся затронуть

> правомерность и/или корректность выданных ранее банов

...а обсуждать по этой теме особенно нечего. Это свободная переменная, значение которой определяется уже в Stack Overflow (полагаю, что командой развития сообществ) по вышеописанному запросу. И они уже сами решат, принимать ли кандидатуру участника на выборах в течение следующего года, после этого, и лишать ли ромба сейчас.

Кроме них (и, возможно, действующих выборных модераторов) никто не сможет принять информированное решение в общем случае, потому что [доступ к данным о блокировках ограничен](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7276/181100). Да и меры, опять же, принимать в любом случае сотрудникам SO.

Это, впрочем, не означает, что они не обратятся за помощью в принятии решения к сообществу.

---

Насколько я понял из слов Николаса в чате, блокировка действующего модератора немедленно подняла в компании вопросы о разжаловании виновника, и Николасу дали *ограниченное* время предъявить веские причины **не** разжаловать. Поэтому, как видно, обычная практика в таком случае — разжаловать. Если блокировка справедлива, разумеется.

Запрещать ли выдвигаться в модераторы в дальнейшем? Я считаю, что нет. Действующие правила этого не требуют, а за год человек вполне может сильно измениться.

Comment: Вот только не уверен, блокировка немедленно подняла, или я зря полез в модераторский чат...

Comment: Я всегда считал, что модераторы выбираются "бессрочно". И что их могут снять только за что-то очень серьёзное.

Comment: @Qwertiy как я понимаю из контекста, **правила внутри компании** требуют поставить вопрос, а как скоро, уже зависит от обнаружения: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=44289280#44289280

Comment: @Suvitruf нарушение действующих правил это весьма серьёзно. Для модератора вдвойне.

Comment: @D-side да, но степень серьёзности у всех нарушений разная. В общем, ждём ответа КМ)

Comment: Откуда вытекает **мягкость** требования?

Comment: @Suvitruf в профилях причины блокировки были идентичны, насколько я помню.

Comment: @alexolut мягкость по отношению к модератору?

Comment: @Suvitruf не понял вопрос.

Comment: @alexolut "Откуда вытекает мягкость требования". В смысле "почему к модераторам более мягкие требования" или "как понять, какие требования более мягкие"? Кандидатов никогда не снимали за прошлые блокировки.

Comment: @alexolut отчётливо помню, что интерфейс сайта сообщал о необходимости написать в обратную связь при наличии блокировок за последний год. [vp_arth любезно нашёл соответствующую строчку в переводах](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44545707#44545707).

Comment: @Suvitruf я уточнял у D-side о конкретной строке из его ответа. В свежем [комментарии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7289/?noredirect=1#comment29801_7290) это проясняется в достаточной степени.

Comment: @alexolut занятно. На последних выборах формулировка другая была.

Comment: Ну, этак можно на любой вопрос по правилам так ответить. Как решит компания, так и будет, это всегда выполняется.

Comment: @VladD не на любой вопрос требуется информация из закрытого доступа.

Answer (score 1):

Общее правило для подобных ситуаций следующее:

#### Если модератор получает блокировку, то он автоматически теряет свои  привилегии модератора на сайте.

В статье «[Теория модерации](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/)» упоминается, что компания ожидает от выбранных модераторов, в частности:

> - Поскольку вы модератор, все ваши действия идут от лица сообщества, поэтому **вам необходимо придерживаться самых высоких стандартов поведения**. Вы лицо, которому *все доверяют*, с практически теми же правами на сайте, какие есть у сотрудников.

В статье также говорится, что модераторы должны решать любые разногласия внутри команды напрямую:

> - Вы должны быть на связи с вашими коллегами из состава модераторов и работать с ними для разрешения любых конфликтов внутри команды. *Управляющие сообществами имеют предписание отозвать **привилегии модератора у участников, которые не хотят сотрудничать***.

В обычной жизни, блокировка участника — исключительное событие, вызванное серьезным нарушением правил. К примеру, типичные причины блокировки:

- накрутка репутации с помощью фиктивных учетных записей;
- целевые голоса / голоса из чувства мести;
- оскорбительное отношение к другим участникам;
- уничтожение полезного содержимого.

Если участник с правами модератора нарушает какое–либо из этих правил (или любое другое правило, за которое мы обычно блокируем доступ), с большой вероятностью, он не может нести бремя «лица сообщества». И вряд ли хочет сотрудничать для разрешения конфликта.

Модераторы должны улаживать конфликты, а не провоцировать их.

Comment: Хм, если есть предписание махнуть банмолотом побольше, почему  Qwertiy ещё ромбовый?

Comment: @Other видимо, нашлась причина из хвоста ответа D-side.

Comment: @alexolut, Видимо. Хотел бы я её знать.