# Что если понимание правил не совпадает с общепринятым? Есть ли у модераторов «амулет» и можно ли его забрать через Мету?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Есть некоторые положения, по которым возникли полувопросы/полупредложения:

1. **Защита выбранных представителей.**
   Я считаю, что выбранные представители (модераторы, владельцы чатов) представляют вторую ветку власти и должны быть защищены от первой ветки.
   Это не означает полный карт-бланш, но, по крайней, их осуждением/импичментом должно заниматься сообщество, выбравшее их.
   Выборные должности — публичные, и поэтому человек, соглашающийся на публичную должность, должен согласиться на публичное обсуждение своих действий. Это, кстати, нормальная практика в политике всего мира.

   Насколько мне видится, сейчас принято келейное, закрытое рассмотрение проблем с представителями сообщества, и это вызывает вопросы.

   Если нам говорят, что кто-то из публичных представителей нарушил правила, почему это нарушение и его тяжесть не обсуждается всем сообществом?
   Например, случае с владельцами чата, как мне кажется (доказать не могу, т. к. голосования не было), сообщество вовсе не считала поведение владельцев чата серьёзным нарушением. И это подводит нас ко второму вопросу:
2. **Интерпретация правил.**
   Я неоднократно замечал, что интерпретация правил (в частности, правила дружелюбия) сообществом отличается от интерпретации правил администрацией.
   Поэтому, когда администрация заявляет, будто бы правила были нарушены, это ещё не означает, что они были нарушены с точки зрения сообщества.
   Я считаю, что администрация слишком сильно расходится во мнении с сообществом по этому вопросу, и хотел бы, чтобы позиция сообщества уважалась.

   В частности, уровень того, насколько вежливыми нам нужно быть с новичками, я бы хотел устанавливать консенсусом сообщества, а не приказом администрации.

   Как и то, нарушили ли представители сообщества правила, должны решать мы, а не администрация.

   А вот уже нарушение правил отдельными участниками должно быть прерогативой модераторов, на это они и поставлены.
3. **Официальная процедура импичмента для всех выборных должностей.**
   Без комментариев.

Comment: Политика, ветки власти и прочее - вы о чем? SO, не государство. SO - это вполне конкретный коммерческий проект, который не пытается построить классическую демократию с разделением ветвей власти, судом, законом и прочим.

Comment: Ясна пихта, но описанные приёмы могут быть применены в рамках коммерческого проекта. А если нет, то пусть сразу говорят: тут мы — Власть и больше не говорят о том, что сообщество что-то решает и его права хоть что-то значат. В текущей редакции реальности считается что комьюнити решает свои вопросы.

Comment: Опять - причем тут власть и причем тут права? это не государство, это сайт вопросов и ответов. Часть действий по модерации сайта возложено на сообщество. Это не означает, что "мы" (кто мы? десяток человек сидящий в чате? читающие мету? топ 10 отвечающих) могут обсуждением в узком кругу устанавливать правила для остальных.

Comment: Сейчас окончательное решение в спорных моментах принимают модераторы - честно избранные сообществом (причем во время выборов сообщество активно подталкивается к голосованию). Если вы считаете, что этого недостаточно - приведите, пожалуйста, какие-то конкретные аргументы, кроме "мы" (на самом деле "я") так считаем

Comment: Например, если вы считаете, что интерпретация правил (в частности, "будьте дружелюбными", https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) должна быть изменена - соберите конкретные примеры, когда, по вашему мнению, модераторы необоснованно удалили содержимое, и задайте отдельным вопросом на мете. Потому что сейчас это не вопрос, а просто ничем не подтвержденные обвинения в адрес непонятно кого (администрации? выбранных вами же модераторов?)

Comment: @PashaPash, Извините, мне надоело уже с Вами спорить. Если есть что ответить по конкретным предложенным вариантам - прошу, пишите пост.

Comment: Вы не опасаетесь того, что сообщество, освобождённое от навязывания бинайса, окажется по своей сути злым и быстро превратит ruSO в mista.ru?

Comment: к чему настолько размытый заголовок "Предложения к администрации" с практически нулевой информацией в добавок уже имеющейся метке `[предложение]`? Вы пытаетесь говорить с позиции человека глубоко знающего сайт и его правила. Какая у вас логика для выбора такого заголовка? [ask]

Answer (score 11):

Не совсем понимаю, вопрос это или предложение, так что и ответ - скорее, констатация фактов:

SO - не государство.

SO - это вполне коммерческий проект, который не пытается построить классическую демократию с разделением ветвей власти, судом, законом, *тюрьмой* и прочим.

Это обычный сайт вопросов и ответов. За хостинг, разработку и развитие которого платит Stack Exchange Network.

Как только обычные участники начнут платить за хостинг, разработку и прочее - они станут источником власти.

Администрация вводит правила на основаннии отзывов от собщества. Нет, у нас не принято келейное, закрытое рассмотрение проблем. Наоборот, администрация стремится к полностью открытым обсуждениям. Если вы считаете, что правила сайта стоит поменять - выносите предложение на мету.

При этом стоит различать обсуждение проблем и обсуждение поведения конкретных участников. Причины этого подробно раскрыты в посте [Почему мы не храним отметки о блокировках в открытом доступе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7276/)
. Если коротко - это делается  для защиты отдельных участников и всего сообщество от ненужных слухов и драм. Нет никакого смысла устраивать публичное общественное обсуждение каждый раз, как кто-то кого-то посылает в комментариях.

---

> Я неоднократно замечал, что интерпретация правил (в частности, бинайса) сообществом отличается от интерпретации правил администрацией.

Участники чата != сообщество. Сидящие на мете != сообщество. И даже "участники с > 1000 репутации" != сообщество. И тем более, отдельный участник != сообщество.

Вполне возможно, что интерпретация администрацией правила "Будьте дружелюбными" (введенного администрацией же) отличается от интерпретации этого правила лично вами вами или другими участниками. Все люди разные, у все разный порог чувствительности - и именно поэтому модерированием у нас занимается не один человек.

Если вы считаете, что что участники регулярно необоснованно получают предупреждения о нарушении правила [Будьте дружелюбными](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) - пожалуйста, оформите список примеров отдельным постом, вынесите на обсуждение сообщества + администрации. Сейчас же это не описание проблемы, а просто неконкретная жалоба.

---

(3) [Официальная процедура импичмента](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157258/).

Comment: `Как только обычные участники начнут платить за хостинг, разработку и прочее - они станут источником власти` — буду вторым человеком, который обратит внимание на наличие в [туре](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) предложения «Сайт создан и управляется сообществом». Что тогда означают слова «создан» и «управляется», если потолок влияния участников — высказывание личных мнений по решениям администрации?

Comment: @Arhad насколько я понимаю, подразумевается именно управление контентом (модерация) и активное прислушивание к мнению сообщества со стороны админстрации (в рамках допустимого администрацией). Т.е. я вроде как участник сообщества, но я точно сайт (как как приложение, включая хостинг) не создавал. Хотя в разработке кусков чуть-чуть участвовал. В английском туре - It's built and run by you. Так что возможно это тонкости перевода.

Comment: `я точно сайт (как как приложение, включая хостинг) не создавал` — движок и управление — лишь половина дела. Это не более чем платформа, которую мы, участники сообществ, наполняем содержимым («build») и следим, чтобы это содержимое соответствовало сути сообщества («run»). То есть мы платим, хоть и не деньгами, но контентом, ради которого посетители сюда и приходят. Соответственно, вкладывая сюда немалые усилия и время (которое, к слову, может таки стоить реальных денег) и обустраивая *наш* уголок, мы, участники, закономерно ожидаем полного влияния на всё, что внутри этого уголка происходит.

Comment: @Arhad Да, вот только полного влияния не будет. Есть "значительное влияние". Например, вы (мы) все еще обязаны пускать в этот уголок любого прохожего и автоматически влкючать его в свой круг. Т.е. это такой "принудительно открытый" уголок. Причем открытость - это основное правило, и оно внешнее. Нельзя взять и устроить фейс-контроль, нельзя взять и запретить "простые вопросы", нельзя запретить задавать вопросы новичкам (и нельзя запретить отвечать новичкам!). Нельзя взять и ослабить правила для "старичков". И нельзя ввести в онтопик вязание крючком :)

Comment: Добавлю касательно `кто мы? десяток человек сидящий в чате? читающие мету? топ 10 отвечающих?` Согласен, дюжина активных участников не может решать за все 45 432 участников, внёсших хотя бы крошечный, но всё же принятый вклад. Однако, как я понимаю, речь идёт вовсе не о необходимости передаче власти. Возмущения идут из-за отмены де-факто сложившихся норм. Мол, раньше всё работало, а сейчас зачем-то всё снесли, *почти* ни у кого не спрашивая.

Comment: Часть пользователей после "_как только обычные участники начнут платить за хостинг, разработку и прочее_" сказали мысленно "О как, ну пусть тогда и очереди сами проверяют".

Comment: @Arhad Какие именно "возмущения"? Есть пара участников, которые обиделись на сам факт, что у нас не демократия, и наголосованное на мете - не обязательно к исполнению администрации. Причем обиделись именно потому, что раньше администрация достаточно часто к ним прислушивалась, причем даже вопреки правилам и вопреки опыту других сайтов сети. И? Администрация должна извинится, принять именно те решения, на которых именно эти участники настаивали, и вообще перестать управлять сайтом? Вся власть народу, потому что кто-то обиделся на то, что не он управляет сайтом?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev при всем уважении, самые обиженные отсутстием демократии, разделении ветвей власти, власти народу и прочим, те, кто прямо требует эту демократию вернуть - почти никак очереди не просматривали и активного участия в модерации сайта не принимали. Очереди у нас проверяют (в основном) не те, кто сидит в чате. и даже не те, кто сидит на мете. Обида вызвана самим фактом отсутствия демократии. Не вижу, как это решить - ввести демократию и убрать администрацию?

Comment: @PashaPash у меня нет конкретных предложений и в этом "конфликте"  я не занимаю чью-либо сторону. Просто я вижу, что чем дальше, тем больше обе "противоборствующие стороны" совершают ошибок, что только уводит от разрешения непонимания.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev да нет никаких противоборствующих сторон. Есть участники, обиженные разные аспекты. кто-то обижен на отсутствие реальной демократии, кто-то - на запрет посылать в гугл, кто-то на жестко вбитое правило "быть дружелюбными со всеми или молчать" - не могут молчать. Кто-то обижен на то, что вопросы слишком простые, а кто-то - на запрет разговоров "за жизнь". Любое ограничение, любой пункт правил кого-то обижает. Обида участника на правила сети или на суровую правду жизни - это проблема самого участника.

Comment: @PashaPash в целом согласен, но если VladD действительно покинул ресурс, то это уже проблема администрации, как мне кажется. Впрочем, может лидеры топа здесь каждый год уходят и это не является признаком проблемы или большой потерей - не знаю.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev вот я, например, очень обижен на то, что сайт, где мне просто нравится отвечать на интересные мне вопросы, пытаются превратить в какое-то государство, с ветвями власти, общественным порицанием и прочим. Очень обижен. Потому что эта политота и попытка сделать из QA демократию портит лично мое удовольствие от общения на профессиональные темы.

Comment: @PashaPash пожалуйте к нам на Тостер, ресурс без малейших признаков политики! ;)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Вот у вас на тостере - представьте ситуацию, когда топовый участник требует ввести прямую демократию. Или он уходит. что будете делать? устроите торжественные проводы? Хотя, какая демократия на тостере, там даже *модераторов не выбирают*, сплошная *келейность*.

Comment: @PashaPash у нас всё очень разумно устроено, все топы давно продались власти или сами власть и c упоением лупят оппозицию банхамерами :D

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev ой, а тостер ещё жив? Его там не планируют признать ошибочным решением и вернуть на habr, как и с гиктаймс поступили?

Comment: @Suvitruf живёт и здравствует. Какие именно перемены его ждут в связи с выходом Хабра на мировой уровень пока обдумывается.

Answer (score 2):

#### Stack Overflow — не место сбора досье нарушений

Как уже упоминалось, на сайтах Stack Exchange для нас крайне важна [возможность реабилитации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7276/6) участника в сообществе после нарушения. Как результат, в подавляющем большинстве случаев, публичные рассмотрения недопустимы (почему это следует делать так, а не иначе, смотрите [в статье по ссылке](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7276/6)). С другой стороны, если вы считаете, что кто–то нарушает правила, вы можете поднять [вопрос о поведении, без указания личности автора](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4790/6).

#### Нас много, мы все разные и это очень здорово!

Пожалуйста, учтите, что на сайте Stack Overflow на русском зарегистрированы почти 20 000 человек. Когда вы говорите, что правила воспринимаются «сообществом» иначе, вполне вероятно, что речь идет не о всем сообществе, а о нескольких участниках. То, что мы не согласны с позицией других людей не делает нас или «других людей» хуже, но может сделать наш общий сайт лучше! Чтобы устранить недоразумение, вам необходимо конкретно описать, в чем ваша интерпретация правила дружелюбия (или любых других) отличается от смысла, который него вкладывает компания. Вполне возможно, что наши различия в понимании много меньше, чем кажутся на первый взгляд. Главное — конструктивный диалог, уважение к собеседнику и готовность аргументировать свою позицию логическими выкладками и примерами.

#### Stack Overflow — это профессиональный инструмент

Замечу, Stack Overflow — это повседневный рабочий инструмент разработчика, который создан с конкретной целью — собрать библиотеку ответов на прикладные вопросы по программированию с минимальным соотношением шум/сигнал. Если вы видите в сайте, например, потенциал социальной сети, сожалею, но это невозможно.

#### Stack Overflow — это узкоспециализированный инструмент, который создается сообществом: самоуправление и самоопределение

Из миссии проекта и выбранного способа развития вытекают многие правила сообщества. Возможно, тут может появиться некоторое недопонимание в разрезе способа принятия решений (как происходит принятие решений, смотрите [в ответе по ссылке](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6899/6)). Обдумывая как прояснить недопонимание, мне показалось интересным рассмотреть два термина (оговорюсь, это вполне конкретные термины из мира права и политики, которые полностью/напрямую не переносятся на сайт и нужны лишь чтобы наглядно пояснить ситуацию):

1. *[Самоуправление](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)* — [состояние, при котором субъект и объект управления совпадают...](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)
2. *[Самоопределение](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)* — [...означающий право каждого народа самостоятельно решать вопрос о форме своего государственного существования...](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

На мой взгляд, на Stack Overflow мы придерживаемся *максимального самоуправления* и *минимального самоопределения*. Причина тому описана выше — у сайта есть миссия (самоопределение) и достигнуть ее мы можем лишь вместе, всем сообществом, организацией и ежедневными процессами которого занимаются избранные голосованием участники (самоуправление).

Минимально и максимально — но не полностью! Не всё и не всегда идет идеально. Сотрудники компании могут и участвуют в жизни сообщества, если видно, что что–то идет не так. Типичный пример — перевод интерфейса сайта, который создается и поддерживается сообществом. Но (!) до того, как в сообществе появился [шеф–переводчик @alexolut](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4066/6), сотрудникам компании приходилось полностью переписывать переводы, предложенные участниками, потому что они носили юмористический характер, были непонятны или вовсе неуместны на сайте. Сейчас это не требуется, и мы полностью доверяем @alexolut, никак не вмешиваясь в этот процесс.

С другой стороны, сайт — это лишь инструмент достижения цели (создание базы знаний по программированию / быстрое получение развернутого ответа на вопрос по программированию). В компании Stack Overflow мы верим, что никто лучше сообщества, то есть тех людей, которые непосредственно участвуют в создании базы знаний, не может знать как должен выглядеть «инструмент». Таким образом, прежде чем сесть за реализацию задуманного, мы спрашиваем совета/отзывы сообщества. Конечно, мы интересуемся мыслями участников не только в контексте реализации функций движка, но и во многом другом.

#### Stack Overflow — это сайт вопросов и ответов по программированию

Что касается «[импичмента](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82)», то этот полит. термин совсем к нам не относится, так как у нас нет большинства институтов для его реализации, то есть он просто технически невозможен.

Если вы не согласны с действиями какого–либо участника, безотносительно, является он модератором или нет, пожалуйста, [предложите рассмотреть модель поведения без привязки к личности автора на Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4790/6). Уверен, большинство участников сообщества заинтересованы в его развитии и реализации миссии проекта. Если тактично указать им на ошибочное действие, с большой вероятностью, они исправятся и будут действовать во благо всем.

Все же, для более сложных ситуаций связанных с модераторами [предусмотрен некоторый процесс](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151606/274323).

#### Правила сообщества едины для всех

Пожалуйста, помните, у сообщества есть правила. И *правила едины для всех*. Если выбранный участниками (или назначенный на бета–стадии) модератор нарушает правила сообщества, безотносительно его популярности в сообществе, он будет отстранен от занимаемой должности.

Повторюсь, правила едины для всех. Без исключений.

Comment: И опять ответ без конкретного ответа на поставленные вопросы. Ладно, привыкшие мы.

Comment: @Other Подскажите, на какой именно вопрос вы не получили ответ?

Comment: Тот, который задавался. Точнее там не вопросы в целом, но не суть. Вопрос - возможно стоит ввести А? Ответ - Вы же знаете как мы чтим Z, Y для нас непогрешим, F равны для всех и вообще R плохо.

Comment: @Other, пожалуйста, будьте конкретны. Подскажите, какой именно вопрос остался не раскрытым?

Comment: На все. 1) Есть только намёк что нельзя обсуждать отдельных участников, это противоречит политике восстановления осуждённых. А вопрос про конкретных юзеров, которые были выбраны народом, их нельзя в один ряд ставить. 2) "Правила едины для всех" - ну вот вообще ни разу не ответ на вопрос о разной интерпретации онных для администрации и юзеров. 3) Копирка с первого "не ответа". Мы можем применить подобные процедуры. Например, голосованием на мете. Сейчас же, как мы видели, администрация может тихо забанить модера и всё. Без обсуждения с теми, кто его выбрал.

Comment: @Other На мой взгляд, ответы на все поставленные вопросы есть в сообщении выше. Отвечая на комментарий: (1) все участники равны в контексте правил, исключений нет и не будет. (2) Если ваша личная интерпретация правил дружелюбия не совпадает с версией из справки/правил сайта и вы хотите устранить недопонимание, пожалуйста, задайте вопрос на Мете (беря в расчет текущие правила сайта!). Если, по вашему мнению, на Мете подобный вопрос неуместен, задайте его мне по почте.

Comment: (3) В ответе есть ссылка на развернутое описание процесса принятие решений на Stack Overflow и почему оно такое, а не другое.

Comment: Пожалуйста, подскажите, на какой вопрос все еще нет ответа?

Comment: Либо Вы специально, либо случайно не понимаете вопросов. Предпочту сказать что все ответы я получил и не распалятся дальше.