# Теория модерации

Tags: поддержка, модерация

<sub>*Свободный перевод публикации из блога «[A Theory of Moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/)»*</sub>

Мы (компания StackOverflow) убеждены, что сообщество должно модерироваться самими участниками. Именно поэтому мы назначаем [временных модераторов](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) или, в идеальном случае, придерживаемся [процедуры выборов модераторов через демократическое голосование](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-exchange-moderator-elections-begin/) на каждом сайте нашей сети. Что же делают модераторы? Коротко: самый минимум!

С самого начала пути, середины 2008–го года, мы следовали цели дать сообществу как можно больше самоуправления. Из первой версии [быстрых ответов о Stack Overflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour):

> Stack Overflow создается и управляется вами! Если вы хотите помочь управлять сайтом, сперва вам необходимо заработать репутацию. Репутация — это (очень) грубая мера того, насколько сообщество Stack Overflow доверяет вам. Репутацию невозможно подарить, ее можно только заработать, убедив других участников, что вы разбираетесь в теме.

Мы проектируем [движок сайтов сети](http://stackexchange.com/sites) так, чтобы все сообщества были максимально саморегулируемы. Это необходимо, чтобы объединить небольшой вклад каждого из тысяч обычных участников сообщества в единое целое. При этом особый упор делается на привилегиях, выдаваемых системой в зависимости от [уровня репутации](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/membership-has-its-privileges/) участника.

- Участники с репутацией 15 баллов могут оставлять тревоги.
- Участники с репутацией 500 баллов могут проверять сообщения новых участников.
- Участники с репутацией 2 000 баллов могут вносить правки в любые вопросы и ответы на сайте.
- Участники с репутацией 10 000 баллов могут голосовать за удаление или восстановление вопросов и имеют доступ к дополнительным инструментам модерации.
- Участники с репутацией 15 000 баллов могут устанавливать защиту на сообщения.
- Участники с репутацией 20 000 баллов могут голосовать за удаление ответов с отрицательной репутацией.

Даже в случае активной саморегуляции иногда необходимо вмешательство модераторов. **Модераторы необходимы, чтобы обрабатывать исключительные ситуации, связанные с человеческим фактором.** Их задача — разрешать (надеемся редкие) исключительные ситуации, которые *не должны происходить* в нормальных условиях, но если такие ситуации происходят, то они могут довести все сообщество до отчаяния и полной недееспособности, если, конечно, они не будут вовремя разрешены.

Наиболее типичная задача модераторов — просматривать сообщения, отмеченные сигналом тревоги. Под каждым сообщением на сайте есть небольшая «тревожная» ссылка, которой может воспользоваться любой участник с 15 баллами репутации.

[image]

Сообщение может быть отмечено тревогой за спам, грубость или оскорбления, если он низкого качества или общим типом тревоги — «требует вмешательства модератора», с детальным описанием проблемы.

[image]

Как только участник отмечает сообщение сигналом тревоги, счетчик в специальной панели модераторов увеличивается на единицу.

[image]

**Если вы видите на сайте что–то плохое, странное или настолько исключительное, что требует внимания модератора .... *[используйте сигнал тревоги](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/14/improved-flagging/)*!** Основная работа модератора — просмотреть каждое отмеченное тревогой сообщение и принять необходимые меры, если требуется.

Чтобы успешно справляться с подобными редкими исключительными ситуациями, у модераторов есть специальные необходимые привилегии:

- Голос модератора решающий. Если модератор участвует голосовании любого типа (закрытие, повторное открытие, удаление, восстановление, перенос сообщения и т.д.), действие происходит немедленно после голоса модератора.
- Модераторы могут блокировать сообщения. Заблокированные сообщения невозможно изменить как–либо, в том числе проголосовать в них.
- Модераторы могут защищать вопрос. На [защищенные вопросы](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/06/07/new-protected-question-status/) могут отвечать только участники с репутацией 10 баллов и выше.
- Модераторы видят дополнительную информацию о системе включая распределение голосов (без авторства) и закрытую информацию из учетной записи участников.
- Модераторы могут [заблокировать участнику доступ к сайту на время](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) и удалить учетную запись вовсе, при необходимости.
- Модераторы могут выполнять действия поддержки, затрагивающие все сообщество. Например, объединять вопросы и метки, подтверждать синонимы меток и т.д.

Если вы модератор одного из сообществ Stack Exchange, ниже краткий список того, о чем следует помнить:

- Теперь, когда вы стали модератором, любые ваше действия идут от имени сообщества. Это означает, что вам необходимо придерживаться наивысших стандартов поведения. Вы являетесь «послом доверия», с уровнем прав аналогичным команде разработчиков и сотрудникам из команды развития сообществ.
- Ваша цель — выступать добродушным проводником сообщества, но с решимостью разрешать исключительные ситуации, при необходимости. Относитесь с уважением к вашим коллегам в сообществе, что бы ни произошло. Проявляйте справедливость и беспристрастность в каждом вашем действии.
- Всегда, когда это возможно, оставляйте небольшой поясняющий комментарий к каждому сообщению, в котором вы выступили (или хотели выступить) в роли модератора. Крайне важно, чтобы участники сообщества могли изучить нормы сообщества и практики модерирования сайта.
- Не давайте содержимому выходить за рамках тематики сообщества: закрывайте, переносите или удаляйте вопросы, которые совершенно не относятся к тематике сайта.
- Регулярно просматривайте отмеченные тревогой сообщения и принимайте решительные действия, если они требуются.
- В случае серьезных разногласий, связывайтесь напрямую с участником, чтобы помочь уладить конфликт интересов.

Хотя модератор сообщества — это волонтерская позиция (получаемая через выборы) и участие в жизни сообщества является абсолютно добровольным, мы требуем трех важных вещей от всех избранных модераторов:

1. Вы должны принять [соглашения модератора](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement) в течении 30 дней с момента назначения или завершения выборов и оставаться активным на сайте.
2. Вы должны всегда оставаться на связи с коллегами модераторами и работать вместе по разрешению любых конфликтов внутри команды модераторов. [Существует процесс](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157258/274323) снятия модераторов, которые не могут или не хотят идти на диалог.
3. На Stack Overflow, в связи с его масштабом и сложностью, существует дополнительное правило. Если вы участвуете на сайте, но не обрабатываете тревоги на регулярной основе, вы можете упустить ваше право быть модератором сайта.

Большинство работы модератора рутинная: удаление очевидного спама, закрытие откровенно не тематичных вопросов и различная работа с сообщениями с крайне низким рейтингом. Идеальный модератор делает необходимый минимум, но эти небольшие действия имеют огромное значение для сообщества.

Став модератором, будьте разумны и грамотно ограничивайте взвешивайте ваши действия в роли модератора. Быть модератором — это искусство, искусство умеренности.

Comment: Уточните, "Мы" это кто?

Comment: @Cerbo Просмотрел статью. Все «мы» в этой статье можно заменить по смыслу на «компания».

Comment: Последнее словечко надо поправить  в абзаце! «Даже в случае активной саморегуляции иногда необходимо вмешательство модераторов. Модераторы необходимы, чтобы обрабатывать исключительные ситуации, связанные с человеческим фактором. Их задача — разрешать (надеемся редкие) исключительные ситуации, которые не должны происходить в нормальных условиях, но если такие ситуации происходят, то они могут довести все сообщество до отчаяния и полной недееспособности, если, конечно, они не будут вовремя разрашены.»

Comment: С какой частотой проходят выборы? Где можно посмотреть требования к кандидатам и подробное описание процесса?

Comment: @EugZol: Elections are generally only held when a moderator resigns (or is removed for inactivity or any other reason), or when the current moderators feel that there is a need to hold a new election. There's an explanation of how the overall election process works in this FAQ on Meta Stack Exchange: [There's an election going on. What's happening and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135360/335251)