# Следующий этап развития русскоязычного сообщества: сайт без выделенного управляющего

Tags: обсуждение, вехи

Коллеги, наше сообщество подошло к новому этапу своего развития — максимальному саморегулированию, без выделенного управляющего.

Хочу поблагодарить всех, кто принял в этом участие: задавал вопросы, отвечал, активно обсуждал правила на Мете, поддерживал коллег в чате. Спасибо вам! Без вас бы ничего не вышло!

---

> ### Коротко:
>
> С сегодняшнего дня у русскоязычного сообщества не будет выделенного управляющего. [Я сконцентрируюсь на развитии всех международных сообществ Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313084/274323). Часть задач по управлению сообществом мы бы хотели передать избранным модераторам. Цель изменений — улучшить опыт участников международных сообществ, совместная работа над инициативами.

Сообщество — живой организм. Оно растет и меняется с течением времени. В самом начале, сайт требовал огромного временного ресурса — мы сами задавали и отвечали на вопросы. Затем в сообществе появились первые участники и мы сконцентрировались на поиске ответов на их вопросы. Переломным стал момент, когда участники начали отвечать на вопросы друг друга.

Сегодня сообщество настолько сильное, что может успешно существовать без участия выделенного управляющего. И мы хотим предложить вам  сделать этот важный для сайта шаг вместе.

### Зачем что–то менять?

Сегодня, мы видим несколько аспектов организации международных сообществ, улучшив которые, многим участникам станет приятнее использовать сайтами.

#### Улучшить поддержку сообщества

Поддерживать в одиночку сообщество из нескольких десятков человек несложно. Достаточно время от времени общаться с каждым участником лично, пытаясь понять, где можно улучшить или оптимизировать, а где что–то убрать. Поддержать сообщество из нескольких сотен людей — сложно, из нескольких тысяч — невозможно.  Проблема поддержки большого количества участников одним человеком может обернуться настоящей катастрофой, если к его действия будут привязаны к срокам (например, без какого–то решения или ответа большая часть людей не может продолжать работать, а ответственный сотрудник, как назло, заболел).

Ключевую роль в жизни сообщества нашего размера играют избранные модераторы. Управляющий нужен исключительно для помощи модераторам. Поддержка участников, в таком случае, полностью ложиться на модераторов.

#### Объединить инициативы международных сообществ

Ранее каждое международное сообщество имело выделенного управляющего. В результате, каждый международный Stack Overflow имел свой фокус, свои цели и свои инициативы (как со стороны компании, так и со стороны сообщества). Когда управляющий представлял инициативу сообщества компании, инициатива рассматривалась лишь в контексте одного сообщества и могла быть отклонена, например, потому что нужна лишь небольшой группе участников.

Рассмотрение инициативы в контексте всех международных сообществ даст возможность реально оценить влияние реализации на жизнь участников Stack Exchange. Ко всему, чем больше людей выскажет идеи о инициативе, тем более продумана она будет.

#### Максимально передать управление сообществом модераторам

Ожидания от модераторов сайтов сети Stack Exchange хорошо известны из [Теории модерации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7420/6). С другой стороны, наши международные сайты уникальны своими культурными особенностями и, конечно же, языком. Мы просим модераторов международных сообществ взять на себя чуть большую ответственность, чем модераторов других сайтов сети. Это связано с тем, что в компании нет такого человека, который бы знал языки всех наших международных сайтов.

В частности, в рамках русскоязычного сообщества, мы хотели бы передать народным избранникам:

1. Поддержку участников на Мете, как говорилось выше.
2. Поддержку участников в чатах и отслеживание соблюдения политики дружелюбия.
3. Поддержка новых участников на основном сайте, разъяснение им правил сообщества, а также отслеживание и удаление агрессии.

В ближайшем будущем мы постараемся подробно рассмотреть вместе с вами все предлагаемые улучшения.

Еще раз выражаю огромную благодарность всем, кто вместе с нами делает интернет лучшим местом для получения ответов на вопросы по программированию. Благодаря вам многие ваши коллеги день ото дня становятся лучше в выбранной ими профессии.

Следите за новостями международных сайтов с меткой «[international-sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/international-sites)» на [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)! Буду крайне рад услышать ваши отзывы.

Comment: Николас, лично вы планируете запустить, вырастить ещё несколько русскоязычных сообществ?

Comment: @Kromster Почитайте англоязычную статью. У меня была первоначально мысль, что это новое веяние в хедофисе - порезали косты всем сообществам и теперь каждый будет на полставки. Но нет, там речь персонально про Николаса, какой он молодец. Там же сказано, что он теперь интернейшнл коммьюнити менеджер и что скоро он получит новые указания. Так что тема, что Николас будет делать дальше не раскрыта и я например хотел бы услышать подробности из первых рук. Ну а пока - просто поздравляю с хорошей работой и желаю удачи на новом участке работы.

Comment: @Kromster Обновил публикацию, добавив кратко основную мысль.

Comment: @AK Не до конца понял ваш вопрос. Раскройте его более детально, пожалуйста.

Comment: Есть неплохой движок и платформа для создания сообществ - stackexchange, с этим можно было создать ещё несколько крепких сообществ на русском языке - как смежных с уже созданными (проще создавать), об этом ранее говорилось как о "расширении онтопика" и может быть даже чуть в стороне (например - о музыке). Вы не хотите ещё повторить успех ru so, запустив ещё пару успешных сообществ? Или вы теперь будете глобально рулить такими создателями новых русскоязычных сообществ? Или только старых? Или вам дадут в нагрузку португальские языки. Что ждёт вас дальше?

Comment: @AK Спасибо за вопрос! Мой фокус — существующие международные Stack Overflow. О запуске новых сайтов каких–либо изменений я не слышал. В то же время, в движке происходит много изменений. Например, запуск Команд. Новые функции движка в будущем могут сильно упростить запуск и поддержку сайтов других тематик.

Comment: Поясню мысль. Например, даже Русский язык сейчас поддерживать в полной мере сложно, так как нет аналога MSE между всеми русскоязычными сайтами. Банально, тот же FAQ о системе не собрать без постоянного дублирования информации. Пока нет системных решений подобных проблем, на мой взгляд, запуск дополнительных сайтов на разных языках несколько сложен.

Comment: В таком случае кто будет медиатором между нашим сообществом и компанией? Модераторы? Какова будет политика в плане решений вопросов на мете? Будет ли мнение сообщества решающим по голосованию как писалось ранее или же мнение сообщества будет как и сейчас чисто информативным для компании и мета останется территорий для обсуждений, а не принятия решений?

Comment: То есть теперь у любых локальных сообществ не будет КМ-ов? Или это касается только ruSO?

Comment: @yolosora Да, совершенно верно. Модераторы для нас будут являться основным связывающим звеном. Я не знаю ни португальского, ни японского и, к сожалению, даже испанского. Взаимодействие в таких условиях будет несколько отличаться от того, как мы ранее с вами общались здесь, на Мете Stack Overflow на русском. В ближайшем будущем постараюсь развернуто все описать.

Comment: @yolosora Это изменение затронет все международные сообщества.

Comment: Вопрос не только Николасу, но и модсоставу: будут ли какие-то изменения в модсоставе? Дополнительная иерархия ("старший модератор"), дополнительные выборы в связи с увеличением нагрузки, изменения в процедуре рассмотрения вопросов? Вот раньше был перс.ящик Николаса для обратной связи, теперь там будет групповой емейл висеть или всё останется как раньше?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky т.е. теперь по любым вопросам связанным с сообществом мы будем обращаться к модераторскому составу, а они уже будут связываться с сотрудниками компании? Конкретизирую.

Comment: @AK Иерархии среди модераторов не будет (о таком даже не думали, если честно). Необходимость выборов — вопрос открытый, решение по нему совместное (сообщества, текущих модераторов и компании).

Comment: @yolosora Очень хочется, чтобы именно модераторы принимали важные ежедневные решения в управлении сообществом. Уверен, этого хотят и участники сообщества. Сотрудники нужны для поддержки модераторов (например, если им не хватает каких–то данных, я буду рад помочь их собрать). С другой стороны, мои контакты в открытом доступе, плюс вы можете всегда воспользоваться формой обратной связи.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky звучит интригующе, ждем дальнейшего поступления развернутой информации. С повышением!)

Comment: @yolosora Спасибо!

Comment: Успехов на новой должности — с повышением! Надеюсь, что и наш сайт попадет под эту статью: «...Maintaining stable growth and health» :)

Comment: @Aer Большое спасибо!

Comment: Присоединяюсь к поздравлениям с ростом в компании. Успехов!

Comment: Поздравляю всех с новым этапом!

Comment: А разрешат создавать новые сообщества на русском языке ??

Comment: @timob256 вы немножко опоздали...

Comment: @timob256 На данный момент я не слышал про такие планы. Надеюсь, в будущем.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky спасибо за ответ

Comment: Из минусов этого решения: отредактировать справку нереально.