# Поменять ссылку на теорию модерации в очереди

Tags: дефект, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация

Нужно заменить ссылку на наш перевод: [Теория модерации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7420/15479).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Где этот блок вообще показывается?

Comment: @Qwertiy https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/review