# Обращение к модерации: Про баны и справку

Tags: поддержка, предложение, справка

Нечаянно наткнулся на старую тему и на свой ответ в ней и перечитал.

> Собственно сам вопрос: [Какие предусмотрены пути опротестования решения администрации?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7226/186752)

> И мой ответ там: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9309/186752

Там я предложил целый ряд советов как улучшить систему банов что бы они были более человечны и дружелюбны к забаненым.

В том числе в комментариях написал о необходимости создать тему в справке касающуюся банов:

> @PashaPash если его(линк) нельзя приложить, то можно создать вопрос в справке где будет расписано пошагово как обговорить причину бана с модерацией. И в имейле высылать линк на эту страницу справки. Если я, сидя на SO лет уже 5-7 не вкурил как это сделать, то, думаю, многие тоже не вкурят. И там же расписать причину временного анулирования балов. Та система которая действует сейчас явно неинтуитивна и здесь явно что-то нужно менять.

Мне стало интересно реализовал ли кто это.

Я заглянул в справку и поиск по слову бан выдал пустоту:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

## Уважаемая модерация, за что вы так со своими пользователями?

Если никто не удосужился банально добавить информацию в справку хотя бы по-минимуму как себя вести, что делать, к кому обращаться... Где вообще возможно узнать о причине бана если она неизвестна забаненому?

И вот если уж никто не удосужился банально добавить информацию в справку -- проверять выполнялись ли остальные мои рекомендации вообще бессмысленно.

Люди попадающие в бан по той или иной ошибке - бывают. А что нужно делать -- справка об этом молчит все время существования ресурса - все лет 7-8.

## Пожалуйста, удосужьтесь написать справку по этому поводу. Хотя бы минимальную

В качестве других предложений по "очеловечиванию" работы с банами можно пользоваться самим моим ответом в той теме: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9309/186752

Answer (score 3):

> расписать причину временного анулирования балов

Уже относительно давно почти все личные сообщения с банами содержат подобный текст:

> Ваша учётная запись временно заблокирована на 7 дней. Во время блокировки ваша репутация будет отображаться равной 1, но после окончания блокировки она будет восстановлена.

---

> Где вообще возможно узнать о причине бана если она неизвестна забаненому?

Ну вообще-то в тексте личного сообщения причина указана. И поле ввода с кнопкой ответить расположено прям под этим сообщением.

> Я заглянул в справку и поиск по слову бан выдал пустоту

Так может надо было искать по русскому аналогу `блокировка`? Впрочем, тогда найдутся несколько полезных постов про автоматическую блокировку, про блокировку модераторами вроде бы ничего нет, но по идее с ней всё должно быть понятно по присланному личному сообщению.

Comment: ```Ну вообще-то в тексте личного сообщения причина указана.``` - в моем случае (пару лет назад) такая причина указана не была в принципе. О причине я узнал тогда из второго имейла который в свою очередь пришел только после создания темы на мете.

Comment: `но по идее с ней всё должно быть понятно по присланному личному сообщению.` - да в том-то и дело что не было понятно пару лет назад - по личному опыту. Да и  неясно было как искать информацию о причинах и с кем поговорить тоже. Снова таки - в т.ч. потому что справка ничего не показывает об этом.

Comment: Даже поискав по слову "блокировка" я не увидел темы где расписывается как пообщаться с модератором по поводу блокировки. SO генерирует какой-то магичнеский линк на каждую ситуацию для подобного диалога - но как добраться до этого диалога что бы там что-то спросить лично я так и не понял будучи на ресурсе уже прилично времени (лет 5 на тот момент) - как минимум эта информация должна быть в справке.

Comment: Я не поленился и нашел в истории имейла оба сообщения от "do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email" и никакой кнопки там нет. Зато есть "задайте их в ответе на модсообщение. Не обязательно писать пост на мете." - а как это сделать - мне неясно и по сейчас, например. Вот именно по-этому справка и необходима. В т.ч. по общепринятому ключевому слову "бан"

Comment: @Andrew, отправил сообщение, на самом сайте оно должно появиться в шапке [вместе с остальными уведомлениями от сайта](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6ZLJ.png). Оно будет вести на страницу `https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/message/2457#2457`, которая будет выглядеть примерно так: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcpUR.png.

Comment: Ага, вижу, система в этом плане обновилась. Спасибо. А как вручную прийти к подобным сообщениям с интерфейса? Кроме как с шапки с нотификейшнами?

Comment: @Andrew, не знаю. А вот тут в профиле ничего нет? https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxKH9.png Не знаю, мне как модератору показываются или самому участнику тоже? Показывается только там, где не 0, так что не могу на другом сайте проверить.

Comment: ничего похожего не вижу, я уже смотрел в профиле: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZNdk.png

Comment: @Andrew, тогда не знаю...