# Как начать выборы? И кто их начинает?

Tags: поддержка, выборы

Уже недели две (как мне показалось) в блоке `важное на мете` висит пост [а не устроить ли нам выборы?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12418/%d0%90-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b). На нём 30 голосов "за". К тому же, недавно ушёл один модератор. То есть соообщество вроде как хочет устроить выборы.

Собственно, **вопрос**: а как начать выборы и кто их начинает? В комментариях мне отвечали: "центризберком SO", "скоро придёт КМ" и так далее,но это вызывало у меня ещё большее любопытство.

У модераторов есть кнопка "начать выборы" или как?

**P.S.** [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1983/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82?rq=1) ничего на эту тему не нашёл.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

У модераторов такой кнопки нет. Нужно взаимодействие с Community Manager.

Теперь детали:

- [Из FAQ на общей мете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135361/383809):

  > Elections are called as needed by the Stack Exchange Community Team on all sites. Depending on the site's current status ...

  То есть выбор инициируются Community Manager **по необходимости**.
- [Когда проводятся выборы](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99512/383809):

  > The community management team periodically looks at the work load on graduated sites and will reach out to the moderation team if it looks like more help might be needed. Broadly, it's up to the moderation teams to indicate whether they need additional hands, and how many sets of hands would be ideal.
  >
  > Although we'll reach out to moderators on the anniversary of their last election, just to see how they're doing, elections do not always take place at the same time every year. Sometimes a year can even go by without any election at all. Most elections are scheduled as a result of moderators reaching out to Stack Exchange to ask for additional help.

  Вкратце: Community Manager обращается к имеющимся модераторам, запрашивая нужна ли им дополнительная помощь. Это происходит регулярно (как модератор Computational Science SE, подтверждаю, что раз в году — точно). Выборы проводятся, если модераторы выражают таковую необходимость.

Таким образом, модераторы Stack Overflow на русском в какой-то момент ответят\напишут Community Manager.

Текущая ситуация:

- [Очевидно, что сообщество за выборы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12418/337980).
- Факт, что [как минимум некоторые модераторы выборы поддерживают (см. комментарии)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12420/337980).
- Я не вижу причины, почему эти выборы не состоятся в относительно скором времени.
- Также я не вижу причин спешить и делать это прямо завтра. Хотя можно и завтра.

Comment: То есть если модераторы напишут КМ'у, то выборы будут начаты?

Comment: Мне неизвестны случаи, когда модераторы, написавшие КМу о необходимости выборов - получили отказ.

Comment: Надеюсь, что в скором времени выборы всё-таки начнутся...

Comment: @Зонтик метишь в модеры? ;)

Comment: @DaemonHK нет =). Но хочу быть избирателем, то есть голосовать за кандидатов. Во-первых, я ещё никогда не голосовал на выборах (так как зарегистрировался пару месяцев назад), а во-вторых (это второстепенная причина) хочу получить знаки "партсобрание" и "избиратель"

Comment: @Зонтик ачиво...чер... понятно))

Comment: @DaemonHK так ачивки на то и существуют, чтобы побуждать к действиям участников сообщества =)

Comment: @Dmitry я голосовать на выборы не из-за значков пойду =).  Хотя они мне и нравятся, но это далеко не главная причина.

Comment: @Зонтик так я вас и не обвиняю ни в чем. Я про то, что так и должно работать и ачивки как раз для этого и нужны. То, что побуждает так или иначе активность среди участников ресурса, всегда хорошо)

Comment: @Зонтик, думаете выборы изменят что-то к лучшему?

Comment: @avp по крайней мере, легитимизируют тиранию

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, о да, это в русле тенденций строительства современного рабства

Comment: @DaemonHK обещаю вам, что на этих выборах моеё кандидатуры **не** будет))

Comment: @Зонтик обычно с этого все и начинается, говорят одно, делают другое))

Comment: @DaemonHK вот видите, моей кандидатуры нет))

Comment: @Зонтик ладно, верим)) из всех кандидатов "знаю" только двоих, за них и буду голосовать