# Выборы модераторов сообщества – 2023

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, выборы

В настоящее время проводятся [выборы модераторов сообщества 2023](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/5)! Выборы модераторов сообщества состоят из трёх этапов:

1. Этап выдвижения кандидатур
2. Этап предварительного голосования
3. Этап выборов

Обычно процесс выборов занимает от 2 до 3 недель, но всё зависит от количества кандидатов.

Пожалуйста, посетите официальную [страницу выборов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election) для получения дополнительной информации и принимайте участие!

О том, что такое выборы и как они работают, можно подробней узнать [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1983/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82). Для общения с кандидатами есть [отдельный чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145259/2023-stack-overflow---moderator-election-chat).

Если у вас есть вопросы по процессу проведения выборов или по кандидатам в модераторы, задавайте их здесь, на Мете — только убедитесь, что ваши вопросы имеют метку [выборы](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ выдвигаться будешь? )

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik а вы?

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik я еще не решил (ц). Думаешь, есть шансы?

Comment: @Зонтик возможно. На выходных подумаю, найдётся ли время на это.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ думаю, есть. Вопрос в том, надо ли оно тебе и сработаешься ли с текущими модерами.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik а в чём проблема сработаться? у тебя не получалось? токсичные модераторы? Ну так подвинуть можно. Ромб не вечен :)

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik насколько я помню, бывшие модераторы (снявшие ромб самостоятельно) могут вернуться в любой момент, выборы для этого не нужны. Только если вдруг хочется место отжать или проверить ещё раз уровень доверия сообщества.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ у меня ок было, но с Бармалеем я вряд ли бы сработался. Не, обход процедур какой-то, даже если прошлый, то нужно снова через перевыборы, как по мне.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik а ты разве с ним не пересекался ромбами? Обход процедур - это должно быть интересно. Небось там тоже ничего не работает, если подковырнуть :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я ушёл до его прихода. "Обход процедур - это должно быть интересно". Заинтриговал (¬‿¬ )

Comment: Интересно, а кандидатам разрешено голосовать?

Comment: @aepot конечно. Можно даже за себя. Редкое исключение на SO.

Comment: В ряды кандидатов в модераторы затесался какой-то безымянный тип. У всех ник большим жирным шрифтом написан, а у него - пусто. Может, забаним его? :)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov голосованию, как оказалось, пока не мешает, но будем посмотреть.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ На предварительном за себя нельзя. Похоже, что оно реализовано как обычный вопрос

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov надо ставить тревогу на этого хулигана! Авось КМ разберётся с этим безобразием, благо переводы есть и теперь без гугла понятно куда кнопки жать.

Comment: @nomnoms12 прошлый раз для предварительного кандидатов не набралось. А на финальном этапе было можно. Кстати, оно действительно [парсится как вопрос.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388286/339911)

Answer (score 10):

Just for info, так сказать...

Построил табличку количества голосов (по состоянию на прямо сейчас :)) от формального балла кандидата, и вот что получилось:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сразу: я думал, стоит ли это вообще показывать, пока идут выборы... но, в конце концов, это все открытая информация, которую может получить практически каждый участник (ну кроме тех, у кого репутации не хватает посмотреть все голоса, и то только для двух кандидатов).

Более-менее нормальная корреляция, как, вероятно, и следовало ожидать. Есть только пара-тройка выбросов, причем у Denis640Kb выброс не такой уж и большой, так что можно его даже не рассматривать как выброс. А вот у двух Михайлов :) — Михаила Реброва  и Mikhailo выбросы куда существеннее (при одном и том же формальном балле).

Пока идет голосование, комментировать результаты вообще и выбросы в частности точно не буду (скажу только, что второй тур мне кажется практически излишней формальностью).

Comment: 50 на графике справа обрезать бы (т.к. максимум - 40). По поводу выбросов - я думаю тут другие факторы влияют. По двум параметрам мы возможно не всю картину видим просто. У Mikhailo позднее выдвижение, в последний день, даже комментов под постом нет - возможно это повлияло. У Реброва довольно хороший текст анкеты, хотя это трудно объективно как-то измерить, и еще сравнить с другими.

Comment: Ну все верно, я же просил за меня не голосовать )) Вот только я посмотрел — опять кандидатов 13. Да что ж это такое... Придется снимать свою кандидатуру досрочно (а я опять хотел в последние 5 минут ))

Comment: @Harry, да. Безумно приятно иметь выбросы в положительную сторону )

Comment: тем, кто за меня голосовал однозначно виднее по какой именно причине они это делали (из-за того, что я и без ромба модерацией занимаюсь, из-за того что я относительно активен на мете и в чате, из-за того, что они разделяют схожие ценности, из-за анкеты...или из-за их совокупности)

Comment: я и сам был неслабо удивлен. Мне кажется, что если бы я был активнее в период голосования и если бы я банально хотя бы о своем выдвижении в своих соцсетях рассказал, то результат мог бы быть другим. Но с другой стороны все хорошо, что именно так обернулось. Ибо конкурировать с Алексом, и уж тем более вытеснять его из победителей я точно не хотел.  Он более достойный кандидат и он уже давно заслужил этот ромб. Мне казалось, что он должен был быть на первом месте.

Comment: Mikhailo в свою очередь снялся с выборов. Если говорить о том, же формальном бале, то мой тёзка его по большей части за счет баллов репутации получил (на 7 больше чем у меня). Соответственно баллы за участие и модерацию он в таком же количестве не добрал (на что и могли обратить внимание)

Comment: В контексте сказанного у меня в принципе есть вопросы к этим баллам. В них есть явный перекос в сторону баллов репутации. Активность на мете в принципе никак в нем не учитывается. Модерация, редактура, участие в данной формуле также представлена достаточно плохо: нет абсолютно никакой разницы сделал ли ты одну или пять тысяч проверок в очередях, etc. При этом каждая тысяча репутации (из первых 20) будет тебе засчитываться за бал

Comment: Возможность махинаций я даже обсуждать не хочу. Мои знакомые узнали о том, что я в выборах учавствовал только сегодня утром, когда я про третье место рассказал. Если у кого то есть желание, то можно расследование провести - мне скрывать нечего :-) Тем более, что голосующих с гулькин нос было и все их по головам посчитать можно

Comment: @МихаилРебров Не понял, а кто говорит про возможность махинаций? :) Комментировать результаты я не хотел, потому что это была бы агитация :); я как раз хотел сказать, что доверие общества больше у тех, у кого вот такие выбросы в положительную сторону :) Что до выброса в меньшую сторону — то, как мне кажется, со стороны Mikhailo выдвижение в последние 5 минут было не более чем шуткой, с соответствующим отношением со стороны общества, так сказать.

Comment: @Harry, это не камень в Ваш огород был. Извиняюсь, если вынудил так думать

Comment: я просто перебирал возможные причины отклонений.

Comment: В банках, и многих других финансовых учреждениях как раз по таким выбросам и большим отклонениям от нормального поведения определяют потенциальных мошенников и пр. Поэтому и вкинул.

Comment: Моя же основная мысль в том, что формула расчета баллов кандидата на SO недостаточно хороша, для того, чтобы полноценно оценивать кандидатов. Поэтому сложно сказать.

Comment: а графики и данные это всегда круто и интересно) за этим всегда увлекательно наблюдать) я вашему ответу без каких-либо сомнений сразу плюсик влепил, не думая ни о каких махинациях)

Comment: ну и если вы действительно так думаете про оценку доверия сообщества, то отдельное искреннее спасибо) постараюсь оправдать его в дальнейшем)